# We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!

Tags: discussion, behavior, be-nice-policy, code-of-conduct

> TL;DR: We've put together a code of conduct (CoC) that is a bit more comprehensive than our existing [be nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) because we feel that our current policy isn't meeting our needs.
>
> Some background, our reasons for doing this and a link to the draft ([Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G1BpL_G_m6F5LIPMUZVcLejSPFTb3XbI_69X8fQSZAk/edit) | [GitHub](https://github.com/tinkertim/StackCOC/blob/master/The%20Stack%20Exchange%20Network%20Code%20of%20Conduct%20(R7).pdf)) can be found below. We'd like your feedback by July 11, 2018.

#### In the beginning, there was 'Be nice'.

From the [earliest web archive snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20080916123307/http://stackoverflow.com:80/faq) of http://stackoverflow.com/faq (circa September, 2008):

> **Be nice.**
>
> Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. We're all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.

And that's all we needed when we started. Stack Overflow began with a large group that were fairly avid readers of [Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com) and [Joel On Software](https://joelonsoftware.com). While many of us sort of knew each other from interacting on both blogs and via mediums like Twitter, what can be said is, through our shared interests, we had *much* more in common with one another than we had differences. For many of us, Jeff & Joel spoke to the *majority* of what we valued and were passionate about.

We had essentially one rule: *be nice*. But, it was *seldom*, [if *ever*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) that we actually had to enforce it. We were a group that, despite numerous geopolitical differences, essentially behaved the *same* through the handful of circumstances one might encounter while using the site.

Sure, the mechanics of the site encouraged sincere collaboration, but many missed that we were *already* a community that (mostly) agreed on the fundamentals of *many* things needed for our group to self-govern; it wasn't *just* the software and gamification that was creating a runaway success.

From our bootstraps, we showed tough love by editing and voting *ruthlessly*, but we were a small enough community that we could sweep away criticism by accurately stating *this is how we like it*. We and the site were something new, and people wanted to be part of both things. And we grew, *wow* did we grow; what an amazing machine where one could plant a programmer and grow a good communicator.

#### And then, there was 'Be nice'.

Maybe in context, we could call it 'Be Nice(***r***)?'

[We expanded our policy a little bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), because it was simply too ambiguous. In fact, a key balance point that we struggled a bit to find [in our initial RFC for the re-write](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback) was just that, breadth vs. depth:

> Some people wanted more detail and examples (for clarity), others wanted less (for broader applicability).

We knew we needed to create something where folks embraced the *intent*, or *spirit* of the document, rather than using the document as a checklist of stuff to avoid moderators, while giving *some* examples of what's bad for use as landmarks. But, the voice of the policy was still *better not do that* rather than *here's how to not do that*.

Since then, we've absorbed an *enormous* amount of feedback from people that have interacted with our sites for the very first time, some stuff has been pretty consistent across rather vast groups of people.

#### We fell short in our 'Be nice' re-write in the following ways:

- We needed to write for the *best* of folks in our community. Off-putting things tend to mostly come from folks who will probably only ever blow their top *once*. We have moderators to deal with the tiny fraction of people that *never* care about rules, so our code of conduct needs to mostly resonate with the overwhelming majority of people we really want to keep. We need less over-posturing for troll dispatching and more guides to help decent folks avoid more common pitfalls.
- Codes of conduct help identify your community to the outside world, and help people decide if your community is a place where they'll feel safe and flourish. Our expanded 'Be nice' policy doesn't hold up to much scrutiny if you're fresh from seeing a bunch of nasty comments go unmoderated because they weren't *technically* rude.
- We're at a point where 'Be nice', which first originated in a group where we pretty much already *had* a strong social contract, just isn't enough. What worked well for *hundreds* isn't working well for *millions*, and we need to write something more comprehensive.

But our policy is short on other things, too. What we need is a formal code of conduct that's similar to what free / open source projects and even conferences use in order to set behavioral expectations and norms.

The difference between what we have *now* and what a formal code of conduct would look like is best expressed by simply showing you our first draft of a formal code of conduct.

#### For your feedback, we're presenting our initial draft of a real Code of Conduct.

We'd very much appreciate your time in taking a moment to **read our draft** ([Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G1BpL_G_m6F5LIPMUZVcLejSPFTb3XbI_69X8fQSZAk/edit) | [GitHub](https://github.com/tinkertim/StackCOC/blob/master/The%20Stack%20Exchange%20Network%20Code%20of%20Conduct%20(R7).pdf)). If you have some cycles to spare, we're specifically seeking the following types of feedback:

1. Even if you don't agree with *all* of it, do you feel that this is a reasonable code of conduct? Does it affect your recommending Stack Overflow as a resource in any way? How so?
2. Is anything in this document, including its purpose, unclear to you in any way? Are there any instances where you'd suggest alternate language or copy? Where? Why?
3. If you're a long-term contributor, how does this document impact your feelings toward new users and their needs, if at all? How does it impact your feelings toward the company? Or, more broadly, did this document inspire any metacognition at all?
4. If you're someone who wants to contribute more often, or have felt yourself sort of stuck on the fringes, how does this document change your perception of the site, if at all?

#### We're open to all feedback.

We understand that not all of you feel like this is necessary, and we understand that truly being inclusive means making sure everyone has seats at this table too, as long as we can possibly extend one. That means we need a civil dialog, so we're asking for any negative feedback to be respectful and honest. Please remember, we're listening to you *as well* as many, many people that simply aren't comfortable coming here, and a big part of our goal is going to remain to include them.

We'd *like* feedback by Wednesday, July 11, 2018, however this question will allow for feedback until a final draft is released, at which point this question will be closed as a duplicate of that one. We'll monitor for new *answers* as long as this remains open.

**Please, post an answer and avoid comments if you have anything of substance to say.**

We'll respond to comments that are readily and practically answerable with a few dispassionate sentences, but if you've got anything even remotely substantive to say, we're asking that you leave an answer. Using comments instead is actively *harmful* because it requires us to spend more cycles moderating and archiving than actually engaging.

#### In closing

We'd like everyone to remember that we're talking about *ways to be nicer to one another* - so please, let's have a conversation about this in the spirit of that intent.

We're in the process of gathering *a lot* of feedback through UX research and having a bunch of conversations with interested groups to gain a variety of perspectives. The more *open* and *specific* you can be about any concerns that come up as you read this draft, the better our next draft will be. For instance, it's fine to say *"that scares me but I'm not quite sure why"*.

Thanks for reading this far, and let us know what you think!

Comment: There's an old saying, "Children don't hear anything you say, but they see everything you do." Mission statements fall into the "anything you say" category, and they're not really directed outwardly. I've seen so many organizations agonize over mission statements without considering that nobody outside the organization cares about, heeds, or even bothers to read them.

Comment: Curious: if you wanted answers by July 11, why is this *just now* being featured in the "FEATURED ON META" block of SE sites?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy It has been featured since July 3 ... I saw it the next day on the handful of sites I regularly check on - can you tell me where you didn't notice it  until now? That's .. definitely a bug .. if so. If you look at the views over the short time this has been posted, word really got out. Kinda baffled as to why you didn't see it.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't paying attention, but I've been on Stack Overflow and a variety of the hot questions pretty regularly.

Comment: At this point in time I would like to ask that this whole CoC be reconsidered. IMHO it's led SE down a dark path and has made SE Inc. (and maybe even us)  less nice.

Answer (score 354):

Random comments while reading the document:

## Our mission

> **Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or language.** Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know, join us in building a learning community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

err... is it? I think [this is our mission](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Don't get me wrong - **I'm all in favor of a code of conduct** - it is becoming a standard for communities to have a code of conduct, and I think it's great you're formalizing it.
But I find the mission statement a little confusing.

## Unacceptable Behavior

> - No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language
> - No name-calling or personal attacks
> - No discrimination of any kind
> - No harassment

Intuitively, I'd expect these to be in reverse order - with the more severe offenses on top.

> **No discrimination of any kind.** This includes any language likely to offend or alienate people based on (but not limited to): race, gender, gender identity or expression, English fluency, sexual orientation, disability, mental illness, nationality, neurodiversity, physical appearance, body size, or religion.

Besides discrimination, many of this also fall under harassment and hate-speech.
Discrimination is something that is almost impossible to prove *for an individual case* - but of course it still worth mentioning.

## Reporting and Enforcement

The example table of *Behavior/Typical Action* is mixing serious and illegal behavior like sexual harassment with childish, SE-specific acts like sock puppet voting. I think you should separate internal rules regarding voting or post quality to another section.

Comment: I agree with this. Perhaps something like "Our mission is to build a library of detailed answers to questions about many topics *through* an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate" would work, which blends both bits of language.

Comment: I think putting the less severe but *much* more common offenses at the top is constructive, since most frequent users will never harass another user but may be tempted to drop a subtle put-down from time to time. If a reader only gets that far through the policy, it's more likely to do good.

Comment: Agree on the mission thingy, disagree on the order thing

Comment: I think this is a point of clarification: the team of us working on this stuff's mission is as stated - it's a separate mission from our overall company mission. Having a specific team mission helps us scope and direct our work appropriately.

Comment: @KristinaLustig - I suspected the "our mission" section relates to the code of conduct. It's a good mission, maybe a lot nicer than curating Q&A, but it might be confusing. Is it intended to be part of the document? If so, maybe it should say "The goal of the CoC"?

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Valid point. I only said this feels wrong to me ("Intuitively"), but I can rationalize this either way.

Comment: @KristinaLustig, that's great that it is your team's mission, but I wonder if you might be missing the point of the concern.  The code of conduct starts by saying "Our mission is...".  That sounds like it is trying to articulate the mission of the Stack Exchange network and of its users -- not the mission of one subgroup of employees.  I suggest changing that wording in the code of conduct.  I don't think a description of your team's mission belongs in the code of conduct for everyone.

Comment: @KristinaLustig (Along the same lines as DW...) I think the ideal preamble / mission statement for the document would be one from which the points in the rest of the CoC naturally follow. The current one doesn't really work since it misses the importance of "content" (ie, questions and answers, not simply help and learning)... something like "building a learning resource through a community that is rooted in ..." would be one step in that direction. Then "Focus on the content, not the person" seems totally consistent with "be welcoming" (while otherwise these might seem contradictory).

Comment: Good point re: mission. Something like what @Frank suggested might make sense.

Comment: What's hilarious about this is that you're attempting to fix something that isn't broken. How many times have you read on this page that "nearly all / most / a majority of people don't do this?"

You have a solution looking for a problem, and do you really think enforcing and implementing all of this won't cause issues itself?

All of the hate speech and discrimination nonsense could be put down to "No personal attacks".

Comment: @LM_Fielding - **1.** I don't consider hate speech and discrimination "nonsense" at all. To me, at least, it is completely unacceptable. **2.** Generally you have laws even against things only a few people would do. It is good to be explicit and say "this is wrong". A law forbidding something most people do would be a lot more problematic, but as you've said yourself, this isn't the case here.

Comment: Hate speech isn't a meaningful concept, and I didn't say discrimination is nonsense I was talking about how dividing people into an infinite number of categories to resolve issues regarding is idiotic when one could simply be against personal attacks, since all mentioned characteristics are personal and unrelated to code.

Stackexchange isn't a justice system, it's a question and answer service. It doesn't need complex "laws".

Be explicit against personal attacks then, rather than being redundant for the sake of virtue signalling. A gay programmer is a programmer, nothing more.

Comment: Re the mission statement: don't forget that the CoC is for the whole network, not just SO.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - I chose to quote SO because while it is true the CoC is meant for the whole network, I believe SO is the main motivation here. SO is the biggest site and the most visible: this causes these problems to be amplified, leading to SO getting the most criticism regarding its inclusiveness, welcomeness, and overall culture.

Comment: I think anything in the behavior table could be potentially legal or illegal, depending on the specifics

Comment: @LM_Fielding. I've often wondered what the phrase *virtue signalling* means. Many people denigrate it, but are unable to explain it when asked.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen: "Virtue Signalling" is when someone performs an action designed to show how "virtuous" they are. Such as explicitly calling out individual "protected groups" instead of a general policy, because it is viewed as more virtuous to protect, say, trans-gender people instead of protecting everyone.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Every other site has similar language. For example, here's ELL's: ["With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about learning the English language."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @LM_Fielding "No personal attacks" doesn't exclude throwing around hate speech as if we were 4chan, it only stops you openly directing it at a specific person. _Sufficient Velocity_ have been through this recently and had to explicitly state that it was offputting and unacceptable to throw around the word "trap" as used in an [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) context, however well-intentioned. Obviously SE is it's own site and needs to make its own decisions, but I seriously don't want to accept posts using bigoted slurs just because they weren't used as a personal attack.

Comment: @Kobi The problem is whenever laws are expanded in such a way that they can (will) become totalitarian. After the so-hated blog post about Be Nice enforcement the new mentality has already been weaponized to silence people for disagreeing.

Comment: As a not-old/not-new user, I feel a lot of "Why didn't you already know that?" on the site. There are many old questions in the database from 8+ years ago that are basic, a bit open-ended, and from people looking to learn, and they received help and upvotes. The same type of questions these days get down-voted with very little constructive feedback.

Comment: If i refer to our recent blog post about handling unwelcoming comment. We may have troubles to define "unwelcoming language". Because there are definitively comments quoted in that "hall of shame" that I don't find unwelcoming. Sure they don't have a "welcoming shape" (thinks about words to decorate the content  you want to post in your comment to make it look better). But a comment is supposed to be short and going to the point IMO. Furthermore you can add the barrier language to make something considered as unwelcoming when it's just rough english...

Comment: Many of us (I think), came initially here to improve ourselves with the perception this was a site from experienced peers to peers. A minimal enforcement of standards on English and being prepared to write a minimum quality question were common sense was exercised, and a small investment in time to write a proper question is not being unwelcoming. Furthermore, this what maintains a minimum amount of quality and non-redundancy in the site. Often closing questions does not prevent people from pointing the askers on the right direction *if the question has a minimum amount of merit*.

Answer (score 301):

I'm not seeing a whole lot in here about meeting our primary expectation: show effort.  I see lots about being more welcoming and not use subtle put downs and the effect of no effort, but the only nod we have to meeting our quality standards is, "Follow our guidelines".

If we're going to be showing this to new users, I think making it understood that we're different and we expect more, we need to acknowledge that we **are** different, and that our expectations very much include a level of effort almost no other site (at least, that I know of) has.

Comment: We also have the revamped /ask page going, which is shaping up to put _much_ more emphasis on pointing out to users where effort seems to be missing. I'm not sure if that weight should fall equally on the CoC or not, but feedback that it seems a little too weighted in favor of those not in the know is definitely standing out. Or, tl;dr; if it were more prominent in places we're more certain new folks _will read_, would you still find it as lacking in this document?

Comment: This is useful information, but I don't think it really fits in a Code of Conduct.

Comment: @TimPost If we're pointing out that, "You could Google this in 5 seconds" is unwelcoming, then I feel it's important that we include the reason people post those in the first place.  Otherwise it seems we're placing greater weight on being welcoming than we are on showing effort, which seems...off, to me. Doesn't have to be much; just in the "If you’re here to get help..." section, extend it from, "Follow our guidelines..." to, "Follow our guidelines, show effort, ...", for example.  That is our core expectation, after all; it deserves mentioning.

Comment: @fbueckert: "*then I feel it's important that we include the reason people post those in the first place*" In the Code of Conduct itself? I fail to see how that helps. One of the most important things about teaching someone something is *focus*. The Code of Conduct is meant to deal with specific behavior; additional statements which do not serve this purpose aren't helpful, no matter how well-meaning such a statement might be. The goal is to explain what is reasonable behavior when addressing one another, not to achieve balance between people.

Comment: @NicolBolas And you don't feel that not including it, but giving an example of, "you should have Googled it" doesn't weight the conduct more towards being welcoming than enforcing our standards?  I get that it's not so much a conduct thing, but I can't help but feel that this is going to come back to bite us, because I believe we're going to get new users pointing to the conduct as justification for not having to meet our standards.

Comment: Perhaps instead of (or in addition to) "Follow our guidelines", a phrase such as "Be eager to learn", "Show interest in your own question", or "Be engaged with your problem" would help with this.  The onus on the helpers is "be supportive while others are learning," while the onus on those being helped is simply "follow our guidelines and don't worry if others suggest changes or edit your question."  There should be an ask stronger than "don't worry" to match "be supportive."

Comment: @fbueckert: The purpose of the Code of Conduct is not to weigh anything more than anything else. It's to teach what is appropriate behavior. Giving an example of inappropriate behavior is useful. Explaining why some people *use* inappropriate behavior is not useful to that purpose.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, purpose or not, it still comes off as such, if you ask me. We already [get enough pedantry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311764/193762) from users when they feel passionately about their posts enough to argue about them.  Clarifying that showing effort is not only good, but *expected*, will go a long way to nipping that in the bud.  As a minimum bar, it doesn't seem like that great an ask.

Comment: @fbueckert We **must** set expectations of new users accurately, _"you're not going to get a whole lot of help here unless you can fill in all these fields"_ - so I totally agree that we need more language, it's just the _where_ that I don't agree with. There's _lots_ of places where new users can go sideways, posting comments as answers is another major pain point, but we're not explicitly calling _that_ out in the CoC. You're right that we need more, but perhaps 'just in time' is a better strategy?

Comment: @fbueckert: Different problems require different solutions. Telling people up-front that low-effort questions aren't appropriate is more likely to be helpful than sticking it in some Code of Conduct page. Confront the user at the appropriate time: when they're trying to ask questions. Don't bury it in some 1000 word document.

Comment: @TimPost I'm open for more improvements, and I'm all on-board with setting those expectations accurately.  As long as those get set, and we see that effort being made, I suppose it doesn't *have* to be in the codes of conduct.  But it just *really* rubs me the wrong way when I see absolutely [no effort questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/144545/20456).  Maybe I'm just heavily biased against laziness, and I want that expectation front and center.  I guess it'd depend on exactly where that expectation goes, so seeing an example would go a long way to assuaging my fears.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's a good point.  What we say is important, as is where we say it.  If it's not in the CoC, then as long as it's easily accessible and makes it very clear that we expect effort, I guess I'd have less issue with excluding it here.

Comment: @NicolBolas Seems like "follow the quality requirements" is part of conduct to me, no?

Comment: @TimPost See above too --^

Comment: @fbueckert I know you can't see deleted comments, but that Borderlands 2 intro question you linked is actually a prime example of established users dogpiling a new user for their lack of effort. The comments still visible on the question are all that *should* have been left. I understand the position of 'show effort first', but if that question was asked today, it would be hypocritical at best to link the question OP the CoC page to make a point about quality/effort in the midst of THAT comment thread. The /ask and /answer pages would be better places to emphasize effort than the CoC.

Comment: -1 for "show effort"; [*"I'm sorry, but... When I'm trying to solve a problem and searching for similar questions on Stack Overflow, I really don't care how much **effort** the asker demonstrates in his question"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/200582). I want question askers to ask clear, answerable, non-duplicate questions whose answers will provide value to future readers. If it takes a week to craft such a question and it ends up 10 paragraphs and a code block long, so be it; but if it achievable in 60 seconds with two sentences, that's *also* fine. Effort is a means, not a goal.

Comment: @MarkAmery Writing a clear, answerable, non-duplicate question **is** effort.  It shows attention paid to writing out the problem, and likely prior research since it's not a duplicate.  I'm not advocating spending hours or days on a question for the sake of it.  I'm just saying we have standards that most of the rest of the internet doesn't, and it's generally a major pain point for new users.  The simplest way I can think of to distill it is to say, "show effort".

Comment: @fbueckert: In my experience, very few users see writing clear, answerable, non-duplicate questions as effort (at least, not enough to satisfy their definition of "effort").

Comment: @TimPost A thought struck me; once we implement this code of conduct, and make our expectations clear, new users will still be free to ignore it all entirely.  Any chance we might be able to make the question ban stricter, so there's ess crap curators have to wade through from users who have demonstrated no ability or desire to conform?

Comment: @TimPost, yes, the CoC needs to address this.  Otherwise, "No [...] unwelcoming language" is in conflict with "Address it directly."  If I tell someone that their question or answer is lacking (relative to our expectations as given in the CoC), then they are likely to perceive it as negative and unwelcoming, no matter how carefully I word my comment.  And we really do want "Address it directly", because the mods can't do it all on their own, and because I don't anyway want to foster a culture of calling in an enforcer whenever something's wrong.

Comment: I think the CoC needs to address the "show effort" expectation, because that expectation is so often a double-edged sword.  While "show effort" is used to screen out treating SE like Google, that rule is also used to justify some of the worst newbie-hostile behavior I've seen.

Answer (score 262):

I'm a bit worried about how specific and absolute the following bit is:

> **If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it.** Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. Even if this wasn’t your intent, apologize and move on.

It reads to me like it allows for no exceptions, and might very, very easily be misused. Just like you sometimes have a storm of chat flags for 'offensive' messages raised on a conversation where people are discussing the weather reports for that day (figuratively), phrasing it in such an absolute way might make this an ideal rule for rules-lawyering and chatroom/comment/post trolling.

I've been on both sides of this: One time I was drawn into a chatroom conversation on periods, and when another user came by and pointed out the amount of detail was uncomfortable for them (I must admit, on closer inspection, it probably crossed the PG13 line), the conversation stopped and we moved on.

On the other hand, I've seen users in the chatroom that weren't acting in good faith, and they'd have a field day with this 'rule', shouting they're uncomfortable with the topic just to stop the conversation and obstruct the community building a good discussion or conversation can achieve. Even discussing site policy in a chatroom might then be cut down.

I'm honestly not sure on how this could be worded better though. On the one hand, I agree we need to be aware that if someone says 'this is making me uncomfortable', people should stop and think, apologize and move on, and people should not be afraid to speak up out of fear of being excluded. On the other hand, I also would hate to see every little thing cut down with an 'I'm no longer comfortable, let's never discuss this!'. I've learned a lot from constructively having uncomfortable conversations.

Is the 'other**s**' here deliberately chosen to point out that there needs to be more than one person uncomfortable before you actually need to take such a complaint seriously?

Who's the **someone** that get's to decide when my behavior is making other**s** uncomfortable and should stop? There are probably situations where people not seeing the problem will say the others are being <...>, and feel empowered to just continue because not one of them has ever experienced their behavior as a problem. So, leaving it entirely to one's own discretion or that of a group of users might not work?

Comment: Agree that it's a thorny matter and not easy to word any better... but at the very least the "someone... others" construction could be changed to "someone... them." I.e. If *I* tell you that *I'm* uncomfortable with the conversation, that's a darn sight better than if I say that "this may be causing (nebulous) others discomfort."

Comment: I'd go further and point out that being told an answer I've put a lot of work into is wrong makes me uncomfortable - at least if my critic is *right*. Some unhappiness is inevitable in any environment where people's hard work gets criticised by others, because *recognising that you've done a bad job at something you cared about* is inherently uncomfortable for most people, me included. And yet Stack Overflow needs criticism to function properly, and that means, almost by definition, that it needs at least *some* behaviours that genuinely and predictably cause discomfort to be permitted.

Comment: @nitsua60 true, but then you'd take a whole lot of power away from moderators. If people are clearly crossing a line you should be able to say 'Hey, this is a no-go because that will exclude a group of people'

Comment: Certainly, ROs and mods should be able to step into a room and say "cut it out." Problem is there's a whole spectrum of issues here, I suppose. 1. The chatizen who is bothered but is nervous about speaking up. 2. The chatizen who has seen people be bothered *by the activity in question, in this room* and wants to speak up. 3. The chatizen who has seen people be bothered *by the activity in question* but not in this room who thinks maybe they should speak up. 4. The chatizen who's trollishly manipulating others' genuine concern. In any case, this'll also apply the second bullet of Chat TL;DR

Comment: Oh, and I am struggling as well with 5. the chatizen that speaks up about a legitimate issue but receives pushback/is ignored.

Comment: The tone used in speaking up can have an effect in the way it is received. If you come out swinging and linking to blog posts/CoC you're likely to be pushed back against.

Comment: @KevinB, as much as I'd love people to be perfectly polite, nice and well-spoken when speaking up, that's often not one's number one priority if one is upset and uncomfortable. So, even if the message isn't conveyed in the most optimal terms, I'd love to see people think about their actions and react in a considerate way... I think immediate pushback is one of those things that aren't really nice, but in the end there might be someone to overrule this? Someone that says 'well, thanks for stopping this today, but in the future you can totally have this conversation/say this out loud' maybe?

Comment: I'd hate to see people receiving pushback because of a technicality in their message...

Comment: Reading the [Exact Words](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExactWords), the complaint has to point out a "behavior [that] *is making others uncomfortable*".  So more than one person has to be uncomfortable, not merely the person complaining?

Comment: @Paul We should also realistically stop behaviour that's making one person uncomfortable, so I think that's an overly legalistic interpretation of the rule in spite of its spirit. Its wording is still a problem even then though: now we just need two trolls in the same place, which is frequently the case.

Comment: Isn't the other side of the sentence also available for an easy fix?  Rather than the absolute "stop", what if it's simply "If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, strongly consider stopping what you're doing."

Comment: I know for a fact many questions on skeptics, politics, philosophy and interpersonal relations will make people unconfortable. On the first page of politics, for example, we have: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31938/; https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16025/; https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31948/why-do-one-party-states-hold-elections; https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/590/; https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31871/

Comment: On interpersonal (not first page): https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/how-to-deal-with-someone-who-always-takes-but-never-gives-back; https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/10783/how-do-i-tell-my-parents-i-dont-enjoy-their-company/11020#11020; https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6481/what-pronoun-to-use-when-talking-about-a-transgender-persons-past

Comment: this is a very broad, poorly formulated 'rule'. Maybe it should be narrower, and only apply to more explicit interactions (call the bothered person A. Such explicit interactions could be answering A's questions and commenting on A's answers, mentioning A on chat). Surely you should not stop asking questions about a subject just because it bothers someone!

Comment: The passage is simply horrible because according to my current knowledge *nobody is able to read minds*. At least if myself is targeted, I can voice my concern (and even then I can abuse it to suppress criticism because *nobody actually can confirm or refute that I am uncomfortable*). *Other* people who have no insight *in other people's mind* should speak for them?! **I would like to retain the normative power to be offended or being uncomfortable for myself and nobody else, thank you very much**. As Tinkeringbell pointed out, this is a feast for trolls.

Comment: Apart from that, SE has so many different cultures and viewpoints that not offending anyone will be quite a task. So what cultural standard do we use to decide if something is uncomfortable for a person?

Comment: @Mark Amery: Yeah, a lot of this niceness/kindness/compassion stuff seems to be boiling down to "stop telling people things they don't want to hear". Yeah, well, telling someone that their behavior is unacceptable *is* making them uncomfortable - look at the people getting angry that a CoC is being written at all (not referring to those who have specific issues with the draft).

Comment: As a guideline it is good, the question is always if it is a law. A guideline is something, which may be wrong sometimes, but is true most the time and people can judge it case by case. A law means it must be acted up on, which is a problem with many cocs which seems not to be present here.

Comment: I think it's great to have a cultural expectation to try to avoid causing others discomfort, including making reasonable accommodation that could involve closing off lines of discussion.  But I agree that coming down fully on the side of any person who becomes uncomfortable for any reason is not sensible or workable.  We should make *reasonable* accommodation to *try* to avoid causing *most* discomfort.  That's a codification of "be nice".  But nobody has a right to expect never to be made uncomfortable.  Part of being nice to others is growing a thick skin.

Comment: The way to resolve this is to add the concept of a "reasonable person" like there is in law. If a reasonable person would feel uncomfortable then fine, but unreasonable trolls can be dismissed.

Comment: @user that still carries the problem of who's reasonable and who's not... It doesn't solve who decides which users should be listened to and which users can safely be ignored. Also, this is world-wide-web network. Which means there's stuff so culturally diverse on some sites (and probably most chatrooms), that just ignorance of a culture can result in a verdict of 'unreasonable'.

Comment: This answer makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: I already have an [example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer?noredirect=1#comment1012699_310061) of the CoC being weaponized. This is already happening.

Comment: @EthanTheBrave Weird that the CoC was being weaponized at that time, because there was no CoC draft at the time that post was written. Honestly, I think there's another answer written already that perfectly expresses how the whole CoC might be used more as a weapon than a shield, it might be better to move your comment to that one... This answer was written purely to express my worries about the specific phrasing used to express this idea, not as a 'the whole CoC is a bad idea' type of post. I actually agree with the fact that people should be free to speak up and taken seriously.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell We were talking about the proposed changes to the Code of Conduct in the comments linked. Also, people *are (currently)* free to speak up and be taken seriously on Stack Exchange - a lot freer than most places anyway. I agree though that a Code of Conduct is not a bad idea, but these policies are being drafted up like safe-space-culture totalitarian 'laws' and I'm going to be railing against them until i see something different.

Comment: @EthanTheBrave if that's what you're trying to do, then writing your own answer really might be a better idea than writing comments underneath the answer of a person that isn't railing against it ;-) It might help to convey there's people feeling even worse about this than just me having a few doubts...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell: I found it unnecessary to give yet another answer directly mentioning it again. We're mostly programmers here and the impossibly of an all-inclusive society makes the no discrimination dangerous and when it fails the text is used as a club against our mind-type so we are sensitive to such things in the CoC.

Comment: The quoted rule is a great rule of thumb for oneself, and no so great as a codification to apply with any rigidity to others.  One fundamental mistake codified by this rule is that some people must be *final judge* who is in the wrong.  Since that can't be the badly-behaving person (the thought goes) it must be the rest of the group. In reality, there are no infallible judges of good behaviour.  We do what we think best with that limited knowledge of course: that's fine.  The point is that this misconception supports the bad idea that ANY discomfort is bad, and the crowd the infallible judge.

Comment: *chatroom conversation on periods* - I was picturing users discussing punctuation marks in detail.

Comment: When somebody points out that the use of 'he' to describe a user is not appropriate in a particular case, that may well make the user of 'he' uncomfortable. But not pointing out that people make unjustified assumptions about the gender (race, sexual orientation, disability status ...) or others perpetuates discrimination. There's a tension in the code between no-discrimination and no-discomfort-or-offence. Somebody referring to a same sex partner in chat might make others uncomfortable. So might mentioning going to Mass. Offence is not the problem. Harm is the problem.

Answer (score 250):

> No subtle put-downs or *unwelcoming language*

(emphasis mine).

I get that the idea is to broadly categorize "not nice" but it seems to me like this is easily mis-interpreted.

Are:

- Sorry, but this question is too broad. A good Stack Overflow question doesn't encompass an entire program, but a specific programming problem.
- Questions are expected to be in English on Stack Overflow, until this is translated this question will be put on hold (for languages without a localized version)
- Questions asking for an off-site resource are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow.

problematic? I would assume the sane answer is no but none of them are particularly *welcoming*. Quite the opposite, they all say **your question is not welcome here**. And those questions *aren't* welcome here. And yet; they could easily be contrived to violate the CoC.

OPs already respond shall we say, negatively, to very similar comments (no snarkasm) *all the time*. Quite commonly with something along the lines of:

> You don't have to be such a jerk and downvote my question. I'm just looking for help

(Source: repeated experience. At least once a week, so common I wrote [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) )

So reinforcing this behavior by stating that we have to be welcoming *no matter what* to *any possible post* seems like the wrong message to be sending, especially to the volunteers.

Comment: Indeed, the standard question closure reasons themselves pretty plainly contain "unwelcoming language" - that's their *point*. Supposedly banning "unwelcoming language" when it's a deliberate and important part of the site's official messaging is incoherent.

Comment: How about instead of "unwelcoming language" we say "exclusionary language"? I think language that excludes folks from the community is easier to identify than "unwelcoming" language.

Comment: @ColleenV: Synonym hunting may be useful for fixing unclear meaning, but the phrase in question is both clear and wrong.  Questions that are off-topic are unwelcome, excluded, discouraged, forbidden, and any similar word.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think that "exclusionary language" has come to be strongly associated with excluding people (not content) and has a much more negative connotation than "unwelcoming". I think "not welcoming" is kind of a neutral response. I'm not particularly excited you're here, but I'm not trying to drive you away. It's kind of sad that we have to try to describe the difference between having content standards and being uncivil, but if we're going to do it we should try to pick the clearest language we can. Apparently "I know it when I see it" isn't a good enough standard.

Comment: @ColleenV: The problem is that the connotations that you associate with it, are not shared by every user worldwide.  Therefore it's important that the plain English meaning makes sense, not just what the author strongly associates it with.

Comment: imho: The distinction should be: * *welcoming* towards the _participants_ themselves, but * *unwelcome* towards bad question ***and*** bad behaviour. ... Calling out bad behaviour and off-topic or poor questions _should be_ acceptable, _provided that_ it doesn't get personal. (_This distinction should be made clear in the CoC._)

Comment: Further to my previous comment, and something to be considered independently of this Q&A: more effort should be put into providing template responses to unwelcome _behaviour_. Sometimes people take criticism of their ***bad behaviour*** personally simply because they realise it reflects poorly on them (even if there's nothing personal about the criticism). So template comments with parameter fields can assist in allowing commenters to provide the feedback with minimum risk of causing unintended offence.

Comment: just say exclusionary of a protected class (and enumerate the protected classes: gender, race, cis/trans, gay/straight, nationality -- with the caveat that the sites operate in one or two languages each). Just say what you mean, and be narrow. It'll be better to add classes latter, than to end up with people that misinterpret the rule completely

Comment: I just asked a question and someone added a comment saying "This might be an XY problem.  [...]". This really upset me (pissed me off). Saying that my question is an XY problem basically comes down to saying that I'm stupid and don't know what I want or how to formulate it. Does this mean that person should stop using that phrase? Or will a moderator decide if he is right (and I DID ask the wrong question)? Bottom line, people WILL be offended ALL of the time. You can't use their feelings as a guideline, ever.

Comment: @CarloWood: The "X Y problem" was created deliberately and specifically for helping newcomers with their questions, but you're reading it as insulting.  The very last thing it intends to do is insult people or tell them they are stupid.  That you've decided to interpret it this way is unfortunate, but I don't really see how there's much we can do about that.

Comment: @CarloWood Sorry to hear that you had such a negative experience. What would be a different terminology which would get the same information to you (or to other askers) without feeling insulting? I am assuming here that you indeed had an XY problem. If you didn't (I never saw your question and cannot judge that), please answer for a hypothetical case in which you do have it, because we do need *some* way to explain that to people, and having been at the receiving end, you are probably better qualified to suggest a better term.

Comment: @rumtscho My main point was my last line, related to the new CoC. Nevertheless, to answer your question; the reason it annoyed me (would be the better word) is because I don't ask XY questions (to put into perspective, I have been coding 40 years and an IQ of 165). When I ask a question at guru level and someone approaches you as if you're a little kid, then that is annoying. I don't see how that can be changed either; I was just using this case as an example of why you shouldn't write a CoC saying that if you do or say something that upsets people that then you're automatically wrong.

Comment: @RobertHarvey- but you've missed the point.  Carlo was made (very) uncomfortable by the "XY problem" comment, and therefore it is quite clearly unacceptable under the stated CoC.  There's absolutely no wriggle room in the CoC for whether the offence was intended - in fact quite the opposite, it's very clear that Carlo's reaction alone makes that "XY problem" wording unacceptable under the this CoC.

Comment: @CarloWood So you're really offended that someone suggests you might be going down the wrong rabbit hole? I would think that with someone of 40 years of coding experience and a high IQ would take it in stride and be eager to hear alternative ideas. Perhaps the alternative ideas don't pan out, but it seems silly to get worked up at the mere suggestion that you might have posed an XY problem.

Comment: "No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language"-This rule is not enforced on this site at all and that is harming the reputation of SE along with everyone on there.

Comment: @35093731895230467514051 I'm not sure what you are getting at; I think SE agrees that its not enforced (which is why its part of the proposed CoC). This answer is pointing out that the "unwelcoming language" bit is so broad as to be actively harmful to our moderation tasks.

Comment: Actually, the first one could be formulated more welcoming. For example: “Please reduce your question to a specific programming problem. Questions about full programs are considered too broad on Stack Overflow.” That way you'd put the focus on how to make the question acceptable, while the current formulation puts the focus on how it is not acceptable as is.

Comment: TL;dr: we don't welcome crap.

Answer (score 225):

> **No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language**. Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle put-down.

This reads like I'm stranded in a scifi dystopia. Now I have a *language* police. Great.

> *Beloved Citizen of the most free Democratic People's Republic. Please kindly check your language before you use it. Should you accidentally overstep the boundaries set by our beloved guidelines, our helpful employees of the department of oral corrections will gently escort you to the nearest improvement facility.*

Now that sounds like a fun land to live in, doesn't it?

---

I don't care about polite or sugar coating. What I would want to see is **friendly** and **constructive**. Please note that friendly is not the same as polite. I can lose a hand in poker to friend, flash a big smile and say "you are an asshole" and it might be friendly. In my country police officers are *polite* and will ask you to "please come with me, sir" but you can tell that they are *not* friendly. That's plain politeness. I have little use for the latter, but I expect the former from a community. Both would be ideal, but my priorities are on friendliness, not politeness. Politeness is an empty gesture. Like wearing a suit. I prefer a friend in jeans any day over an idiot in a suit.

So lets give it a try without that language police involved:

> **Be friendly and constructive**. If you have to criticize, help the user by showing up a way to improve. For example, saying "you could have Googled this" is not adding any value on the path to a solution to the given problem. Instead, "This is called Invariance and Covariance, put it into Google, there are tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in a comment here." gives a clear direction how to proceed forward.

Comment: *`that can explain it much better than we can in a comment`* Well...that's what answers are for, really, not comments. But I see the point trying to be made: there are resources, research was not done, and we would like to communicate to the asker that this is the case.

Comment: @Draco18s While true, the instances I posted something like this, the actual explanation on Google was too long for an answer and the whole question should have been closed as "too broad". But I think such a comment is better then *just* the VtC, because it points to something to do, instead of simply telling somebody "no".

Comment: Oh I agree that the comment is indeed *appropriate.* I'm just quibbling over the language *of* that comment.

Comment: English is not my native language, I'm open to improvements. I think you got what I'm trying to say though.

Comment: \*Salute\* Just trying to help. :)

Comment: You have some constructive feedback here that I'd like to see incorporated into the CoC, but then you preface it with a LOT of sarcasm.  Is the sarcasm really necessary?  If your answer just started at the line, it would be a good comment

Comment: @FuzzyChef You're being the language police referred to in the answer.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I think it's a good means to transport how much I loathe the idea of a language police (or policy). Without it, it would basically be "this could be improved" and that's only half of what I want to say. It can be improved *because as written it's so oppressive it would make most dictators proud*. That half should not be lost. However, I do appreciate your comment on how it could be better from your point of view. As long as there is no secret mod society suspending me for my language, I'm perfectly fine openly discussing it's use with anybody.

Comment: +1 for the wording suggestion at the end, but I really agree the sarcasm at the start doesn't help you make a case. That kind of thing has people [flip the bozo bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bozo_bit#Dismissing_a_person_as_not_worth_listening_to) and decide the rest isn't worth reading, so I'm hoping people will be reading the second half *in spite* of the first half. Pointing out people will be afraid that it's a trap they might fall into is also pretty reasonable, but I would wish it wasn't also buried among the sarcasm.

Comment: The sarcasm made me understand clearly the point at first glance, without need of excessive and confuse explanation. +1

Comment: I would change that middle line to "there are tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an **answer** here.". Then it becomes clear that the post is actually too broad in that example.

Comment: Your rewording is *so much* better than the original, I'm impressed.  This is exactly the sort of improvement that I'm talking about [in my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312070/307622); you've taken it further.

Comment: @Draco18s Answers are supposed to be self contained.  Link-only answers are not considered good style, so a comment is more than appropriate for this kind of situation.

Comment: @FuzzyChef While I wouldn't have chosen to use sarcasm in an answer to this question myself, there's no reason to assume the contempt is for a specific person rather than for the idea (an idea that, yes, may steer people in the direction of being a specific badly-acting person later on -- but that's nobody here, and it's the purpose of this debate to avoid such outcomes).  That's a critical distinction.  "Let our ideas die in our place": rather in the spirit of this website, I would say.

Comment: I do agree that friendliness should be preferred over politeness, but the problem is that the communication quality is greatly reduced over the web. Saying _"you're an asshole"_ is inherently hostile, but said along with a friendly gesture, tone, and a close relationship, the whole statement changes meaning. The same with _"please come here, sir"_ said by a friend and a smile. At the web we mostly get just the text and the reader herself/himself have to fill in the rest. Thrown together with the fact that everyone is from different upbringings, this leaves big risks for misinterpretations.

Comment: As I see it, politeness acts as a middle ground for text based communication. Although far from perfect, writing something that’s not hostile in it’s actual meaning (i.e. politeness) removes one possibility of misinterpretation. Since it’s hard to guess how someone will take one’s message, just being polite is a simple fallback guideline. But as you said, politeness is not friendliness, and friendliness should come first. And your rewrite is a great improvement over the current CoC, as it emphasizes what to do, instead of what not to do, along with a nice, concrete example.

Comment: Good point. I also like the humor (no idea why some people call it sarcasm). If someone asks a question and you want to help them, then you can give a (friendly) answer. If the stupidness of the OP, or his lack of research etc, upsets you to the point that you want to make him feel bad for it (subtly, we wouldn't want to be tapped on the fingers by the moderators) then just click away and answer another question. The key here is to be (warm) friendly and thus helpful only, without shining through irritation. +1

Comment: If someone posts a program and misspells a variable name, and I tell them they've misspelt a variable name, I'm not going to eat my heart out worrying about whether my answer is a subtle put-down. And if someone comments that my answer wasn't nice enough, I will interpret that comment as a not-too-subtle put down.

Answer (score 150):

> **No discrimination of any kind.** This includes any language likely to offend or alienate people based on (but not limited to): ...English fluency,...

It seems strange to say that we shouldn't/won't discriminate based on English fluency. I think the goal of including "English fluency" in the above list is to stop people from saying subtle put-downs like: "Did you pass second grade?", "Do you speak English?", etc. But that seems to be handled by other sections of the Code of Conduct. More importantly, most Stack Exchange sites must discriminate on the basis of English fluency.

For an extreme example, if a fluent Spanish speaker has zero English fluency, they should not and cannot post on the default Stack Overflow (English) site. This is true for most Stack Exchange sites. Of course the same would be true for non-English sites like Stack Overflow (Russian). The community members there discriminate against me. Since I'm not fluent in the language, I cannot post there.

The best possible interpretation of including "English fluency" in the list of attributes that cannot be discriminated against is that you are trying to stop subtle put-downs directed towards people who write mostly understandable posts, but with minor flaws that often come with not being a native speaker. The worst interpretation is that this is Stack Overflow (the company) once again trying to lower the standards (in a top-down way) so that anyone can participate and not feel left out.

Either way, it seems like this is an unnecessary element in the Code of Conduct since subtle put-downs based on language fluency are already disallowed and discrimination based on whether people can communicate is necessary on every Stack Exchange site.

Comment: As someone who is a native English speaker but has from time to time had to make myself understood in French and Spanish, I respectfully disagree.  English is the defacto common language in tech but most people have to learn English.  I have seen French, Spanish and Chinese who are learning technical English successfully ask and answer questions on SO and I think that they should be included.

Comment: @empty, I agree with most of what you said. I'm happy for anyone to contribute to StackOverflow whether they are a native speaker or just recently learned English. But there is still a standard on all the sites that you must be able to communicate, and that requires a certain level of English fluency. If people are under a certain level, we cannot communicate and thus those posters will be discriminated against by having posts deleted. The same is true for me if I tried to post on Russian StackOverflow.

Comment: Google Translate is a beautiful thing.  But it has its limits. :-)

Comment: @empty The people who "successfully ask and answer questions on SO" are those with good enough English to be welcome here.  I think stiemannkj1's point is more in the spirit of "you're not tall enough to ride this ride": it's not their fault and they're welcome back when they're taller, but they can't do it _now_.  (That said, I think the proposed policy would still allow deleting those questions, we just couldn't explain to them why, or would have to be hyper-polite in doing so and hope they're fluent enough to pick up on that.)

Comment: @empty as a non-native speaker, I follow stiemannkj1 actually. If I can't comprehend what you're asking, it's impossible to help you. I don't expect correct grammar, punctuation or sentence structure (most native speakers can't get that right either). As long as I can understand what you're asking, all is fine. But there have been a significant amount of questions consisting of a seemingly random sequence of close-to-english words that don't make sense regardless of the order you put them in.

Comment: @JorisMeys I agree that a question has to be comprehensible.  Word-for-word translation of high context languages like Japanese is poetic but very difficult to understand.  But the point is about _fluency_.  I can make myself understood very well in French and Spanish but I would hardly call myself fluent.  Fluency is "the ability to speak or write a foreign language easily and accurately or
the ability to express oneself easily and articulately."  As long as somebody can get their meaning across, I'm fine with answering their question and even editing it.

Comment: @empty I think we're understanding "English fluency" in the context of the CoC differently. You seem to be understanding it as meaning " one who is fluent in English" whereas I understand it to mean "the degree to which one is fluent in English". stiemannkj1, I think, is not proposing that we discriminate against people who are not fluent in English, but that we discriminate against people who are below a certain threshold of fluency (that is the degree to which they are fluent).

Comment: @called2voyage I agree with you.

Comment: I tend to disagree a little bit here. Discrimination on English fluency is different than just stating that a contributor should be more clear, and shouldn't contribute if they're not. Stating that an answer is ambiguous and should be clarified is OK; stating that the answer is understandable for you but might not be for others because of millions of grammar and syntax errors isn't OK, and the answer should be edited, not criticized because of that.

Comment: Thanks @JorisMeys for your clarifying comments. I agree with most of what you said. I do think we need to expect a certain level of correct grammar, punctuation, sentence structure etc. as well though. You could make the argument that we need that structure **for** the less-fluent folks. As a native speaker, I find it pretty easy to decipher broken English in most cases, but less fluent people might have even more trouble understanding grammatically incorrect language.

Comment: Also, if we consider that many if not most of the traffic to these sites is for technical Q&A, it's important to be extremely clear in communication. That's hard even for native speakers, but may be impossible for someone who just learned English last month.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος, are you saying it's not okay for users to respond to a poorly written post by saying: "Please fix your grammar."? It seems like you are saying that people should never criticize a post for being riddled with grammatical errors but should take it upon ourselves to fix the issues. I have no problem with people fixing grammar, but I also have no problem with people saying: "The grammar in this post is poor, and the post is hard to understand because of it. Please fix it." I don't think posters are entitled to have others fix their writing.

Comment: I cannot help *but* to discriminate based on English fluency. If a person is not fluent enough in English for me to understand the question, I cannot help them with whatever their problem is.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I guess the border is when the English on the post is so broken that most of the readers cannot comprehend it (aka. the VLQ flag), like: "CoC this will very useful if human-human possible follow" (word-per-word translation from "This CoC will be very useful if users can follow it" in my native language)

Comment: @stiemannkj1 I meant that, if you understand what the poster means, but are afraid somebody else won't, then should come an edit. If it's challenging for yourself too, of course you shouldn't edit it (and post a kind comment instead, some things are just harder to say kindly anyway).

Comment: I would be beware of double standards. I have lost countless hours improve the English of others posts (and mine), with a special mention honour to a very good answer of a Russian user, where it was quite difficult to all all the adjectives missing. However, some low quality answers are beyond help. If the OP is not willing to invest his time in a good question for his own benefit, why should the onus fall on others?

Comment: One of the first sentences says: *"Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of... language."* As far as I know, all people are not welcome regardless of language and English is a requirement for most sites. Given that this sentence seems to be an overarching preamble, I would remove any mention of language from it and instead cover it in detail in the body. I think it should be made clear that English is required while also reassuring non-native speakers that they won't be discriminated against for an honest effort.

Comment: I'd upvote this twice if I could. :) I spend a lot of time helping OPs clarify their question, but sometimes the language barrier makes it very difficult. It can get frustrating, both for the OP and the commenters, when both sides have difficulty deciphering what the other side is saying. If the OP's fluency is too low, I just VTC as "Unclear", and move on, but in borderline classes I like to try & help.

Comment: (cont) Of course, there's no excuse to be rude to someone due to their low English fluency. Sometimes I suggest they get a friend to help them rewrite the post with better English, but I suppose that _could_ be interpreted as a put-down if it's not said carefully, or if the OP is feeling defensive. I'm a little concerned that the CoC may _discourage_ people from making helpful comments in good faith, for fear that they will be perceived as being discriminatory.

Comment: This reminds me of a particular user who doesn't think we're discriminating against them based on their English fluency, but thinks we're discriminating against their view that English grammatical rules are a matter of writing style and we should refrain from editing their content because what we think is grammatically incorrect is in fact grammatically correct to *them*.

Comment: English fluency covers people complaining about the exact wording of a question rather than making a good faith effort to understand and improve/answer it.

Comment: If StackExchange truly cared about language discrimination, they would set up Stackoverflow in hundreds of languages like Wikipedia and Wikimedia wikis.

Answer (score 130):

I'd like to see

> Unacceptable Behavior
>
> No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language. Regardless of intent,
>   this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For
>   example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle
>   put-down.

Extended to include something like:

> If other community members have decided to offer you constructive feedback and suggest improvements, do not insult or harass them for it. For instance, insults (subtle or obvious) against users who chose to moderate your contributions is not acceptable. "Which idiot downvoted this?!" would be an example of unacceptable conduct.

This would make it clear that this policy and code of conduct cuts both ways, and would serve to assuage fears that volunteers are being asked to make an undue extra effort to be welcoming while no such effort is expected from new users. I'm sure that's not your intention in formulating this, but why not be proactive to dispel such fears right now? It'd work fine to further explain this paragraph, too:

> If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to
>   help you. Our community is made possible by volunteers. Follow our
>   guidelines and don't worry if others suggest changes or edit your
>   question - they’re trying to make your question helpful to as many
>   people as possible.

I'm also confused why serial voting and sockpuppetry is included in the code of conduct - that seems more like a terms of service technicality thing. From my reading of it, the code of conduct deals exclusively with intrapersonal and social conduct perusing the network, while a sockpuppet account is technically gaming the system to multiply or amplify your voting power - not something you'd normally conflate with actual verbal or written abuse.

Comment: I cannot iterate enough, I agree with putting some focus on, not being abusive towards those members who choose to help moderate the quality of the contributions (through the review queue).  While there have been instances of, where I have unintentionally was always been a perfect gentlemen towards other users, I believe those exceptions were sometimes caused by subtle abusive behavior directed towards me (i.e. users who disagreed with a flag/close vote).  I sometimes have difficulity determining when it's time for a flag.

Comment: I really like the phrasing of your last paragraph - "the code of conduct deals exclusively with intrapersonal and social conduct" - this is something that bothered me too, but you've said it much better.

Comment: I strongly disagree.  The proposed new sentences have [too much emphasis on the negative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312070/307622).  **Insult, harass, idiot, unacceptable.**

Comment: @Wildcard So do you want to remove the other examples then too? The example Magisch provided is something that happens everyday.

Comment: Re: serial voting & sockpuppetry - agree this could probably be removed.

Comment: Re: being clearer that the CoC cuts both ways - I hear your point and would love more information. Do you have more examples of misconduct toward users who moderate content quality? I'm particularly interested in examples of subtle insults that you've directly observed/experienced. cc @Ramhound

Comment: @Donna If you want some examples of not-so-subtle comments, you can see some [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733/1197934).

Comment: @Donna It’s been a combination of small things over 7 years.  While I might have came on too strong in some cases, I have been called a drug addict, in a recent case after I thought the question was about Office 2003 instead of Office 2013.  In other cases I have been insulted for throwing possible duplicate flags on question.  I often, if I believe I will be attacked for flagging a question, will delete the “possible duplicate” comment to avoid being pinged by the author.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRRjM.jpg) is an example of the hostility that is often received by users of the review queue.  I linked the question in a chat, and the user apparently decided to delete their account (they had answered numerous questions), instead of serving their suspension (to the credit of the moderators it happened quickly).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. These are really helpful (although I'm sorry y'all had to dig these not-so-nice things up). I think we can be clearer that the CoC cuts both ways.

Comment: @Donna I dug up a compilation of just some that another user has compiled [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366692/how-do-you-know-stack-overflow-feels-unwelcoming/366733#366733). If you can ignore the general tone of the answer, I don't think they were making any of those up. Often times it also takes on the form of something like "Which idiot downvoted this" or "If you don't want to answer, stop annoying me" or similar such lesser put downs. Not entirely grating in and of itself, albeit very discouraging.

Comment: Serial downvoting is a clear example of "not being welcoming" so it has its place in the Code of Conduct. I would also add serial deletion of proper answers without a reasonable motive, but that only happens on IPS so it would be site-specific.

Comment: @Magisch Interestingly enough that question is locked, you cannot upvote it and on its way for deletion. We all have been on the receiving end of similar comments when helping with moderation, there is no way around beating the bush trying to ignore it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Actually, only the answer itself is locked.  The question is not, and I rather doubt the answer will be deleted.

Comment: I compiled that answer, and would have continued to add to the list as yet more curator-abuse came in.  The mods etc didn't like it continually bumped and locked it, which is fair enough.  I can confirm that none of the entries in that list were made up - they were all copypasta from 'real' comments.  Imma saving up the new ones now, eg: 'I feel that the StackExchange moderator community is a hostile mob of snobs posing as intellectuals who would rather write parking tickets than teach anybody how to do anything.'.

Comment: I used to just ignore minor annoyances like 'If you don't know answer, just move on and stop with the toxic downvoting'.  I will now r/a flag any such comments immediately.

Comment: @MartinJames Thats honestly a good policy. Those are unnecessary and unhelpful, so good riddance to such commentary.

Comment: I've got pretty thick skin, so unless someone's being pretty vicious, I generally don't flag as rude, even if they're attacking me.  But I think I might have to start, as currently I try to welcome new users, but clearly they often don't deserve that level of leeway.

Comment: @fbueckert well, yes.  If is now recommended that all users report snark etc. that can be seen as violating the CoC, well, OK ,that applies to curators too.   I mean, I would like to flag all h/w/requirement dump questions as rude/abusive, but I suspect that would be too much for the 'blog & tatter' set to swallow, such unwelcome OP's being a protected species now.

Comment: @MartinJames Oh, trust me.  I'd love to just straight up murder certain question types.  I think there's lots there that just doesn't interest experts, but we're now expected to handle because we're the place to be.  That'd make me *very* happy.  We have certain question classes that *are* off-topic at Arqade, and we get lots of pushback from askers and defenders.  So we're already accused of being elitest.  I'm curious to see how just straight up downvoting and closing questions is going to come off; I suspect the perception is only going to get worse.

Comment: I wonder if the sockpuppet behavior thing is just a subtle nod to the fact that cheating the system generally isn't very nice to others anyway.

Comment: `If other community members have decided to offer you constructive feedback and suggest improvements, do not insult or harass them for it`... That's nice enough in concept, but this can be an issue of people choosing to help you with things you didn't ask for help on, for some personal benefit (upvotes, etc). It's distracting. It's advice I didn't ask for, and therefore unwelcome. You don't know where people are on their journey, so mind your own business.

Answer (score 130):

I've already added two answers of things I think should be changed based on objective criteria. This is subjective and my "feelings toward" things, so it's a separate post.

> If you're a long-term contributor, how does this document impact your feelings toward new users and their needs, if at all?

If anything, it makes me reconsider whether I should help newcomers *at all*. I'm not here for gaming or other hobbies where a suspension might be a nuisance over the weekend, those SE sides are a side-effect of me hanging out on the professional sites. **My account is a professional resource.** <sup>(1)</sup> Of the 300+ days a year I use Stack Overflow, sometimes even before I had my first coffee, I'm sure there will be a day or two where I get snarky if I see a poster that shows no effort. I'm only human. I think it goes without saying, but I say it anyway: I'm talking about sarcasm or snark here. No insults, no harassment.

This document is made to tell me that I jeopardize my professional resource by commenting. So I will simply not do that anymore or only with accounts I recognize as friendly. I will downvote those that don't conform 100% to the rules instead of commenting and trying to help. That is a safe action. I think it's **unfriendly** and **not welcoming**, but it's safe from punishment by the thought- and/or language police.

My experience says that sites that already drive "be nice" to higher levels suspend people for things I don't want to be suspended for. I *have* been suspended for basically repeatedly saying that I think specific actions of the moderators are *unprofessional*. Yes, that's how badass insulting I am when I'm really mad: "*unprofessional*". I really rock it. I should become a rapper. Saying it too often got me a suspension for "Abuse of Moderators". If that is abuse, we definitely need a new term for what you are describing in the CoC. By the way, it took [5 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296310/contact-us-and-then-what) to even get somebody but the original mods to look at that suspension. So no, there is no trust from my side that SE can handle a policy like that and it's fallout. Because not only the user-base grew, the moderator base too. And those, too, are not this tight-knit group you once knew by heart.

And again, I will not risk a professional resource on the off-chance that a mod might have a nice day when I have a bad one. If being human once in a while means I lose my account, I will immediately stop helping people that don't know the ropes here and need help.

I will leave that task to all the new people who will come in and contribute because it's so "nice" now (how was that sentence on the snark level? Close to being suspended already?).

> How does it impact your feelings toward the company?

It feels like you guys got off course. I see the ugliness that sites invite that make the user tell their personal problems. And all the harassment that follows. That's not SE or SO. SO (and I guess everything around it, like superuser, dba, programming etc) has always been about relatively neutral information exchange. I care whether someone can solve my programming problem. I have no need for information about gender or age or skin color and there is no discrimination based on those properties if the users don't *have* those properties. Yes, once you expose those properties creepy people come out, because creepy people *exist*. Everywhere. That hasn't changed and you will not change it with a Code of Conduct either.

I said it in a comment earlier: I'm here because I'm a professional and I'm looking for a solution to my professional problem. Being a professional sometimes means you have to put up with stuff. Just ask a random waitress if "professional" means everybody is nice to them all the time. I will take any amount of snark or sarcasm or any other type of comment *if there is a tiny chance it helps me solve my problem*. Because *that* is my priority. Solving my problem. *Not* being nice, *not* being welcomed. *Solving my problem*. I can ignore any comment I don't like, but I cannot ignore not getting a solution.

It does not feel like that is your focus anymore.

---

Clarifications:

<sup>(1)</sup> My account is a "professional resource" because I develop software as a job. StackOverflow is a valuable resource for that, I use it multiple times a day. You can get free professional advice there. Every single software developer I know uses it to look things up multiple times during their working day. My reputation allows me to put bounties on my own question or ask for clarification from others. Threatening me with a suspension is threatening access to that resource.

Comment: +1 because I think you're raising an important point: the tension that exists between (for lack of better terms) professional and hobby use of the Network. (And I think this helps me understand better some of your comments/posts elsewhere.) Notwithstanding, if this new CoC makes someone think "I'm not at my 100% Nicest today, maybe I shouldn't comment" then it may be Mission Accomplished on that front. On the other hand, if it makes someone think "I'm not at my 100% Nicest today, maybe I shouldn't *answer*" that seems a different kettle of fish.

Comment: I wish we had, say, 10 upvotes that we could spread across answers to a single question in whatever way we could, because I would put all 10 on this answer if I could. The concept of *professional behavior* is the most important thing. I'd much prefer a simple code of conduct that says "Act as if your boss was going to read everything you say here, so be on your best professional behavior" and leave it at that. Now, for the many students who come to this site, they might need a longer explanation of professional behavior... but *professional behavior* should be at the core of the CoC.

Comment: Totally agree. You cannot police people based on feelings. Especially when an indispensable professional tool is at stake. Common decency should be enough  for everyone. Noone participates in a community to offend people... And if they are, it will be obvious without using really blurry moral red lines placed by someone's feelings.

Comment: *Down vote and press on* has been recommended to me at various times at each of the SE sites where I contribute as the expected SE interactive model.  Your point on this particular initiative encouraging that behavior pattern is well made.

Comment: @nitsua60 most of programming I've done as hobbyist, yet I've seem to be able to ask non-controversial questions.

Comment: I'm glad you're raising the conduct of moderators. In the near-decade I've used StackExchange sites, I've generally found them respectful and reasonably friendly spaces, at least for me, a cis, white, male, English-speaking, professional forty-something. But most of the problems I _have_ witnessed were caused by moderators, when they seemed more interested in a power trip than providing guidance to people making honest mistakes, including myself in one or two cases. Maybe this has been addressed in the last year or two, but I think this is a point less `l33t` users should make the call on.

Answer (score 126):

I'd like to add some additional clarity to **Our Expectations**

1. > **If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming.** Learning how to participate in our community can be daunting, especially if someone is new. Be supportive while others are learning.

   Yeah, the whole **welcoming** bit didn't go so well. It's too vague. This is aimed squarely at curators, and [I wrote a Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367016/curation-and-cynicism-or-why-stack-overflow-sometimes-doesnt-seem-welcoming) about why curators are cynical. So I would proposed this

   > **If you're here to answer questions, or moderate content, please remember to support the questioner as well.** We want people to feel that they can get answers (it's why we exist). While not every question deserves an answer, remember to be kind to the person who asked it. Explaining constructively what would help get an answer, or what rules were broken, can help the questioner learn.

   We're no longer being vague. We're talking to a specific group (one SO/SE needs) and offering concrete things to be done. **Avoid using welcoming if at all possible**. Nobody knows exactly what that means.
2. > **If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you.** Our community is made possible by volunteers. Follow our guidelines and don't worry if others suggest changes or edit your question - they’re trying to make your question helpful to as many people as possible.

   In keeping with the rewrite of #1, let's offer some concrete suggestions

   > **If you're here to ask questions, please listen to the criticism of others.** We want your question to help not just you, but anyone else with that question as well. To that end, other users may edit your question, leave comments and possibly even close your question. Pay attention to what these actions are trying to tell you. Other people are volunteering their time to help you, and in turn by helping the site be helpful to others. Respect them by trying to work with them. Most of the time, taking criticism can help you get the answers you need.

   This is much more "big picture" in its advice. Suddenly curators aren't bad guys who want you to feel stupid, they're people who want to help, but perhaps not in the way you were expecting. **Closing questions is being helpful, but may not seem welcoming to a new user.**
3. > **Be friendly, clear, and constructive.** Editing, commenting, and sharing feedback are healthy parts of our community. When giving feedback, avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online. Be open to receiving constructive feedback.

   Mostly this is talking about tone. I think this misses the crux of the issue though. People are reading too much into some statements. For example here's one someone else listed

   [image: A terse comment]

   It was read as openly hostile, when I simply read it as a terse statement. It didn't attack anyone, it just stated facts. In other words it wasn't "welcoming enough". I think we need people to not necessarily be friendly, but to assume the best of intentions, absent any open attacks

   > **Be clear and constructive, while assuming the best about others.** We want everyone to feel welcome here, but we also want people to get their questions answered. Assuming the best about others helps you the most, because it keeps *you* able to take constructive criticism instead of feeling insulted when no offense was meant. Remember, the intent of words is hard to discern online.
4. > **If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it.** Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. Even if this wasn’t your intent, apologize and move on.

   So... what exactly happens to violators here? Are we going to hand out bans for people who made others felt "unwelcome", but weren't overtly rude or even belligerent? There's not a "be reasonable" exception here. A help vampire could wear someone's patience down and then turn it into a flaggable offense. Again, this could benefit from a more concrete standard

   > **Respect requests to stop behavior that is making others feel uncomfortable.** Remember that no question, answer or comment is worth getting worked up over. If someone is making you upset, ask them to stop. Do your best to resolve it civilly with the other person or take a break from the situation. If they still won't stop, we may consider that harassment (see Unacceptable Behavior).

   This still largely preserves the original intent (no harassment) while adding an important directive to try and resolve it with the other person. Otherwise, people may feel free to run straight to mod flags for otherwise simple disagreements

Comment: I want to upvote this once for each point it makes. Especially calling out *`closing questions is being helpful, but may not seem welcoming to a new user`* and *`It was read as openly hostile, when I simply read it as a terse statement. It didn't attack anyone, it just stated facts.`*

Comment: @Machavity: "*It was read as openly hostile, when I simply read it as a terse statement. It didn't attack anyone, it just stated facts.*" The first sentence only made sense if we assume the OP isn't smart enough to know that, when an error message says a line number, that's where the error was detected. Reminding someone of something they obviously know is prima facie insulting. And the second sentence similarly didn't need to remind the OP they only posted 7 lines of code. The only useful information is "you didn't tell us what line 49 was."

Comment: @Nicol Expecting others to solve the problem, but withholding the information necessary to solve the problem - that's what is insulting. The "terseness" of comment serves as an example, it shows necessary level of precision that's expected when someone is stating the facts here.

Comment: @artem: I posted the much more terse comment without the insulting language: "You didn't tell us what line 49 was." That's the information that needs to be communicated. Terseness has nothing to do with being insulting. And how do you know that the OP is "withholding" anything? Were they unwilling to provide that information if it was requested in a non-condescending way? It seems to me that the OP may well have forgotten to mention it and needed a nudge. That's hardly an excuse for the insult.

Comment: @artem: "*that's what is insulting*" And that makes insulting them back OK? However disrespectful you may find it for someone to not provide all of the information needed to approach a problem, ***that's no excuse*** for being a jerk.

Comment: I don't consider that comment insulting. How do I know the OP is "withholding"? Because they did not provide it in the question. Forgetting to mention something is not an excuse for wasting other people time.

Comment: @artem: The word "withholding" implies intent. You cannot accidentally "withhold" something. You can forget to provide it, but that's different from "withholding" it. One is an accident; the other is deliberate. It's imprecision like that which makes the difference between what is and is not respectful, nice, or welcoming. "You forgot to provide X" is a very different statement from "you withheld X".

Comment: As to whether you feel that being told something you already know is insulting, I'll take you at your word that you feel that way. But it doesn't make you *right*. Generally speaking, most people will respond to being told something they *obviously* already know with eye-rolling, indignation, or sarcasm: "Thanks, Captain Obvious! Got anymore useless facts to share?" Good, effective communication is all about triggering the right response. If the first sentence of your post triggers a negative response, it no longer matters how useful the rest is.

Comment: @Nicol I agree that your comment is better. But I think the other comment is also OK, borderline but OK. I don't remember the exact details of that question and whether the necessary information was eventually provided or not, but if not - not providing information when asked shows the intent clearly.

Comment: @artem borderline? huh? It's obviously completely fine. The questioner just was not able to face the fiasco and thought it's a good idea to accuse other people of being unwelcoming, out of spite.

Comment: @NicolBolas *"The first sentence only made sense if we assume the OP isn't smart enough to know that, when an error message says a line number, that's where the error was detected"* - which may genuinely be the case. Don't underestimate the tendency of beginner programmers to *not even try* to read and understand the words that make up an error message, but instead to just write it off as technobabble that they have no hope of successfully interpreting. I don't think the first sentence is redundant; I think it's advice that some askers genuinely need.

Comment: I like basically every detail of this answer. I *particularly* like the fact that the guidance to askers doesn't presume that all criticism they'll receive is valid and that they should blindly follow instructions they're given, but instead asks them to "pay attention" to it and explicitly notes that guidance will only be useful "most of the time".

Comment: And finally, I agree completely with the point about the "uncomfortable" rule being ludicrously broad. Not only is there no "be reasonable" exception, but there isn't even an exception for *disengaging* from the interaction, which seems notable since ignoring someone is itself a behaviour that may make them uncomfortable. As written, the rule is basically a "Simon Says" clause; it amounts to "you are required to unquestioningly obey instructions from anybody who uses this magical sequence of words".

Comment: The comment in the screenshot could be improved: "The error says at line 49 and you posted line 1 to 7. Please add the relevant code around line 49 to the question". Just a nice question without implying that the poster is doing something wrong (even when he actually is) and something which can easily be acted on (just posting the relevant code). In the end it does not matter if he did it wrong, it matters that the mistake is corrected so the question can be answered. One big hint is the word "clearly", which makes your comment looking condescending, even when it is not intended that way.

Comment: @allo I've never claimed it was perfect. And your criticism is valid. But the problem is that it was held up as an example of "SO culture is rude/broken", when all I see is a frustrated user who has read the n-th "Why this no work?" question for today and no longer cares about being *nice* while still trying to not cross the *rude* line. Most of the time this subject comes up, it's only ever mentioned that the curators must change, without any acknowledgement of the fact that, without curators to tamp down the bad questions, SO would be overrun with bad questions and spam.

Comment: I would not have been offended. I just saw that you could try to avoid negativity a bit more, while making it possibly even more terse. But I object to your ``a frustrated user who has read the n-th "Why this no work?"`` line. For me as someone reading your comment it does not matter if this is the first or 100th annyoing post you read today, I do not even know it. But I expect that you are as nice as you were when commenting the first or possibly just do not comment (at this time) because you are already annoyed. Nobody else should suffer more because their question is read after others.

Comment: @allo Again, not disputing it could have been done better, but I don't want this to be a one-sided conversation either.

Comment: Agree with all of this, but specially point2. _We want your question to help not just you, but anyone else with that question as well._ Most new users totally miss this basic concept of SO and can get quite nasty when you try to improve or suggest they improve their questions.

Comment: @allo I very much disagree with the idea that *"The error says at line 49 and you posted line 1 to 7. Please add the relevant code around line 49 to the question"* would be a better formulation of the comment, for two reasons. Firstly, it doesn't convey that anything was done wrong by the asker, which *does* matter, because without them realising that they'll likely repeat the same mistake in future without realising that it's a problem. Secondly, it doesn't clearly convey the motivation behind the request or lead the asker to seeing their question through the eyes of a potential ... [1/2]

Comment: ... [2/2] answerer. Without inspiring that kind of empathy, the comment is far less useful *even at the narrow goal of just making this question answerable*; with your formulation, our confused asker is likely to simply obey and paste a few lines of code that include line 49, without stating which line in the block *is* line 49, leaving the question still unanswerable. In general we should be aiming to help new askers understand how to ask good questions and encourage them to thoughtfully attempt to do so - not aiming to obtain their mindless obedience of ad-hoc instructions from answerers.

Comment: I think it's a miss to change "make it as easy as possible for others to help you" to "listen to the criticism of others".  Making it easy for others is much broader, and in particular, it extends to *writing* questions, before there's any opportunity to receive criticism.  I do, however, think the suggested changes to the paragraph body are mostly an improvement.

Comment: I would say that the sample comment is not offensive nor in any way rude. It's clearly telling the person to post their comment. If a mod came over and posted that comment while closing a post, I'd say the comment made complete sense. They are essentially telling the user they did wrong *and they did do wrong*. Sugarcoating that a user screwed up in some fashion shouldn't occur here. A mistake in the actual understanding of their problem is one thing, but a user failing to provide a proper query should allow for minor polite scolding by people who are in a place of authority.

Comment: @MarkAmery I think it is much better. You are not here to educate the people how to ask, this should only be a side effect. And a user which was asked three times to PLEASE add the corresponding code will get the hint for his fourth question. If you try too much to tell him "you're doing it wrong" he will just be discouraged to participate. Leading by good example is so much better than constant complaining and trying to form users. People will pick up the good habits when they live with them while using the site, even when they are not explicitly educated to do so.

Comment: I like your points, but would suggest *please listen to the criticism of others* be changed to *please listen to the input of others*. Many comments about improving questions are not criticism.

Comment: One good part here is the last clarification: the suggested says if *someone* says you're making *others* uncomfortable while yours is suggesting if *I* feel uncomfortable *I* should say something. This is a great point. It shouldn't be *someone* saying for *others*, it should be *me* speaking up for *myself*. And we all can do that. And then it can't be abused with "I claim there are people uncomfortable but won't tell who and just want to police discussion so stop it now."

Answer (score 110):

It has taken me a few months for me to figure out why the recent, overt, pushes to "Be Nice" feel off. I think this code of conduct has helped me figure out what was bothering me though.

> If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. Learning how to participate in our community can be daunting, especially if someone is new. Be supportive while others are learning.

That first sentence is great. The problem is the second and third.

> especially if someone is new
>
> while others are learning

Other than a user with 1 rep and a creation date in the recent past, how do I know if someone is new? Even if someone has hundreds or thousands of rep, how do I know they are learning a technology?

I feel these pushes have subtly created an "Old Guard" vs. "Noobs" mentality, especially on Stack Overflow. We're being told to treat less established users and "learners" with friendlier, fuzzier, welcoming hugs. Yet, at the same time, I end up deleting comments by those very users that attack the more established members for attempting to help them. Responses back are one of three things

1. Publicly ignoring it and flagging it for moderator attention (Good!)
2. Responding back in a professional manner (Also good!)
3. Responding in a way that matches the tone they received (Bad).

The code of conduct should do a couple additional things:

1. Help set expectations. Answers may be provided in minutes, but they may take days or weeks. Users can't expect an answer to occur immediately.
2. Remove the subtle requests for different treatment between a new learner and an established user. Even if we aren't calling this "Be Nice" any more, we should be treating all users the same.

---

Unrelated to the code of conduct but still important: These pushes for improved behavior are great. However, I feel that a large amount of work that is going into this is being done at the expense of the "Old Guard", I mentioned above. This is the group that is invested in the moderation tasks of the site. They are the ones that keep the site tidy, presentable and running smoothly. There are a lot of requests for improved tools and features for this group of users. When are those going to happen?

Comment: *`how do I know if someone is new?`* I remember once having to comment on a 8k+ rep user that their answer was of poor quality (it was 3 lines, barely more than "here's teh codez"). They replied that they didn't know what I meant.

Comment: Hi, "Old Guard" member here.  I'm reading a list of changes to my rations and am discovering that I've been reassigned to Antarctica.  I get *why* they want to reassign me to Antarctica, since we have newbies coming over and discovering that it's cold and dark half of the year, and believing that the advice of others is unwelcoming on how to survive or what they need to do.  I'm not sure how comfortable I am with having to hand-hold these travelers, since they're **coming to Antarctica** of their own free will, so I thought it fair to assume they had *some* knowledge.  Send help.

Comment: It's less like going to Antarctica and more like going to a party at the house of someone you don't know very well. You do your best based on how you were meant to behave at other parties (if you've been to any before). If the host tells you off coldly for sitting on the sofa, maybe you won't come back to the next party and they won't get to see the amazing party trick where you open a bottle with your eyelashes.

Comment: @LangeHaare newbie here. Bravo for distilling my answer to 3 sentences

Comment: @LangeHaare:  I do feel like the analogy is apt.  Unlike visiting an associate's house party and not having a good experience of it, suffering in Antarctica, much like being spurned at Stack Overflow, has lasting consequences that will impact one's formative career (or so we're told from Twitter/Hackernews/`%SOCIAL_MEDIA_LINK%`).  Being told off at one person's party has consequences for that person and/or their circle of friends, which can be relatively easily addressed with another circle of friends if necessary.

Comment: @makato to me that suggests 1) SO needs better, more diverse competition so we should nurture and encourage alternatives like http://askquestions.tech , 2) SO is like Antarctica only if we users make it so, isn't the goal of the code of conduct to warm it up a bit?

Comment: @LangeHaare:  So... 1)  No competitor ever nurtures another competitor.  2)  My opinion is that warming up the Antarctic is harder than making sure that everyone who visits the Antarctic has really good winter weather, instead.  That is to say, I feel like the CoC is trying to warm up the Antarctic instead of giving everyone a reasonable checklist of what they should have before they come over.

Comment: `"That first sentence is great."` I respectfully disagree. The first clause of the sentence gives a massive out: if I'm *not* here to help others, apparently I *don't* need to be patient and welcoming.

Answer (score 107):

Honestly?  After skimming the new Code of Conduct, I kind of feel like...

[image]

Look, I get the need to be nice, I get all of this, and I largely agree with it *all* since I can't really get on board with the subtle barbs that we at Stack Overflow tend to throw at others.

But there are at least *three* problems that this doesn't cover.

1. While there are clear designators of "harmful", the *unclear* designators lack a lot of definition and prescription, and would result in a large amount of false positives generated for moderation.
2. The burden of moderating comments is still heavily on moderators, and on any normal site this could fly, but on Stack Overflow I'm less convinced.
3. This doesn't actually fix the problem of scope on any site which suffers from this issue.  A site which is large who has users who blithely ignore the scope of the site that they're posting on itself are more than bound to ruffle feathers, and while this gives *those* users a way to redress wrongs against them, it offers *no* solace for users who are only trying to help with curation.

The *n-1* th, lesser concern is that somehow I fear I'm losing some of my voice and personality on the site...but I'm not sure how high I should rank that concern right now.  I'll peruse it in all honesty afterwards and add this as an extra point.

---

The first issue is how comments are perceived.  That is to say, someone saying, "This is a duplicate link, and this specific answer addresses your question" could be perceived by OPs as them being called unpleasant names and having their ability to perform searches called into question.  Hey, it's happened to me more times than I care to remember.

Heck, some people get offended and angry at you for asking a *clarifying* question.

The Code of Conduct makes it seem such that anyone who feels that they've been wronged by someone in comments is fair game to get punished by the system.  And that's fine...**if** they actually were wronged.

I suppose this is to say, what this is lacking are guidelines on what would be acceptable discourse with polite yet forceful comments.  That is to say, it doesn't explicitly prohibit or permit comments which suggest to the OP that their answer is somewhere else, or any examples on those <s>annoying</s> [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340103/welcome-to-stack-overflow-heres-a-passive-aggressive-comment)-style comments.

The second issue is a matter of scale.  Moderators handle this all the time, but I'm not sure that this is going to scale.  This new Code of Conduct allows for a lot more stuff to be flagged - which is overall *good* - but I don't know how well suited Community Moderators are going to be with handling all of this at once.  Maybe time will tell.

The third issue... [hopefully I've captured a decent amount](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370486/1079354) in there, but that conversation will be evolving, no doubt.

Comment: Agree that CoC implies increased role of moderators, both in importance and in volume. It is unclear how StackOverflow is going to address it. I would love to see clear communication re: what is going to change in the way moderators are nominated, educated and monitored.

Comment: How is scope creep or any scope issue a Code of Conduct thing?

Comment: @Helmar:  The new policy mutates  (at least for Stack Overflow) what is an already mutated form of the stated mission of Stack Overflow.  Mutating it further doesn't help matters.

Comment: This CoC is going to end up as a stick to beat up people with. We already notice a fair amount of unnecessary flagging, especially in chat. With the threshold for "offensive" now officially reduced to "at least one person found it offensive", expect more drama in the days to come.

Comment: I'm offended by the new CoC. Where do I flag?

Comment: So much this. I can hardly wait until questions get downvoted and closed in complete silence for fear of violating the CoC. How welcoming it will be!

Comment: @AndrasDeak:  That's how I've begun to operate, anyway.  I've had less friction come from it, but I bet it isn't pacifying the OPs out there...

Comment: @Makoto I sincerely doubt there's anything we can do to make everyone happy, short of handing them all their answers on a silver platter, without any thought, effort, or movement required on their part.  So if it makes your life a little easier to just downvote and close, then you can save your critical thinking for a question that really deserves it.

Answer (score 95):

I guess I'm going to have to say what I said last time:

## People will get offended by anything.

Because...

## People, fundamentally, do not care what you think.

There are a lot of good posts here about how the CoC draft puts too much pressure on *us* (the existing community) to try and conform to an ideal that cannot be objectively achieved and not enough onus on the new asker to make sure that *they* adhere to the guidelines on acceptable content. Making the site 100% welcoming to 100% of people is impossible and you've started to make The Good the enemy of The Perfect. Do we need to be better? Can we be better? Probably.

But.

There *has* to be the possibility of people being able to make comments along the lines of "what have you tried?" because questions that show no effort *are worthy of downvoting and closure* and the attempt to inform the asker that this is the reason that their post is being downvoted and closed *should be an acceptable comment.*

With a population of millions, *literally any comment* can be seen as "unwelcoming" by *somebody.*  Remember...

> You can fool all the people some of the time and some of the people all the time, but you cannot fool all the people all the time.

...just replace "fool" with "please." At some point, we're going to have to shrug and say, "we tried" and just let some folks think we're a bunch of arrogant a$$holes. We aren't, on average, but we simply cannot please everyone all the time and attempting to do so is only going to turn other people away as the site becomes more and more stuck up and elitist...only over politeness instead of helpfulness.

[image: What a gent]

Comment: How are we going to become more stuck up and elitist if we're actually trying to be welcoming and patient with people? Stack Overflow was looking to many like it was stuck up and elitist *well beforehand,* that's part of the problem the community's addressing here. At some point we tried, yeah -- but we should keep trying, not because of appearance's sake, but to keep on ensuring new users can be welcomed and use our sites productively.

Comment: "*There has to be the possibility of people being able to make comments along the lines of "what have you tried?" because questions that show no effort are worthy of downvoting and closure and the attempt to inform the asker that this is the reason that their post is being downvoted and closed should be an acceptable comment.*" Why? If it's a low-effort post, why is downvoting (closing where appropriate) alone not enough? I certainly see no reason to go further than that if the only advice I could give is "expend more effort".

Comment: @doppelgreener It happens when people become overly sensitive over the words being used, everyone is forced to bend over backwards to please these people. Instead of doing so, they leave the site, and the people who are left are the self-important twats that everyone else views as "the elitists of sensibilities and language": if you don't use the right words, they get upset and call a moderator on you for being mean. Maybe not actually called that, but that is what they would be in effect.

Comment: @NicolBolas See literally every comment ever about "why is my question being down voted?" New users *already* see being down voted as part of why the site is unwelcoming, being unable to inform them about down votes will not help correct that view.

Comment: @Draco18s: "*New users already see being down voted as part of why the site is unwelcoming*" So what? We can control what language we use, so as to not be hurtful to others. If you want to tell others what they're doing wrong, you still have to do it in a reasonable way. However, we cannot control how other people interpret the meaning of our actions. Downvoting, voting to close? Those are actions, not words. And they have very particular meaning. Others may not like them, but they still need to happen; they are an integral part of this site's utility.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the logic here: *People do not care what you think* ⇒ *People will get offended*. How can people get offended if they don't care what you think?

Comment: While I am not usually mr. nice in person, I have had my share of users offended for telling them the question had no technical  merits, was wrongly tagged, explaining why I did downvote them, for using british dark humor, and for using known colloquial expressions as the hw is so bad, "feed it to the dog". People will be people.

Comment: @Kobi Because people aren't reacting to what you're *saying*, they're reacting to the fact that *your lips are moving.* They want to be upset, so they're going to be upset, your words and actions be damned. (Or I suppose, online, it wouldn't be lips, but fingers, but I think you get the point).

Comment: @NicolBolas People want to know the *reason* behind the action. I want to be able to tell them. Currently the proposed CoC makes it impossible to do so, because anything I could say could be interpreted by somebody somewhere as being "not nice."

Comment: @Draco18s: Why do you have so much difficulty with the difference between what something is "interpreted as" rather than "what you actually said?" You can write something that is highly unlikely to be "interpreted as" not nice. You cannot stop someone from choosing to see it as not nice. So if you do need to communicate with such a user, do your best to make what you write exceedingly difficult to be "interpreted as" not nice. The line you're referring to is not as thin as you make it out to be.

Comment: @NicolBolas *`You cannot stop someone from choosing to see it as not nice.`* **That's precisely my point.**

Comment: @Draco18s: No it isn't. Your point is "you ***can't*** stop someone, so why not be rude anyway". My point is "you can't ***stop*** someone, but you can at least make a good faith effort". My point is that if you make a good faith effort, then the fault is on them, and everyone can reasonably see that.

Comment: @NicolBolas How do you define a "good faith effort?" The CoC draft doesn't say. **That is the problem.**

Comment: @Draco18s: Providing a strict definition of "welcoming", "not nice", and the like would only lead to rules lawyering. I don't know why such words engender such fear in you. Can you not reasonably judge for yourself what seems reasonable and what isn't? Can you not tell why "You could Google that in 5 minutes" is unwelcoming and hostile? And if not... well, I don't know what should be done.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hence my comment about unreachable ideals. *I don't know what the solution is either.* But a situation were any and all comments can be flagged as "rude" (by a different someone each time) is definitely not it.

Comment: @Draco18s: Any and all comments can be flagged as rude *right now*. The question is whether such flags are *correct*. And thus far, I see no reason why a perfectly fine comment would be more likely to be accepted as rude under the new CoC than under the old Be Nice guidance.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I can, and can give you a specific instance. I recently had multiple *rude or offensive* flags on a comment I posted that got it deleted. The content in question was a specific quote from the SO help pages: "*Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.* Can you [edit] your post to add those things?"

Comment: @KenWhite: Then bring it up on the appropriate meta site, asking why it was removed. If that was the total content of your comment, then it should not have been deleted.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I know why it was deleted. It was deleted because it received sufficient flags as rude or offensive that it was auto-deleted, because the new policies have no intellect or judgement behind the enforcement; they just assume guilt rather than requiring any proof. It's the new lynch mob mentality among all of the newer, low-rep users who think that any request for improvement, clarification, or suggestion that it's off-topic is wrong that started with the *Be Nice* post that accused everyone who moderates the site of being bigots.

Comment: @KenWhite: "*the new policies have no intellect or judgement behind the enforcement*" There are no new policies as of yet. And if comments are being inappropriately deleted, then calling attention to that is *really important*. If no moderator was involved in the comment's deletion, then you need to stand up and say something about it. Because holes in the system don't get fixed until someone stands up and says that they exist, producing genuine evidence of the problems. Or I suppose you can just blame "the new lynch mob". It won't actually help, but I suppose it makes you feel better.

Comment: "what have you tried?" is too blunt. Be gentle. Be welcoming. Show you care about them as a person _in writing_. Take that extra step. "Interesting question, wondering if you have tried anything in particular to figure this out, that might help us." Then give it a while before you down vote. Maybe there is a "downvote queue" button that could be there where you can come back to the post after a few days and see if you should still down vote it. A down vote right after you ask a question sucks, especially with minimal / no explanation.

Comment: @NicolBolas: If I had a link, I'd ask a mod to take a look. I don't. What I got was a comment from a ~300 rep user linking me to the *Be Nice* blog post, which had two upvotes. Before I could respond, my comment was deleted. Within seconds, so was the user's comment. Net result: A low-rep, inexperienced user used a non-applicable reference to that blog post and got a comment from a very experienced user that simply cited the help center content deleted via the gang mentality created by that blog post. If you can't see then connection, then you've already swallowed too much of the Kool-Aid.

Comment: (continued) So the end result: I've drastically reduced the comments I leave trying to help or teach new users, and I almost always run out of close votes and question/answer votes daily because I use them instead of commenting. It's safer for me - I don't risk suspension for being helpful. Say what you want - that blog post (and the posts that have followed) have changed policies here, whether they're official or not. A moderator told me in a private comment "If it's any consolation, I've had to stop leaving many comments I've used before also."

Comment: @LancePollard: No, none of that. "What have you tried" is pointless to ask because it's irrelevant noise. If the question is unclear, ask for clarification; if there is no example of what's wrong, as for one. But things like "Interesting question" or waiting to downvote? No. Downvotes are not for the person; they're for the *content*. If the content is worthy of a downvote as it currently stands, then do so. Seeing a question that deserves a downvote sucks too.

Comment: @KenWhite: If this truly is so common, why aren't you bringing this up more? If there is some lynch mob running around getting comments deleted, *talk about it*. Keep making perfectly reasonable comments; if one gets deleted like this again, you'll have a link and can present evidence. Good comments being disappeared is not what should be happening, but what you're doing isn't going to solve that problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Because it's SE itself (the company) that empowered those users and continues to do so, up to and including the content of this post itself. It's discouraging any sort of moderation or enforcement of guidelines while encouraging the lynch mob, #metoo mentality that makes any claim of disrespect or bias automatically true whether there is any fact behind it or not. The site has gone the way of *guilty because someone said so whether there is evidence or not*, and continues to move in that direction. SE will continue that way until their complaining stops, no matter what we say.

Comment: (continued) The attitude recently is *It's irrelevant what the users who have spent years building this site for us think, because a few whiners on Twitter are more important to us.* When quoting from the help center draws flags that are upheld, and comments asking for a MCVE draw flags or moderator warnings, it's clear what the direction of SE staff is going forward, and it's also clear that what the experienced, long-term users of the site say are irrelevant to them.

Comment: @KenWhite: The problem I have with what you're doing is that you act like there's nobody on your side If you can *prove* that these failings exist, you can at least convince more users that these problems actually *exist*. What you're talking about is literally the first I've heard of this sort of thing. Consider how many others exist who have no idea about what comments are being removed. You can either give up and let them win, or you can actually fight. But to fight, you have to actually *prove your case*, not merely shout "lynch mob, #metoo mentality" and expect to be heard.

Comment: @KenWhite: Have you considered that maybe some SE employees aren't even aware of these issues? I personally doubt Shog in particular would approve of reasonable comments being deleted without moderator intervention. But of course, we'll never know, because nobody will actually stand up and prove that these things are happening.

Comment: @NicolBolas It gets hard to find examples when comment deletion isn't notified. The only reason Ken even *knows* is because he got an @-mention that he was able to click on just before the comments were removed. If he had been asleep or at the store *he never would have gotten the reply in his inbox.*

Comment: @Draco18s: Yes, that is annoying. Which is why it's important to try to *create* these circumstances by *not* refraining from commenting. If there are large groups of people out there abusing the rude/abusive flag, we need to know about it. And the only way we will know is to post unquestionably acceptable comments, see if they get deleted within a day, then notify the authorities (via a meta post).

Comment: "At some point, we're going to have to shrug and say, "we tried" and just let some folks think we're a bunch of arrogant a$$holes" - statement of the year right here. Safe is relative, Nice is relative, Welcoming is relative. A garage is safe, but not nearly as safe as putting it in space where noone can get to it (*caugh* Uncle Elon *caugh*). Everyone just needs to chill out quit getting so offended over every little thing, cause frankly, if this place gets as tedious as twitter, i'm just going to stop helping people.

Comment: Wikipedia's "civility" policy has a similar effect: Everyone is superficially "polite" to avoid violating the rule, while actually acting like complete jerks, which just ends up making every interaction much more infuriating and stressful than if were allowed to just express our frustration openly.   Our species evolved these forms of communication for a reason. Somewhere between "usenet flamewar ragefest" and "gritted-teeth sneering politeness" is a good middle ground of respectfully expressing frustration with someone else's actions.

Answer (score 84):

As a moderator of two sites, I don't think I can moderate against the "no subtle put-downs" rule. Almost any disagreement or any attempt to deal with poor-quality content can be re-construed as breaking this rule. In fact, a lot of the actions I have to take to moderate could easily be construed as "subtle put-downs". For example, often people post incomprehensible gibberish posts. I have to close such questions or delete such answers, and I usually include the phrasing "You might like to ask a friend who speaks English to help you." It's not wonderful, but it's the best I can do for a visitor who is probably not going to come back anyway. But now I feel like it's only a matter of time before someone with an axe to grind decides to recast this as a subtle put-down, or as discrimination against people who don't speak English.

Another example is that recently I suggested-edit--banned a member of my community who has a long history of suggesting "spelling and grammar fix" edits that introduce spelling and grammar errors into the posts they're supposed to fix. Roughly half of his edits are wrong in this way, and it has taken a lot of time from people to filter them out. Of course I've also messaged him to describe the problem, and described the situation in a sensitive way, and he understood and accepted the situation, and continues to contribute in other ways. I'm not sure the situation would be as easily resolved with a user who has read the new CoC and feels entitled to continue their edits regardless of the harm they cause to the site and the time they take from other users, because they've been given the expectation that we will lower our quality standards to avoid discriminating based on English fluency.

---

The "No discrimination of any kind" is way too broad to be enforceable. There are many kinds of discrimination, and not all of them are as obvious as harassment or negative remarks. What if we have a user who is a prolific answerer, but never answers questions from someone with an Indian-sounding username? What if they never answer questions from one particular individual, who is known in the community to be homosexual? Am I supposed to do something about that, as a moderator? This isn't a job. We can't interrogate people about their intentions like an employment tribunal would, and we can't force people to answer questions from different users equally or fairly. We could ban them completely, but I don't think I would be up for banning a user who is causing no harm to the site just because of how they decide which questions to answer, especially if it's also on me to judge whether their behaviour is discriminatory or not.

---

You say in the post that:

> We need less over-posturing for troll dispatching and more guides to help decent folks avoid more common pitfalls.

but I'm seeing a gap between what you say and what the draft CoC actually says. If you really want to **help** people be welcoming and inclusive, set examples of good behaviour, and show off exemplary behaviour in difficult cases. Give people a repertoire of strategies for dealing with low-quality content and visitors who don't want to engage with the site, while living up to your idea of what "welcoming" is. You can't achieve that by just giving people a list of what they can't say: you'll find that a lot of people choose not to say anything at all, and that it's disproportionately the people who were being nice to begin with. A sure way to make the site look less welcoming is to scare the nice people into silence while the bullies keep doing what they were doing.

Comment: "What if we have a user who is a prolific answerer, but never answers questions from someone with an Indian-sounding username? What if they never answer questions from one particular individual, who is known in the community to be homosexual? " Nobody is (or should be) forced to answer questions so mentioning this *issue* when somebody doesn't answer is both pointless and irrelevant to the CoC. You can't accuse someone of discrimination by not doing something they are not required to do.

Comment: @DavidPostill I find that to be a valid question though. What if it becomes really obvious? Like in some smaller tags, some users answer almost every question in that tag. What if accusations of such behavior come forth? I agree in so far as that it sounds like a goldmine for people who just want to stir drama.

Comment: You raise some interesting points. I do wonder however what are the repercussions of managing saying some demographic is more welcome than other.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't quite follow. Anyone who says outright that certain groups are unwelcome is censured. That's what happens now and I don't think anyone is proposing to change that. That's a form of discrimination we can and do police. My point is that there are **some** forms of discrimination we can't really do anything about.

Comment: While we might not require fluent English for posting on the sites, the bar for suggesting or reviewing edits must be another thing entirely. Someone who isn't mostly fluent in English should simply stay away from edits.

Comment: @Lundin The point is that if they *don't* "simply stay away from edits", the new CoC might prevent mods from taking action.

Comment: The phrase "No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language. Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others." is a deep flaw in an otherwise pretty good CoC. It's an invitation for abuse. The rest of the CoC can work well (with reasonable people moderating.)  I don't think this bit can be made to work even by reasonable moderators.

Comment: +1 for *A sure way to make the site look less welcoming is to scare the nice people into silence while the bullies keep doing what they were doing*

Answer (score 82):

Fundamentally, I feel that a COC needs to be a *shield* not a *sword* or a *potential bludgeoning stick*. One of the… unintended consequences of the blog posts is folks using it that way. It needs to reflect the best we can be, rather than the worst we could be.

A *glaring* omission (having talked this through) is a requirement to try to deal with people with good intentions. Our current "Be Nice" FAQ contains the line

> Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.

Assuming good intentions *is important*. It blunts the chances of some of the drama, internal or external, and is a solid basis for solving our problems like adults.

One thing I'd suggest is, many of these things are *universal*. Decency and civility shouldn't vary whether it's main or chat — the language on making people uncomfortable, for example is just as useful on somewhere like IPS, comments or chat. We shouldn't really be splitting fundamental things into "chat" and Q&A. As far as conduct goes, there are no second and third class citizens.

Some of the language… might reflect "assume good intent" better. I know folks ask for examples (I do, but I like concrete complaints I can sink my teeth into, rather than vague ones, especially externally), but sometimes conciseness is better.

Let's consider

> This includes any language likely to offend or alienate people based on (but not limited to): race, gender, gender identity or expression, English fluency, sexual orientation, disability, mental illness, nationality, neurodiversity, physical appearance, body size, or religion.

We can probably condense it down to

> This includes any language aimed at offending or alienating others

Firstly, this is a *lot* shorter. It doesn't create a list of things (that honestly feel rules lawyerly). It focuses on *intent* — and along with

> If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it. Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. Even if this wasn’t your intent, apologize and move on.

lets people sort things out mostly like adults. The lack of examples actually helps folks use the rules as they need to.  The latter is kinda as true for Q&A as much as chat.

> No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language. Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle put-down.

<strike>Feels kinda vague too, and potentially interpreted a little too flexibly. I'm not too sure how to word the intent of it better though.</strike>

The problem I have with is it's... kinda absolute and imperative. It feels like a command, that needs to be suffixed with an "or else"

Consider how

> Regardless of intent, subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language can have a significant negative impact on others. For example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle put-down. Be welcoming and patient, especially with those who may not know everything you do.

Is a little longer. But it kinda feels more adult. It tells you why it's wrong, what's wrong and why. It respects the reader just a little more.

Comment: I like the shield vs sword distinction. The COC is a bit of a mix: some parts are where we aspire to be the best versions of ourselves and will sometimes fall short, while others are pretty firm hard lines about conduct that won't be tolerated. That's a good thing, because we can't all always be perfect, while we all need to never be bigoted toward each other. I'd hope that people don't use the COC to conflate the two.

Comment: IMHO "You could Google this in 5 seconds" is **not** subtle.

Comment: tbh... I'll cede that point.

Comment: "likely to offend" is different from "aimed at offending".

Comment: This is intentional

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware of this *"assume good intentions"* part. I'd rather tackle this from the opposite direction, based on [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) : *"Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity"*. This is **far** more universally applicable.

Comment: which assumes that well, people are stupid. Which kinda runs counter to "be nice"\

Answer (score 79):

> Even if you don't agree with all of it, do you feel that this is a
>   reasonable code of conduct? Does it affect your recommending Stack
>   Overflow as a resource in any way? How so?

This is going to be a rambling, I fear not entirely cogent response based on many factors, only one of which is this code of conduct.

Lately, I feel like the volunteers on the site have been asked to take on much ... additional effort. It feels like we're held to the highest personal standards of both etiquette and professionalism, with the added task of carefully considering the impact of our words on people who are easily dissuaded from using the site. This is kind of ... at odds with the general experience volunteers face. You're expected to:

- Be on your best behavior
- Excuse mistakes and non adherence to the rules and standards
- Be the better person in the face of insults and personal attacks
- Temper your criticism with the perspective of the other person in mind

A lot of effort has gone into actualizing this lately on Stack Exchange's side. I don't begrudge focusing on what the volunteers can do for this - after all, unless you're already an engaged user of the site, the Stack Exchange team has at best a very dubious influence over your behavior.

This comes into play with my friends. Here is where this answer gets personal and uncomfortable to share. My friends are mostly like me - direct in their wording, maybe not entirely easy to deal with, but motivated. They like being part of a bigger whole, and in the past I have recommended Stack Exchange heartily to them as a place where they can fully come into their own and make their mark on the world as helpful people.

For better or worse, Stack Exchange has gotten quite a bit of publicity for its public efforts in the past months, but this has arrived and appeared entirely differently in my circle of friends. To put it bluntly, I've lost contact with some extended acquaintances over this, I don't know if that's a good thing or not, but I do know that Stack Exchange suffers a pretty horrid reputation in my social circle right now.

The last five conversations (easily) I've had with my friends about this site was about how they think it has gone off the deep end in order to please people on Twitter with an axe to grind. The public presentation of this change isn't helping that.

I personally know (or at least choose to believe, I have a lot of respect in Stack Exchange staff and other users that are with them on this that is difficult to shake, so I assume best intentions for now) that this isn't the case and that we're not in the middle of a culturally Marxist*² takeover of the network.

Selling that to my friends and strangers however is ... exhausting. I've deliberately avoided the topic with them lately because I'm loath to justify my continued support for this site time upon time again.

I do think most of this is a perception problem and not an actual network problem. The code of conduct reads ... one sided, skewed towards those who would do anything at all with enough regularity to care about the site. It does not explicitly mention people taking criticism poorly, but it does mention people giving criticism in a less then ideal way, for instance.

All this has made me hesitant to bring up Stack Exchange to friends, lest I get sucked into another hour-long discussion about inclusivity and how they feel this site has kowtowed to special interests too much. I have plenty of communication issues of my own, and I'm not very good at appealing to emotions and easily exhausted by such talk, which is why I've avoided the topic for now.

So no, at the moment I wouldn't recommend Stack Exchange to my friends and colleagues. Not because of the code of conduct in particular, but because of the perception and PR problem the latest efforts have created.

From a user perspective, I maintain my trust in the staff and users I know on the network that seem to trust this will be a success and not to the detriment of long term users.

*² I'm loath to use this terminology. It is often not used in good faith and annoys me to hell and back to repeat. But I'm not sure how to paraphrase this without going into a 2000-word tangent about current political events.

Comment: "People on Twitter with an axe to grind" I should've used that line...

Comment: "*Excuse mistakes and non adherence to the rules and standards*" We are? I don't see any expectations of that. It's simply a matter of how you respond to such things.

Comment: @NicolBolas Outside of practice, i've seen many people argue publicly that we should cut new users extra slack and shaming people who don't do so. This is part of the perception problem I'm describing.

Comment: @Magisch: It depends entirely on how you define "cut new users extra slack". Some people feel that not being able to post, "you can Google that in 5 minutes" is cutting new users slack. I can't really agree with that interpretation.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't either. I'm thinking stuff like exempting them from downvotes or closevotes for first questions (which I've seen posted as policy statements by moderators before, even)

Comment: @Magisch: I don't recall community moderators posting about such things, but yes, there are people who want to give favorable treatment to first questions. There are people who also want to post unpleasant things on first questions. Until actual site policy changes to promote one of these sides, why not just ignore them?

Comment: @NicolBolas This answer is about how the recent efforts affect my recommendations of stack to friends and colleagues. A percieved issue is an issue whether or not it's actually enforced.

Comment: @Magisch: It's funny. When the SO staff posted a blog about "percieved[sic] issues" with regard to SO not being welcoming, lots of people said that perceptions don't matter, only facts, and if nobody could prove that there was a problem, then there wasn't. But now perception matters. It's probably not a coincidence that in one case, it's *their* perception and in the other case, it's the perception of someone else. So whose perception should we care about more: you/your friends, or the people saying that we're being unwelcoming?

Comment: @NicolBolas I care about the perception of my friends more because it comes up as an argument that is tedious and becoming harder to disprove when I talk to them. I don't talk to random people on twitter on any consistent basis.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not sure this answer is in any way making a black-and-white statement about whose concerns are more valid rather than adding a very reasonable concern on top of the existing concerns and strengthening the fact that, well, this isn't a particularly easy topic to tackle.

Comment: Bit of advice: tell your friends to ignore Twitter. Twitter is a trash fire. You don't want to ignore a trash fire if it's headed toward you, but... You don't look to a trash fire for advice on how to build a useful living space. We're looking at the mess on Twitter as a sign that we need to clear the proverbial brush from around our foundation, *not* as an example of how to build a healthy, nurturing community. If your friends can't see the difference, maybe they need to step back from the fire a bit.

Comment: You know, this is a pretty good summary of how I feel about things too. This used to be a "leave your politics at the door" kind of place, and certain verbiage lately has raised some concern that they're headed down the path the twitter administrators did a few years ago. There's no fire yet, but I'm seeing sparks of particular common phrases crop up more an more in the blogs that make me worry we may be a few years away from Verified User badges and censor bots. This is a place for helping people learn things they have questions about. Not another place for political grandstanding.

Comment: @Shog9 And yet here we are doing exactly what the dumpster fire wants instead of (not even in addition to) listening to your own community. Now maybe that's coincidence.  Pretty much everyone agrees that a better CoC isn't a bad thing by any means, but this draft still completely ignores years of community feedback *again* so it really doesn't feel like a coincidence anymore. You'd think in a code of *conduct* it'd mention following quality rules. But it doesn't, which is *exactly* what the dumpster fire wants.

Comment: You'll forgive people for "being unable to see the difference" when this continues to happen repeatedly.

Comment: Did you read it, @ɥʇǝS? Compare with the current "be nice" policy, which has no advice aimed at askers / new users at all, but asks that others give them special consideration. Half the guidelines in the proposed CoC are advising askers to follow the guidelines and be accepting of edits and feedback. That's kind of a big step up, IMHO.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS: "*it'd mention following quality rules*" What do you think "make it as easy as possible for others to help you" and "Follow the guidelines" mean? What more do you want, a detailed listing of them? "*And yet here we are doing exactly what the dumpster fire wants instead of (not even in addition to) listening to your own community.*" Because nobody in the community wanted an improved ask-question page. Oh right, they did, and it's being worked on. Please stop spreading this notion that *nothing else* is being done.

Comment: I did read it, yes.  Your comment feels rather disingenuous.  Tim points out in the Q we don’t want to be too ambiguous and so everything else is expanded and expounded on, but there’s literally one sentence about actually writing quality material and it just says “follow the guidelines”.  Again, as the Q says “*Codes of conduct help identify your community to the outside world*” and yet there is *one sentence* about the networks different and special quality requirements.  It doesn’t even mention in passing that this isn’t your traditional forum or wiki.

Comment: So, as I said, you’ll forgive people for thinking SE stopped caring about quality or their mission statement (heck the CoC has a radically different mission statement than SE has ever had. Hopefully that’s just a wording issue).  And no, half of it is not about following guidelines and accepting feedback. Other than that one aforementioned sentence it immediately dives into *giving* feedback, not taking. And then it is never mentioned again.

Comment: @NicolBolas People started abusing Jay’s blogpost *the day/day-after* it came out to tell off people leaving quality comments. Not rude comments. Normal, everyday comments. So yes, the CoC does need to be more explicit about actually following the quality guidelines or people are going to abuse it in the exact same way. A better ask page is great, but that’s not the code of *conduct* which is what everyone looks to for conduct rules.

Comment: Just about every other possible bad behavior is spelled out, so why the reluctance to be explicit about the quality guidelines? Again, you’ll forgive people for thinking you don’t *want* them to be explicit.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS: "*People started abusing Jay’s blogpost the day/day-after it came out to tell off people leaving quality comments. Not rude comments. Normal, everyday comments.*" And people were telling people off for leaving "quality comments" the day *before* Jay's blog post. And the day before that. And before that. People have been hurling abuse at "normal, everyday comments" since the site began. Such people do not need an excuse to rage against someone for pointing out their inadequacies.

Comment: @NicolBolas Which is a red herring. You can't *stop* the abuse, but you *can* take steps to not give them more tools to add to their abuse. Especially tools that make it seem like the site rules are on their side.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS: "*Other than that one aforementioned sentence it immediately dives into giving feedback, not taking.*" I don't see now "taking feedback" is relevant. If you hurl abuse at someone *for any reason*, that's against the rules. If you post a snarky condemnation *for any reason*, that's against the rules. You seem to have a persecution complex, that you're overly sensitive to criticism you see that can be aimed your way if there isn't criticism that is aimed specifically at "them" too.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS: The only "sides" are the Jerk and the non-Jerks. New, old, high-rep, low-rep, all that is irrelevant. What matters is *behavior*.

Comment: Just as you are hesitant to bring up Stack Exchange to friends, I'm hesitant to encourage anyone to come to a site where members of the community consider it to be too much additional effort to be on their best behavior and consider the perspective of the person they're talking to when offering criticism. If those aren't ideals we can agree to aim for, recognizing that we're all fallible, why have moderation at all? What's the point of having this community if it's not a place where we agree to make an effort to treat each other well?

Comment: @Shog9 not to be a trouble maker, but the "Did you read it?" comment sounded like a "subtle put-down" to me

Comment: Honest question, @Lamak. This answer that we're commenting under - and my first comment - are primarily focused on the meta aspects of the CoC, the context in which it is proposed, the "perception problem" as Magisch put it. The one paragraph that touches on the CoC itself characterizes it as "one sided, skewed". Seth appears to be riffing on that, suggesting that the proposal "ignores years of community feedback" and doesn't "mention quality rules" - this is literally true (it doesn't contain the *exact phrase* "quality rules") but inaccurate - 2/4 "expectations" are aimed directly at askers.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree with you about that, but my comment was meant to bring to the conversation that "being right" doesn't really matter when posting a comment, and that one should never use it to "subtly put-down" another user...no matter how wrong they were

Comment: Again, not a put-down @Lamak. I completely understand the concern over the optics of doing a CoC change in this context, but... If we're going to discuss the text of the proposed CoC itself... I really do want folks to read it.

Comment: @Shog9 I do understand you, really. I just want to highlight how the fact of having something like this: "Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. Even if this wasn’t your intent, apologize and move on." can affect a discussion. Specially if anything can be interpreted the wrong way by someone

Comment: Did this negatively affect you, @Lamak?

Comment: Not directly, but since this is the meta post about the CoC, there's still a use on bringing it up, specially because the comment **did** sounded condescending....just like your last one did

Comment: This only works if we're honest with each other, @Lamak. If we start trying to guess at whether folks are being sincere, guess at how others will react, deny our own feelings... Then it becomes a twisted mess where no one dare speak up lest they be misinterpreted. I asked an honest question, intended to establish a baseline for discussion; if that bothers you, Seth, or anyone else... Let me know, or flag it, or send us an email. I, or a moderator, or a teammate will take that seriously. That's been my policy for as long as I've been here; I've edited or deleted plenty of messages as a result.

Answer (score 78):

I like this; it's pretty clear, and it covers a lot more than I thought it would.

One thing that pops out at me is the section on Reporting and Enforcement:

> #### Reporting and Enforcement
>
> Every person contributes to creating a kind, respectful community. If you find unacceptable behavior directed at yourself or others, you can:
>
> - **[Flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) the harmful content.** Depending on the content, flagging will alert moderators or trigger an automatic deletion.
> - **Address it directly.** If you’re comfortable addressing the person who instigated it, let them know how this behavior affects you or others. You can also remind them of the Code of Conduct. If the behavior escalates, disengage immediately -- staff or moderators will take action.
> - **[Contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f).** We’ll respond as quickly as we can.

I feel like this presents all three options as equally beneficial choices in a given situation, but they often aren't. For instance, if a person makes a single rude comment, you wouldn't go straight to contacting Stack Overflow; you'd either flag or maybe address it directly. Similarly, if there's a large-scale problem - say, a couple of users harassing people on a larger scale - you probably don't want to *only* address it yourself; letting a mod know is a good first step.

So, can there maybe be a way of making it clear that not all of these actions are appropriate for every situation? I know it's hard to succinctly do that, so maybe linking to an FAQ page or two about flag use (in addition to the one already linked) could put the options in context.

Comment: Great feedback. I think adding some detail about which options to use when makes sense. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Numbering (instead of bullets) might be a subtle way to imply escalation.

Comment: @TomLimoncelli the down side with numbering is that it implies progression... but in reality, there's no progression here. Someone can *either* flag something *or* address it directly depending on personal preference. For example, if there's inappropriate (unnecessary) language in a post, it can be edited and flagging could wait until a time that person rolls back the edit to contain the content.

Comment: It may be useful to put this in steps. For example, you should first alert moderators (or CMs if the problem requires CM attention), then try and address it yourself (if you're comfortable doing that), and then if it hasn't been handled to your satisfaction, use the Contact Us form. Either steps like that, or examples of when to use "Contact Us" vs flags.

Comment: As a moderator I'd prefer someone to seek us out via a flag whenever something's making them uncomfortable and they don't know how to deal with it. For many users, my preference would be they never have to use the "address it directly" option. I would especially not want them to feel they must try that before flagging.

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm also rather wary of that one, also as a mod; in theory, resolving small-scale stuff quietly is nicer than having to bring in the big guns. But 1) it almost never works like that, 2) not flagging leaves no traces for mods to see (and on SO and the larger sites, they'll *never* see it), 3) there's so much potential for things to go wrong, and 4) I think that option almost implies that one *shouldn't* ask for mod help if needed. In other words . . . yes, I agree. I suppose you could probably make a solid argument for removing that one entirely.

Comment: @doppelgreener (and HDE) also as a mod, I feel the exact opposite. I think that ideally, the first step should be "Hey, that's making me uncomfortable, please stop". Of course, that assumes the user feels comfortable doing so and many don't. That's absolutely fine! If you don't feel OK addressing it yourself, then by all means, flag! But if you do, I think it's always best to try to point out that a certain behavior is unpleasant for you first and only escalate to mods either if you don't want to do that (fair enough) or it doesn't work. So I'd put the "Address it directly" part first.

Comment: 'seek us out via a flag whenever something's making them uncomfortable and they don't know how to deal with it' well, I won't be doing that.  No-effort requirement/homework dumps make me uncomfortable, but I don't want to run out of flags every day - the mods would soon get annoyed.

Comment: @MartinJames No-effort requirement/homework dumps aren't a CoC violation. This advice is appearing on the CoC document, and directs people what to do about CoC breakages, like harassment, bullying, sexism, and so on. Inside the scope of *that kind* of action, I'd rather people seek me or another moderator out via flags on the site I moderate. If someone's uncomfortable about an edit or a homework dump that's something else outside the scope of actions the advice is about, and I don't imagine the CoC is trying to speak about that stuff (nor am I).

Answer (score 72):

> **Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or language.** Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know, join us in building a learning community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

## That's not the mission of Stack Exchange.

The mission is correctly described on the Tour Page of every site:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about (site topic).

This is *not* a minor problem with the Code of Conduct.  It's a *key* problem.

> ## Ask questions, get answers, no distractions
>
> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

The Code of Conduct ***MUST*** reflect the actual mission of the site.

---

Obviously there is no point in having a Code of Conduct that just repeats the Tour Page.  But the MISSION STATEMENT should either be left out entirely, or it should match the *actual* mission of the site.

You could state the purpose *of the Code of Conduct,* which is different from "our mission."

It looks like the Code of Conduct authors wrote what THEIR mission is, *in **writing** the Code of Conduct.*  That's different from the mission of the *site.*

The purpose of the Code of Conduct should **align with** the purpose of the site.

---

A possible new wording:

> **Our mission is to work together to build a library of detailed answers to every question on a variety of specific topics.**  The purpose of this Code of Conduct is to help the site run as smoothly as possible and to help guide our diverse contributors to interact with each other in a professional, collaborative, kind and respectful manner.

I'm sure this could be improved and tweaked, but the current text's complete misalignment with the *actual mission* of the site should be viewed as a HARD failure (blocker, showstopper).

---

Even more bluntly, stripping away modifying clauses:

> Our mission is to build an **inclusive community**....

This is flatly wrong.  Our mission is to build a **library of detailed answers.**

Comment: This reminds me of all that corporate pep-talk mumbo jumbo. "We are here to deliver best-in-class solutions as an integrated, collaborative team displaying 21st century best practices in synergy." No, we are here to *make money*, the synergy stuff is just for show.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, for all that your comment was intended as agreement, I think there is a crucial distinction to be made between the *production* of a group or individual (i.e. what they *produce* or *put out* that others find valuable) and the reward they receive **in exchange** for that service, whether monetary or otherwise.  The only groups in the U.S. with the correctly stated mission statement "to make money" are counterfeiters and the U.S. Mint!  One must **produce** something (whether service or goods) to *exchange* for money (or for goodwill or anything else).

Comment: ...But yes, oftentimes a company mission statement *is* just unreal "PR" mumbo jumbo with no connection to reality.  :)  Still, in such a case there *is* a correct way to specify the goal, and it is never "to make money" for the reasons I describe above.

Comment: "This is flatly wrong. Our mission is to build a library of detailed answers" Not any more, the site owners have been telling us now for over four years that this is no longer the case. From now on, it's newbies answering duplicate questions all the way. 
Because "engagement" beats curating a high quality resource in cash terms.

Comment: This is a point of confusion others have had ... the mission statement here relates only to the mission/purpose of the CoC, **not** of the network. They are two different things. The goal of the CoC is to outline how we expect users to behave so that the network can be "an inclusive community...".

Comment: @Catija In that case it should say so it reads as if SO's mission iod to create a community

Comment: @Catija it says “Our mission.”  The Code of Conduct is not a group that can be referred to with the word “our.”  Your comment makes sense but that is not at all what the plain language of the CoC says.

Answer (score 65):

How do we deal with *lazy* users (I hope I'm safe saying this until the CoC goes live ;) persistently trying to offload work in chat?

Most language-specific chatrooms on chat.SO will every once in a while get a user who asks questions, doesn't really read answers, and does no thinking of their own when they receive help. Typical dynamics involve pages worth of "*Please, could you post the actual code you're trying to debug?*" and "*We just told you how do to that, why do you keep asking this?*" and "*Did you really read the 10-page tutorial which I linked you a minute ago and ascertained that it somehow doesn't do what it does?*". And yes, "*You could have literally searched google with what you asked here*" is also relevant.

Most people are patient and understanding with users asking for help. However, when there's a clear lack of effort on the asker's side, and no intent to *learn* what they're asking about, we need them to stop in an effort to protect our sanity and not waste our time.

I have seen several users whose behaviour is perfectly described by the ["help vampire"](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm) syndrome. A possible remedy to this situation is confronting the user with their behaviour, telling them in very clear terms that their behaviour is simply inappropriate, and optionally pointing them to the help vampire info-page in hopes of getting the message through.

Now, as I understand it, none of this feedback will be *appropriate* under the new CoC. Linking that page or even calling someone a help vampire would be unthinkable, right? So even if I let go of this, how do I communicate in a *welcoming, friendly* manner that they need to stop asking and they need to start thinking for themselves, and reading the help that they get? And if I manage to communicate this to them but they keep on continuing with this disruptive behaviour, how can I kick them from the room in a *welcoming, friendly* manner?

Don't let my cynical tone fool you, I'm genuinely concerned and curious about handling entitled users who show no effort in trying to solve their problems. On main we can just downvote, close and move on, but the dynamics of chat are very different, and this needs to be addressed.

Comment: Does kicking people out of a chat room for disruptive behavior require talking to them? I don't think so. As for how you tell someone they're a Help Vampire, there's no "welcoming" way to tell someone that. Once you've identified that the person is being unreasonable, the best thing to do is disengage and ignore the person. If they persist, then they're being disruptive and can be asked to leave.

Comment: @NicolBolas "*So I went to this chatroom, asked for help, everything went OK. But then suddenly they started to ignore me, and then I was kicked! That's so unfriendly.*". As I noted elsewhere, I believe that omitting feedback for the sake of not saying anything (to be on the safe side) makes for an even less friendly/welcoming end result. The company can't seriously think that we're all better off if we silently take moderation action. If that's not what you're suggesting then I missed your point.

Comment: If things got to the point of ignoring them, then everything did not go OK before that. It's fine to say that, because they are refusing to take your advice about reading and learning about the system, you're not going to engage with them. It's not fine to link them to sites that call them names.

Comment: This scenario is one that happens rather commonly.  At some point, it's less about being welcoming, and more about enforcing standards.  We can't compromise quality for the sake of being welcoming.  So if a user isn't learning, well, kick away.  Their inability to follow the rules is their problem, not the room's.

Comment: Kick-mute already solves this problem. Just make sure you keep some kind of history of it in tact if you decide to move the messages.

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer that partially addresses my concerns, and that I found it without reading three pages of answers. I'm certain that Chat serves many great purposes but the time I see it most often is in the comments - SE *politely* saying 'take it to chat' (instead of saying: 'Get a box of crackers'). Some people are offloading to Chat because their [spam-seed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256709/what-is-a-spam-seed) comment didn't gain a response (which is acceptable, because 'Be Nice' says: "Disengage"); but then they're upset by the off-putting and downvote.

Comment: Why are so worried about chat quality? Main concerns me more as it affects the quality of the archive contents, chat not so much.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I take it you're not an avid user of chat. That is fine. Surely you don't find it hard to accept that there are a lot of users who actively use chat to socialize both on chat.SO and on the many site-specific rooms of chat.SE. I also object to your assertion that somehow there's a trade-off between moderating main and moderating chat. Why can't we have a CoC that is applicable to both?

Answer (score 59):

The major issue in the successive policies of SO, is running the danger into enforcing double standards: the registered users who play by the rules are being held to a higher standard of conduct, and actually penalised against drive-by users.

If the system gets so twisted, old and new users may actually have no incentive both to create or maintain registered accounts, as it far easier to just use low-rep accounts, and trow away them at the minimal signal of problems. I would not like to go there honestly, it is not the reason I am here.

There also might be a latent problem of having a segment of users that does not see the effort of building reputation, following our FAQ, or often taking the time to write good questions as productive. One of the problems is that it is far too easy to use one time throwaway accounts. Again, I rarely heard anyone mentioning this.

For instance, I am in a car related free forum. My account had to be formally accepted in as other users of that group were, and anyone that deviates from a certain standard and quality of posts will see the  account cancelled. I do not advocate such extremism, however it could be an interesting experiment allowing a cool-off 24h period of an account before it could be used to comment or give answers, if not posting questions.

As for the discrimination of language, I as a foreign English learner, do find it strange an English forum not imposing certain standards for people to be able to participate coherently. I have helped improve many questions and answers. However, putting the onus on others of correcting questions (or answers) of people who often do not want to invest time in writing things correctly in English does not seem entirely correct. Please do call my attention and correct my English, I am here mainly for learning, and not for being worried about being discriminated against my mother tongue being something else.

Lastly, the bigger elephant in the room is considering all rep 1 questions new users. Trow away accounts are clearly being gamed by people who do not want to follow the code of conduct of this community,  for evading moderation, niceness enforcement and bad reputation building, and we are ignoring that against enforcing heavy standards to the established user base.

Comment: As somebody who speaks only English, I couldn’t write English without something like Word or autocorrect or a similar grammar add-on.  My point of course is that I don’t expect perfect English from anyone, but all three of those tools would correct things like (u vs you), (i vs I), and other similar mistakes I see daily.  I can handle misspelling words, I can’t decode, misspelled shorthand English (i.e text message quality English)

Comment: @Ramhound Nobody writes perfect English. But we know many posts here are not shortcomings, are just a rushed job that neither conveys the question neither is well written. As for *perfect* English, you can peruse how many edits I have in some of my top questions. Writing as anything else requires time and effort, which some are not willing to invest even in their own questions.

Answer (score 58):

As a moderator, I have concerns with the list of behaviors and typical actions. I'm afraid that this will lead to rule-lawyering. Even with the statement that actions are taken on a case-by-case basis, I think that people will focus on the behavior and typical actions.

It says that content that contains a subtle put-down is typically met with content deletion. That's generally true. However, repeated put-downs are dealt with in an escalation. The first deletions may not come with a warning. Repeated deletions may come with a warning, and then escalation into longer and longer suspensions.

Likewise, it also says that some content may result in an account suspension. If the user has a very long history of positive contributions and no history of previous poor conduct, it would have to be a pretty heinous comment for me to jump immediately to a suspension. I would delete, and would probably not wait on a warning, but I wouldn't place a strong member of the community into a suspension for one comment that may have been made in jest or that didn't come across well over the Internet or may offend a group of people unintentionally.

I'm afraid that people will read this CoC and interpret these "typical actions" as mandates for moderators. I'm also afraid that users may bring their complaints to Meta and not present the full picture - other users may not have access to the full backstory, especially if there's a lot of deleted content. Moderation is a volunteer activity - I don't want to deal with people who want to rule-lawyer. I am open to feedback on my actions, either publicly on Meta or via feedback to the community team, if anyone things that my actions as a moderator are inappropriate.

I do think that it's totally appropriate to give clear, specific examples of behaviors that violate the CoC. I do not believe that it is appropriate to link the course of action that moderators take with specific behaviors.

Comment: "I do not believe that it is appropriate to even suggest the course of action that moderators take." Maybe something like this instead: *Depending on the severity and regularity of the violation, moderators may take one of these actions...*

Comment: @called2voyage That would be ok. Let me edit to reflect that my objection is the linking of actions to behaviors.

Answer (score 57):

### What's good

First of, I like the Code of Conduct in concept and content. All single issues that I might have are already carefully worded in other answers. You stated a goal what you wanted to achieve with this Code of Conduct.

> We needed to write for the best of folks in our community. Off-putting things tend to mostly come from folks who will probably only ever blow their top once. We have moderators to deal with the tiny fraction of people that never care about rules, so our code of conduct needs to mostly resonate with the overwhelming majority of people we really want to keep. We need less over-posturing for troll dispatching and more guides to help decent folks avoid more common pitfalls.

From my point of view that's a good CoC to reach that goal.

### What's Concerning

My feedback however is concerned if that's the right goal. What is the CoC supposed to achieve? It's fed by the general problem by all policies that are longer than a paragraph. ***Nobody reads them.***

> “[...] *Apple could put the entire text of "Mein Kampf" inside the iTunes user agreement, and you'd just go agree, agree, agree - what? - agree, agree.”* - John Oliver

Be it Terms and Conditions, User Agreements, Terms of Service, Codes of Conduct of however they are called they are basically worthless documents until someone sues. Which is even more useless in this case since we've got a few million Stack Exchange users who've never heard or agreed to said Code of Conduct—unless you plan to force-feed it to every user with a mandatory accept box before continuing to use the site. Furthermore, I'm guessing, nobody wants to use this document to sue.

### My Question: What's the CoC really for?

Can a CoC really replace a half-pager guideline on what's okay and what's not?

**Be Nice**

It has three bullet points in relatively easy to understand language.

**The Code of Conduct**

The new Code of Conduct has eleven bullet points and contains the words *neurodiversity* and *instigated* while proclaiming one shouldn't discriminate due to English fluency with the former not even in most modern dictionaries and the latter easily being replaceable by *caused*.

Even worse the bullet points are not contained within themselves. The bold typed start proclaims something different than the following sentences will:

> **Be friendly, clear, and constructive.** Editing, commenting, and sharing feedback are healthy parts of our community. When giving feedback, avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online. Be open to receiving constructive feedback.

The further sentences are trying to explain the bold stuff but are demanding something completely different. The ability to be friendly, clear and constructive has very few to do with the expectation of handling other people's feedback openly.

Additionally I wonder why only people here to help should be patient and only people looking for help should make others' lives easier?

By honest counting we'll get to about 12-15 bullet points with behavior requirements in the Code of Conduct, possibly based on user roles. That's longer than the creative commons license that legally covers our posts...

Again, that's okay for a Code of Conduct. Those are wordier documents since they are the modern insurance of employers to either sue employees if they violate it or at least being able to say publicly they told them to be better. As employee I have to sign that I read it and will act accordingly.

**What's it good for?**

Sure Stack Exchange can set up such a document and point to it if there's a shitstorm about an escalation of racial slurs in the comments. Goal achieved? :|

Meta can discuss that document forever but that won't change a thing. The people civilly discussing a Code of Conduct on Meta are not our problem. Which brings me back to my question, what's the CoC really for? Giving meta a great basis for discussion or **reaching the goal that *Be Nice* originally set out to do**? It's very well for the former but in my opinion a step back for the latter.

### Why it cannot replace ***Be Nice***

Airplane emergency check lists have at most 5-6 items. No good modern checklist has more because people can't remember more consistently. (Cf. [The Checklist Manifesto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0312430000)) We as community and especially the moderators need that check list to point to. You've started alright with the tl;dr part, already anticipating that—well, nobody reads the full thing.

The problem is that the tl;dr is currently the boiled down rainbow unicorn part of the document. It says basically be a good person. It's missing, don't be a jerk. When was *Be Nice* used? Exactly, when someone wasn't. The CoC cannot be very well used for that. Most of the target group *Be Nice* was thrown at won't read that much text. The CoC sounds like nice background literature and the tl;dr version is a nice opener to set a communities tone.

However, the target group we need the current *Be Nice* for was forgotten. Jerks. With the rainbow unicorn "be a good person" version as opener and the linked CoC the people who need behavior guidelines will never pass the guidance, "don't be a jerk", or any of the unaccepted behaviors in the CoC. This cannot be stressed enough, they will not be read.

Let's have a look at racist comments for example.

- Previously any racist comment ***failed to meet the criteria of two out of three points from a half-pager.***
- Now the reason to delete said comment ***is buried behind a preamble, in a bullet point list, on item seven, in a sub-enumeration of items which might partly require a dictionary (depending on English fluency).***

Exaggerating a bit, will moderators in the future write after deleting an insult to an overweight person, "deleted comment due to CoC, Section 2, Sub-Section 3, Item 10"? That is not making it easy on anyone who wants to uphold any standard.

I very much prefer a hint to something simple, like *Be Nice, Don't be a jerk*. Maybe the current *Be Nice* is the best tl;dr the CoC can have.

Most times simplicity is key. That's why airplanes rarely crash.

---

<sub><sub>I see the irony in my post failing that simplicity badly. But it's late and I didn't have time to write a shorter post.</sub></sub>

Comment: "*When was Be Nice used? Exactly, when someone wasn't. The CoC cannot be very well used for that.*" Um... why not? Particularly the TL;DR version of the CoC.

Comment: @NicolBolas because the CoC has explicitly another target group and because the tl;dr; doesn't contain any don'ts.

Comment: After reading this answer, I wonder if the new CoC could _augment_ rather than _replace_ the old “Be Nice” policy.

Answer (score 55):

Sigh.

I think the SE team really wants to put a new Code of Conduct through, so I am not particularly convinced that many criticisms will have an effect. Fundamentally I find
an overview how cases and differences in opinion should be handled very good. It helps other people to understand how a site works (if they bother to read it; the shorter, the better) and it gives everyone a guideline what to do if something is amiss. A kind of manual if "Be Nice" does not work.

But one point which I personally miss in the existing answers is

**Not anticipating the effects of difference of culture and worldviews.**

While being mostly active in other groups, I also participate in Politics.SE.
The people visiting Politics.SE are *very, very different* in nationality and political beliefs and often quite vocal about their beliefs. They also have often...erm...a not so good opinion of other viewpoints and worldviews.

Let's play devil's advocate here.

> Follow our guidelines and don't worry if others suggest changes or edit your question - they’re trying to make your question helpful to as many people as possible.

Important to note: Here it is assumed that the behavior (edits or changes) come from good intentions. Am I too pessimistic to assume that not all changes or edits are well-intentioned? Especially with politically charged items like e.g. "Crimean accession"/"Russian annexation"?

> If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it. Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. Even if this wasn’t your intent, apologize and move on.

> No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language. Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle put-down.

I really can't imagine that trying to enforce this in Politics.SE will not cause pandemonium. **Opinions of politics who are deviating from the own belief are making people often extremely uncomfortable**. Politics is also full of charged words who can be extremely easy misinterpreted as put-down or unwelcoming. Given that intent should not matter at all and an apology should be issued to a political opponent (!), I cannot see that this will work out.

But even on less controversial themes I see that we have a plethora of many, many different cultures and worldviews. Some people are more straightforward than polite, some cultures have other core values than others. **The nice thing about "Be nice" is that is an accepted behavior in all cultures.** Even if someone violates expectations, talking together will solve this easily if both sides have good will. The new Code of Conduct tries to introduce a "One Size, Fits all".

**Another problem I see is that the Code of Conduct now urges people to point out behavior *they think others find uncomfortable*. People cannot read minds, so if e.g. I am targeted by a remark, at least I would like to retain personal autonomy if and how I find a remark offensive or hurtful**.

Overall, I do not like the overall tone of the Code of Conduct. It feels in my opinion too...**patronizing**.

It is not more the tone of "Be nice": We trust you that you have good intentions. If something goes awry, try to fix it to the best of your abilities.

It is now more: "We need to show you what correct and acceptable behavior according to our standard is. Intent does not count anymore, if something goes awry, we will decide if there is an offense and how to cope with it".

I think SE goes the wrong path. Trying to project a good image, trying to be welcoming to everyone, trying to avoid and subdue conflicts, trying to urge others to report others. But I don't think what I say does matter at all.

> The attempt to make heaven on earth invariably produces hell. Karl Popper.

Comment: +1 I do think it is a difficult balance to get right, and ultimately it does come down to the communities themselves to work out what the 'proper' behaviour should be (if we are trying to be 'democratic' about it. I think the interesting thing would be to consider which lines in the CoC can be taken out, not what else needs to be added in :)

Comment: It might also be that SE doesn't care if Politics.SE needs to be shut down. Just saying.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.  What's really happening here is that certain antisocial individuals simply don't like to see people or groups succeeding or expanding.  So, they seize on any **pretext** to object.  No matter how *apparently valid* the criticisms are, they are really just saying "Stop communicating, stop being there."  And rather than cheerily ignoring it, Stack Exchange is trying to please and appease everybody and avoid offending *anyone.*  That's impossible, of course.  What we really need is a redoubling of focus on the **actual** mission of SE.

Answer (score 50):

There is a difference between what you write and my expectations of Stack Exchange.

#### SEN CoC:

> **Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or language.** Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know, join us in building a learning community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

#### My CoC Expectation:

**Our mission is to build a website with good questions and excellent answers on a diverse number of fields.** Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. We're all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor. **Be Nice.**

---

#### SEN Expectations:

> - **If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming.** Learning how to participate in our community can be daunting, especially if someone is new. Be supportive while others are learning.
> - Etc.

#### My Expectation:

- **Be nice.** Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. We're all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.
- **If you are here to find an answer, and did not find it, please check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).** If you did find your answer, please upvote.
- **If you’re here to help others, be patient and nice.** Learning how to participate in our community can be a learning curve, as this is not a forum.
- **Be friendly, clear, and constructive.** Editing, commenting, and sharing feedback are healthy parts of our community. When giving feedback, avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online. Be open to receiving constructive feedback.
- **If you are reading something that is making you feel uncomfortable, let it go.** If you see a pattern, flag it and move on. Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. You can handle this (as an adult) and move on.

**Unacceptable Behaviour:**

- **No discrimination.** This includes any language you know is offensive to people. This includes (but not limited to): nationality, race, gender, religion, sexual orientation, disability or mental illness.
- **No harassment.** This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.
- **No name-calling or personal attacks.** Focus on the content, not the person.

---

#### My 2 cents

I don't think there is anything wrong with the current Code of Conduct. Worse yet, Stack Exchange and I have different things we want out of it. SE wants to be *an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or language*. I want a site where I can *get a solution to the problem I am facing*. I *want* expertise. I *expect* decent human behaviour.

If I ask a stupid question to my friends, I will get a stupid answer back. If I ask a question to my wife that tells her I have put little effort into it, I will get an answer to do my own homework. And I am fine with both of them: **Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you.** Effort in, effort out.

If you want an *an inclusive community*, go find your sub reddit. I want good questions with excellent answers.

Comment: I agree with you 150% about the MISSION.  No, the mission is not a "welcoming community."  And it never was.  The core mission was "Ask questions, get answers.  No distractions."  As noted on the Tour Page.  Along with, "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about (site topic)."  THAT'S the mission.

Comment: I agree with everything you said. The plain truth is not everyone should feel welcome. For instance: People that can't be bothered to read the rules on asking questions, people that can't be bothered to do minimal effort in researching, asking coherent questions, or read and understand the answers, people who are clearly posting homework assignments. This CoC completely ignores these issues, and puts responders who rightly rebuke these types of users, in jeopardy. I have faith in moderation to downvote bad answers. But, there is a big cost for moderators to remove all the terrible questions.

Comment: In my view one of the best answers. With all due respect to the authors of the proposed CoC, I believe that it will destroy what SE is today. The proposed CoC is an invitation to self-declared social justice knights to open SE for their crusade. See _Well-Kept Gardens Die By Pacifism_ at Less Wrong for what awaits SE if it continues on this path.

Answer (score 36):

There is a large amount of redundancy in this document, which is the main issue I have with codes of conduct in general. More text means more opportunity to exploit the wording. Even if such an attempt is not successful, it wastes people's time. In particular, everything under the section describing unacceptable behavior is redundant. These are *all* covered by the Be Nice policy. Why do you need to specify that you can't use discriminating language for people based on their race? In other words, why do you have to say "be nice to everyone" and then, right after that, say "be nice to people of other races"? It seems unnecessary and overly politicized. Just say that you have to be nice and keep feedback constructive.

In addition, simply calling it a "code of conduct" leaves me with a dirty taste in my mouth. Such documents are very frequently used for abuse, both by people with good intentions and those with bad intentions. As such, many people do not like such things.

I think the current Be Nice policy is *wonderful*. It is simple, easy to read, and highly inclusive. **I would like to see anyone point out a negative action that would be allowed in the Be Nice policy, but not with this new code of conduct.**

Comment: "*These are all covered by the Be Nice policy.*" Are they? Because people apparently keep doing them and keep not getting sanctioned for it. So if you're going to tighten the reigns so to speak, it's a good idea to make it more clear what is and isn't acceptable.

Comment: I get what you are saying, @forest, and to be honest, I like your comment around focusing on the TL;DR version. It mostly works.

Comment: @NicolBolas *"people apparently keep doing them and keep not getting sanctioned for it"* - citation needed. Barring odd occasions when a user blows up, starts throwing insults at people, and gets suspended, the only item in that four-item list that I think I've seen happen on the site is the "subtle put-downs and unwelcoming language"... primarily because it's a vague enough phrase that any criticism could be construed as a violation.

Comment: I think the point about calling out race &c. as a particular instance isn't so much for the people who would break the policy, as to give confidence to people who are minorities in some way and would be afraid of discrimination or harassment. That's certainly the idea with the kind of open-source and conference CoCs on which this one is based.

Comment: @DanHulme What further confidence is needed than telling people to be nice? Do they really need coddling to feel good? I think the idea that they need _special_ treatment to be a little offensive.

Comment: @forest Under the new rules, if you find it offensive, they should stop saying it and apologize to you.

Comment: "your post makes me uncomfortable" Under the new CoC, your post now violates the CoC. If I comment this on all of your posts ever, you are now a repeat offender that needs to be banned. Isn't exploiting the word of the law to your benefit fun? ^_^

Comment: @Tezra Indeed. And while that specific example is rather contrived, it is _certainly_ possible to abuse the exploit the word of the law in such a way. Even if it doesn't end up working, it will have wasted everyone's time, which is still a win for the trolls.

Comment: @forest I'm just afraid that will work if a tired mod sees it in a flood of 500 identical flags. Although if we REALLY want to rules lawyer this, **not harassing people is Unacceptable Behavior**. So we are all violating the CoC by being nice?

Answer (score 34):

A single, simple question in response to this question:

**What problem(s) is a Code of Conduct intended to solve?**

Is the problem "new users don't read the Help Centre and therefore don't know about Be Nice"? Because... if they can't be arsed to read the short-and-sweet policy, do you really think they're going to read the much longer Code of Conduct?

If the problem is "someone got moderated and complained about it because they allegedly don't understand why, and the current Help Centre documentation isn't thorough enough to give an adequate explanation" then fair enough, a more comprehensive document than Be Nice will probably be helpful. Unfortunately, it's been my past experience that most people who choose to challenge administrative decisions do so not because they believe a mistake or bad judgement call was made, but because they are bad actors who either get their kicks out of wasting others' time, or honestly believe they are in the right despite any and all evidence to the contrary; self-entitlement seems to be a helluva drug.

---

As for the new CoC itself, I have a fundamental objection to it on the grounds that I feel its language is too restrictive and open to abuse by bad actors; but if (as it appears) it's already been decided that it shall be imposed, then I have the following comments:

- Keep the original/legacy Be Nice mission statement as the very first item in the new CoC, with a blurb before and after that gives context. Something like:

> Our Code of Conduct can be summed up by the following statement:
>
> > **Be nice.**
> >
> > Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. We're all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.
>
> The above can be ambiguous, so in order to clear up any misinterpretations we've outlined fuller guidelines below.
>
> <rest of CoC follows>

- [@Kobi's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312050/) re "Our mission" is spot-on, I won't bother repeating what he's said here, except to concur.
- "Our expectations" section: move the "If you’re here to get help..." bullet point to the top of the list (same for the abridged versions) - IMO the CoC is primarily aimed at new users, so let's put them front and centre.
- "If you’re here to get help...": as @fbueckert noted, add something about demonstrating effort.

Comment: well said. I like your suggestion of putting the TLDR version up top

Answer (score 32):

In the spirit of not discriminating against people based on English fluency, what do you think of making the CoC available in simple language?

The first two sentences in the code are already prime examples of sentences that are possibly hard to parse for non-native english speakers.

Instead of a long sentence like:

> Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know, join us in building a learning community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

What about multiple shorter sentences?

> It does not matter whether you came to ask questions or share what you know.
>   Join us in building a kind, collaborative and respectful community.

Carrying this on throughout the CoC is... challenging. Simple language is **hard**

> It applies to everyone using the Stack Exchange network, including our team, moderators, and anyone posting to our Q&A site or chat rooms.

---

> It applies to everyone using the Stack Exchange network.
>   That means our team, moderators and every user on any Q&A site or chatroom.

---

In a similar vein the vocabulary used in the CoC belongs to a pretty high register. 
That's all fine, but be aware that not everyone will know all the words. And of those not everyone will actually go and look them up to understand the CoC...

Comment: "In a similar vein the vocabulary used in the CoC belongs to a pretty high register" - simple language, please :P

Comment: Good examples of what I was trying to say in my answer's title.  +1 for making good recommendations.

Comment: I'll add that jargon and idiomatic expressions are equally bad, especially if they translate poorly. What even is a "put-down"? I've never used this word in my life. If you know where it comes from and who uses it, please edit Wiktionary. :) https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put-down

Answer (score 32):

I think the intent is (broadly) good. I get what it's trying to do.

However, some of the specific phrasing seems to be setting us up for not being able to moderate effectively (whether as diamond moderators or ordinary users). For example consider this heading:

> No discrimination ***of any kind***.

(emphasis mine, because that's where the problems arise)

On this network of sites, we're dealing (almost entirely) with responses to text. The very *function* of the site is to discriminate between good answers and poor ones, and so we must be careful only to proscribe what we actually want to avoid, not to make it impossible for the site to function.

This kind of overly-broad prescription gives people who write poor answers every excuse to cry foul.

My suggestion is avoid 'dealing in absolutes' like that, because it gives people too much opportunity to point to the policy and turn the tables -- to make life very difficult for the people trying to keep the site functioning by constantly finding this or that objection to their crappy posts "discriminatory". It *is* discriminatory -- ultimately because their post is bad.

Please allow us to continue to discriminate in the ways we should -- against poor content -- rather than setting yourself up for *compulsory* defense of poor content on the grounds that someone may cite discrimination ("you're discriminating against me because I can't spell, cite a reference or express a coherent thought -- that's not fair, I am just differently-abled, I am offended and I demand the commenter be suspended according to the clear wording of the guidelines. At the very least their discriminatory comment should be removed and their discriminatory downvote reversed").

[In actual cases, though it won't be framed quite so obviously, but rather more subtly.]

That we should be nice when we do discriminate against poor content, and avoid being (by some reasonable standard) personally offensive, sure, I agree with that -- we should focus on the content and not the attributes of the poster, but people's capacity to find *any* form of criticism personally objectionable is boundless.

I also think the document focuses too much on the *action* to be taken. This is akin to the usual objections to mandatory sentencing in judicial systems -- they reduce or remove the ability to consider mitigating circumstances. That such recommendations should exist somewhere (as guidelines for moderators) sure; I don't think their place is in a policy document.

Comment: It seems to me that the punishments outlined in the CoC are more akin to sentencing guidelines than mandatory minimums. The former are not usually decried as awful these days.

Comment: Thanks. It's possible I took them the wrong way; I would still suggest that it's not the right place for them.

Comment: This is a crucial point, and it's part of why [nvoight's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312059/300411), saying that the CoC should forbid harassment, not discrimination, is so important.  *Every user* on the network "discriminates" all the time against poor content (by voting it down), content that violates site policy (by voting to close or delete it), and uninteresting content (by ignoring it).  "No discrimination of any kind," without a clear definition of what "discrimination" means, is a dangerous standard.

Comment: I was going to suggest that swapping the word from "discrimination" to "bigotry" would fix this... and noticed that actually, that's exactly the word the existing [Be nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) uses. Not sure what motivated the change, but I think it was a bad one.

Answer (score 31):

1) It is understandable that as SE becomes an actual corporation, political correctness will infiltrate the official language. The usual side effect is that the text becomes boring, and this is what happened with the new Code of Conduct. In other words, **you turned "be nice" into "be heavenly"** and the rather universal consensus is that heaven is a boring place while you're alive.

2) **You spit on the glorious past of the SE universe by not including the motto "Be nice" in the new text.**

3) You start the Code of Conduct by writing

> Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel
>   welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or
>   language.

***Regardless of expertise?*** Consider that in all cases where the subject matter of an SE site is also a subject matter of formal education, the "regardless of expertise" part is a clear signal that it can be also used as a do-my-homework mill (and without pay).

4) It is also understandable that you want to increase control over the moderators. But by suggesting

> If you have concerns about how a moderator has handled a situation,
>   contact us directly

you do it in a most belittling way. **The suggestion should be to first discuss such issues on the meta-sites.**

But apart from the above, the new code of conduct is certainly more suitable for a massively massive audience, that really needs to be told not to put the cat in the microwave oven to dry. And I write this without any degree of sarcasm whatsoever.

Comment: I think you might be imagining a problem when you talk about "[increasing] control over the moderators". Contacting SE with a concern about moderation has always been the policy. I think most other moderators would agree with me that we would suggest this to a disgruntled user over posting on meta. I don't feel belittled by this advice.

Comment: @DanHulme It is certainly a possibility. I guess it has to do with my professional biases.

Comment: I agree, I feel that mandating behavior beyond the simple doctrine of "be nice" ruins any sense of freedom this forum has. It also sets a precedent of allowing the corporate leadership to define our culture and the way we communicate. TL;DR: I on principle don't like companies telling users how to act.

Answer (score 31):

Stop pretending you care what we think.

**Stack Overflow is not a community**

*A nightclub is not a party*, it is a business that provides a *party-like experience* to sell overpriced cocktails.

*Stack Overflow is not a community*, it is a business which provides a *community-like experience*, in order to sell eyeballs to recruiters and other advertisers.

The nightclub owners have decided that rather than cater to the die-hard fans, they are going to pivot and make a mega-club that trades off the cool of the old name. But they can't say that's what they are doing, because that would kill the cool.

Stack Overflow owners have decided that rather than cater to the professionals, they are going to pivot and turn into a do-my-homework, write-my-code site for CS students, and lazy or incompetent programmers. There are a lot more of them than there are of the experts, and they'll ask and answer far more questions. They'll mostly be duplicates, but so what? It's engagement, it brings the eyeballs, and that's where the money is.

Like any other social network, we are not paying, *we are not customers*, we are *the **product***.

**The goal of quality is taking a back seat to increasing the audience.**

90% of new questions are poor quality, duplicates, answered by the most basic one-page tutorial, or all three. "join with group by" must have been asked thousands of times.

What to do about it?

**If it's a problem, there are solutions:**

**Homework must be banned outright**

These are ALWAYS duplicates, often people doing the same course.  Create a new site: https://cs-homework.stackexchange.com.

**SQL-Help must be moved off the main stack overflow**

There's clearly a lot of demand for it and plenty of people willing to provide it. But SQL is hard and it's in the nature of SQL that it's not obvious how one question relates to another. The answer is often something like "you need use a subquery not a join", and the question is not *strictly* a duplicate of anything, and *will never be useful to anyone else*.

Create a new site: https://sql-help.stackexchange.com.

**Finding duplicates must be incentivised**

Closing as duplicate should be rewarded, answering a question later closed as duplicate should be negative rep - you should have duped it.

**But is it really a problem?**

Not for the "community", that's a side issue. Is it a problem for the owners?

So that last three sections suppose that quality is actually a primary goal. In fact I don't believe this is true of the leadership: It's clear that growing the audience is the primary goal and quality has been sacrificed for 4 years as no way has been found to align the two.

Closing duplicates is not incentivised because they don't want us to do it - it kills engagement. At the moment, answering an easy duplicate will earn all parties 30 rep, ***and this is intentional***: [Whatever they say they want, what they really want is what they reward.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions/253083#253083)

From now on, it's newbies answering duplicate questions all the way.

Because "engagement" beats curating a high quality resource in cash terms.

Comment: "*Closing as duplicate should be rewarded*" interesting idea. Would need to somehow tackle the issue of people doing it for the reward, especially with many grey areas where dupe or not dupe can be debated. Tho, if we cleaned up the site in general and removed low quality localised questions then people will do this more naturally anyway as the reward will be keeping the site clean. At the moment it's a losing battle so not enough people bother

Comment: @James If it's not part of the rep system it won't get done. At present asking and answering an easy duplicate will earn all parties 30 rep. That's why it happens ***and this is intentional***: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions/253083#253083

Comment: Yeah I get that, but introduce "2 rep for marking a Q as a dupe" and half of Stack Overflow questions will be flagged as dupes overnight. People only interested in rep will likely inadvertently vote in favour of each other and many will end up being (incorrectly) closed as a dupe.

Comment: @TimPost I don't think I'd classify it as rude... Cynical, definitely. But quite honestly, when I'm in a cynical mood SO does make this impression on me, as well. If the complaints in social media about not being "welcoming" are taken seriously, then the causes of this kind of reaction should be looked at, as well.

Comment: @TimPost And that is you being "nice"? I thought this was one of the better posts here. And if you are going to accuse people of being "mean-spirited" and "falacious" you should be specific in those accusations.

Comment: @NeilButterworth the first sentence alone "Stop pretending you care what we think." makes it clear that nothing good would come from SE engaging with this post any further. Large parts of the post are assigning some nefarious purpose to decisions by SE, making this far more of a personal attack than anything resembling constructive criticism.

Comment: @Mad Well, it's not obvious to me that people like Tim Post _do_ care what we, the users and contributors of SO,  _do_ think. They seem to have their own agenda, which this post spells out quite well.

Comment: I removed my comment. However, I put this document out for comment _in good faith_ and it is, at best, disingenuous to imply that I'm being anything but honest when it comes to caring about the feedback that we receive, or this community in general. You start off with _Stop pretending to care_ and as someone that has _also_ given _years_ of his time _for free_  to help this place run, I'm gonna call you on that.

Comment: @Tim Well, we all contribute for _free_. Except maybe not you, as you seem to be " Director Of Community Strategy for Stack Overflow" - does that mean you work for SE? For money? Genuinely interested.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I was an elected mod (2011) for several years prior to being hired, and quite active all the way back to the early beta. Yes, I'm compensated now, but I'm not pretending to care because it's my job and I _strongly_ resent the suggestion of it. That's all I'm going to say, my character was challenged, and I'm taking the opportunity to refute a pretty low blow.

Comment: @TimPost it was a plural "you". It wasn't aimed at you personally - how could it be? I wouldn't know you if we passed in the street. Which goes to my point: SO is not a community, it is a business, and we are not members of a community, we are interchangeable punters providing content to draw more punters to sell to advertisers. A year ago the complaint was we couldn't find good questions. Now we can't find good answers either. You lost the focus on quality in favour of inclusiveness, now we are drowning in worthless clickbait: SO has eight answers for you! Number 7 will astound you!

Comment: I've had questions marked as duplicate which weren't. I explained clearly why not but the duplicate-claimer is either too stupid or wrongly incentivised to care.

Comment: "We'd like your feedback" answered with "Stop pretending you care". Wow. Basically publicly calling the poster a liar! Even IF you somehow knew for a certainty that @TimPost were insincere, how does this type of approach help anything? Unless one is going for pure shock value, which would seem to be the "engagement" and "eyeballs"-seeking which you yourself are decrying... considering the context, that this received upvotes is both ironic and disappointing.

Comment: @TimPost actually I was planning on posting an answer as well but seeing that this is just another time when people (meaning a employee) asked for "*all feedback*" but then respond defensively when given negative feedback - I just can't. I typically use SO more during the summer (when working on technical projects) but after the problems with Docs and then all the "SO users are horrible" posts/blog (yes I know this is not what they were meant to convey but they still feel like "pretty low blows" to many of us) - I just haven't wanted to face the scrutiny of answering questions this year.

Comment: ...you (again, meaning SE as a company) has lost a lot more trust then I think anyone there realizes. It can feel like any attempt by people to express this is either ignored, responded to negatively, or just given an empty response. I don't doubt logically that SE employees really care but then again some days I really do.

Comment: I think that punishing people just for answering a duplicate is a bit harsh. The rep shouldn't go away. If anything the answer should transfer to the original post by some automated mechanism. I say this because sometimes answers to duplicates *are* still quality content and the user didn't know a duplicate existed. However, there is a recent trend of certain MSE users answering and then closing as duplicate regardless of whether the duplicate actually matches. In other words they purposefully close it to prevent other people from answering... stopping that is a higher priority imo

Comment: @TheGreatDuck if you have specific examples of users answers, and then closing as a wrong duplicate, please flag them. That's certainly something that's actionable now, if it is happening.

Comment: This post is blatantly abusive and I have flagged it as such as it is in violation of our Be Nice policy.

Comment: To ignore constructive criticism is unintelligent. The post is fine, the comments were a bit below the belt imo. I get why someone on the receiving end could be offended. That said, again, just use it as useful info in whatever capacity it can be useful and move on

Comment: I strongly agree duping should be rewarded, yet I won't go as far as to say: "answering a question later closed as duplicate should be negative rep". Sometimes questions are duped a little to quickly, and there is a specific edge cases in the actual question that merit its own answer.

Comment: It's not `black` or `white`. `SE is an emotionless company` vs `SE is a community`. _It's both_ to different extents. You are using an extremely simplistic description of the situation, aka a [biased model](http://katbailey.github.io/ml/images/biased.png) (biased models aren't always bad; often they are extremely handy and adequate, but not in this case). That being said, I fully agree that CoC feels like aiming to promoted growth and will damage quality, as it has been the case for quite a while now with other SE policies.

Answer (score 29):

> #### Reporting and Enforcement
>
> ...
>
> - Address it directly. If you’re comfortable addressing the person who instigated it, let them know how this behavior affects you or others. You can also remind them of the Code of Conduct. If the behavior escalates, disengage immediately -- staff or moderators will take action.

Can you clarify how to do that and when? Via comment would conflict with [When I should comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

I'm surprised that meta pages were never mentioned either. They could provide a platform for discussing problematic cases - maybe more suitable than the comment section below someone else's post. What role do they play?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. We'll have to take another look at the commenting guidelines. Re: Meta - opted not to mention it in this iteration precisely because we'd need to clarify its role & set people's expectations about going to Meta - which is a hefty topic in itself.

Comment: @Donna I think that paragraph makes _perfect_ sense for chat. Less so, if at all, for main sites though. Perhaps retargetting it to chat only would be a good idea?

Comment: I see this paragraph a bit as a contrast to being welcome and no put-downs. When you are having trouble with the person, personal addressing of it can often make it much worse. Telling people to clarify it between themself can lead to flame wars, which could be avoided if some third person would help them to cool down instead of shouting at each other making it only worse. And in the end both will tell you "the OTHERperson started it I tried to tell THEM to stop and THEY made it worse". This does not help any of the persons in the conflict.

Comment: @Anne  Why did you delete your question, posted today (March 24, 2019) on meta.se?  I was working on a "fleshed out" answer with examples, as you asked me to do, when you abruptly deleted your question.

Comment: @Namaste Sorry for making you waste your time!

Comment: No problem, @Anne.  BTW, I did think it was a good question, at least with respect to wondering how "philosophy" might be a valid tag on MSE, if ever!  Cheers!

Answer (score 29):

### Language is bloated; leaner prose is recommended

I'll make two concrete recommendations.

1. Change

   > *Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or
   >   language*

   to read

   > *Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate.*

   Comment: (1) stronger statement when unqualified, and (2) "regardless of *expertise*" looks to be completely opposed to the basic SE model.
2. Remove or significantly rewrite this one:

   > *No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language. Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For
   >   example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle
   >   put-down.*

   Comment: while this bullet aims at a worthy goal, it is "soft" rather than "hard" as guidance.  Too subjective.

   [As was discussed in the "let's hold comments to the same standard" Q&A on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311757/380710), within the set of users that is *all SE users* there are varying abilities with language, varying writing styles, and a non-trivial number of people who use English as a second, third, etc language.  (Not to mention different cultural assumptions ...).  The term "unwelcoming language" needs to go because it is nebulous at best.

   Removal of this point, since it is redundant, is my suggestion.  The CoC goes into considerable detail later on behavior that is not within bounds.  If for reasons of required content or completeness it can't be removed, then it needs to be rewritten to be less subjective.

   At the very least, this bullet point needs to be the fourth of four bullet points, not the first of four.  The name calling / discrimination / harassment bullet points are all of greater weight.
3. Some other good recommendations for leaner, [more concise language are in this well presented answer by @Vogel612's Shadow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312084/380710)

Answer (score 29):

It fails to address the source that ignites the rude comments, which is very often rude questions.

For example, if we look at this:

> Unacceptable Behavior
>
> No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language. Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle put-down.

I agree. But take a moment to consider who was the first offender here. It was the rude poster who is abusing the site by asking something that they could Google in 5 seconds.

We need a clause about Unacceptable Behavior when asking a question. Examples:

- Asking questions where the OP has not even done minimal research.
- Asking questions which is nothing but a copy/paste homework dump, with no effort by the OP.
- Asking questions that are not even remotely on-topic.

These are among the rudest things I see on the sites. We offer ***free*** expert advise that would cost a lot of money in a different context. The bare minimum to ask in return is to not abuse that service by asking questions like the ones mentioned above. Doing so is plain rude to the people who are taking their time to answer questions, free of charge.

Failing to understand why the community views such question as rude, is a failure to understand and deal with the root of the problem. This is where a whole lot of friction regarding this topic comes from. People rarely post rude comments out of the blue, they are rude when something upsets them.

If there is no clause about rude questions, SE will once again antagonize the community.

Comment: Well, [they're going to try to clarify that new users are also subject to the CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct?page=1&tab=oldest#comment1020807_312044).  They're also going to try to put the [effort expectation somewhere more likely to be read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct?page=1&tab=oldest#comment1020664_312049).  You bring up a good point, though, about what should we do when all of it gets ignored.

Comment: I think there are different kinds of rudeness – in tone (which is addressed in the CoC), and in the fact of putting questions which are not appropriate (which is not addressed). Which kind of them is worse is obviously a point of discussion.

Comment: A question that has an answer that can be easily found in a search of the web in general is not rude. It's desirable, as long as the same answer to the same question is not easily found by searching SE/SO. The "research" clause on questions means searching SE/SO, not searching the internet in general. My read of the helps, FAQs, and meta posts on the topic of easy to answer questions is that they are in no way rude.

Comment: I tend to disagree with Todd's point, but not for the obvious reasons. I agree that filling gaps in the SE/SO sites by posting questions which can be answered elsewhere is desirable, BUT leaving them unanswered is not. If the asker posts the question to fill gaps, then they're supposed to answer them themselves. Our help is not supposed to be abused under the guise of filling in gaps, when in reality the asker didn't try to find the answer, AND didn't try to contribute to the community.

Answer (score 27):

The *Our Expectations* section sets up a dichotomy between people who are here *"to help others"* and people who are here *"to get help"* that I think is unhelpfully misleading about the site's core purpose.

To quote [a recent comment of Shog9's](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7087104#7087104):

> a lot of the problems we have with Stack Overflow arise from how poorly we describe it to folks.
>
> It's a reference site. That's how almost everyone uses it, and how it is primarily useful. You don't go to Stack Overflow to learn anything, you decide to learn something and sooner or later end up on Stack Overflow to fill in the gaps in your knowledge. I'd guess somewhere north of 90% of everyone who has used Stack Overflow uses it that way.
>
> But we describe it as a place to ask questions... As though that's anything but a means to an end.

This point goes hand-in-hand with [others' feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312050/200582) about the mission statement in the CoC. We're meant to be [*"working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"*](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Question askers are supposed to be asking themselves whether the question they want to ask is a *useful addition to that library*; that is the basis upon which other users will vote on their questions. If it *is* a useful addition, then the asker can very much claim to have "helped others".

Indeed, an asker whose question gets a good answer may not have *personally* received any "help" from it at all. For all we know, they already implemented a crappy workaround for the problem they were working on, shipped it, and moved on to other things, all before ever getting round to asking on Stack Overflow - and then posed their question purely out of altruism to help the *next* programmer to encounter the same issue.

The dichotomy presented by the CoC does a disservice to askers in several ways. It presumes that they are asking for selfish reasons, when they needn't be. It devalues their contribution to our library by presupposing that only *answering* questions can "help" anyone, when in fact there is great value (and a fine art) to creating tightly-specified, concisely-answerable, broadly-applicable, easily-Googleable questions for answerers to hang their answers upon. But perhaps most importantly, in the context of our current problems with both question quality and civility, it sets up the reader with false expectations about what we expect from question askers here, by making us sound like we are primarily a helpdesk when in reality we are primarily a library.

I'd rather all the language about "helping" was culled, and the primary goal of Stack Overflow* - building a library of questions to help *future readers* - was emphasized. Doing otherwise sets up askers for a negative reception that they won't understand.

---

* It occurs to me after posting that I've completely neglected all the Stack Exchange sites other than Stack Overflow in this answer. However, I think this commentary applies to most of them, besides the oddball ones like Puzzling.

Answer (score 27):

Since you seem to be strongly focused on making people feel welcome, this information might be worth a new answer despite the existing 103 existing answers:

> If this Code of Conduct is adopted in its present form, I would feel less welcome on this site.

To avoid misunderstandings, I want to emphasize that I strongly agree with important parts of it (basically everything about discrimination, harassment and personal attacks) and that I'm well aware of the importance of taking the perspective of others (e.g. those who feel uncomfortable or discriminated against) and of not imposing our perspective on others.

However, the draft sets this consideration, as important as it is, as absolute and takes an extreme position that I believe would be as harmful as it's well-intentioned.

> **If someone points out that your behaviour is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it.** Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. Even if this wasn't your intent, apologize and move on.

It's very important to be aware that we can unconsciously make others uncomfortable or affect them negatively. It's also very important to understand that we're not the sole judge of whether this has happened or should have happened. It's good that you're so aware of this and are emphasizing it. But you're throwing out the baby with the bathwater. Making just anyone who "points something out" the sole judge isn't that much better than making yourself the sole judge. If this item is taken literally, it would force me to apologize if I justifiably asked someone to refrain from a certain behaviour and someone "pointed out" that this made that person uncomfortable. That way madness lies. Not all forms of feeling uncomfortable can or should be avoided. Of course many forms can and should be avoided, and I appreciate that you're focusing on that, but it seems to me that you've somewhat lost sight of other, also very important considerations in the process.

> **No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language.** Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For example, saying "You could Google this in 5 seconds" is a subtle put-down.

That's neither subtle, nor a put-down. It's a criticism of behaviour that's worthy of being criticized. If you want to discourage this particular form of expressing that criticism because you believe there are better forms of expressing it that achieve the same effect while making fewer people feel less welcome, that's cool – but then you should acknowledge the constructive intent of the remark (instead of dismissing it with "regardless of intent") and concretely point out how you'd suggest improving on it. In its current form, this item reads as if there were no reason to write such comments, no problem with people spamming the site with questions that they could have answered in 5 seconds by googling – as if the only goal worth aiming for is to make people feel welcome and comfortable, no matter how anti-social their behaviour is. If you deter people from deterring people who should be deterred, that may do more harm than all the welcoming atmosphere can do good.

I'm a political activist; I've spent a large part of my life trying to understand other people's perspectives and deconstructing my own. I'm really not writing this because I can't relate to the ideas and principles that I feel have inspired this draft. To the contrary, I strongly believe in many of them. But I also believe that it's excesses like this draft that are giving them a bad name.

*Edit*:

Some more thoughts on the googling part: Further down, in the table, you use a different example for a subtle put-down: “This is obvious, just Google it.” That you're effectively equating these two comments illustrates the lack of differentiation in the draft. “This is obvious” is indeed a put-down (though, again, not a very subtle one to my mind). It takes what's obvious to me as a measure for what should have been obvious to someone else; and it implies that the other person isn't intelligent enough for it to be obvious to them (whereas it might just not be obvious to them because they lack some piece of prior knowledge).

This is completely different from “You could Google this in 5 seconds.” We're not talking about people here who might have a disability that prevents them from accessing the Internet. The person was able to find out about Stack Exchange and to figure out how to post a question here. It's not conceivable that they've never heard of search engines or are incapable of using one, yet capable of posting a question on Stack Exchange. I'm also not talking about a case where it might require some level of expertise to know the right search terms or to interpret the search results. There are often questions that would be answered by simply googling the central term in the question and reading its definition on Wikipedia that comes up as the first hit. There are also other indicators of complete lack of effort: Questions whose title is nearly identical to the title of an answered question, where you can check by entering the title in the “Ask a question” form that that question was suggested when the person asked the question, yet they don't even mention it, let alone explain what it is in the answer that they don't understand. Of course one can overlook things; I'm not saying that it's OK to insult someone for this; but if it's no longer OK to point out that the question could have been resolved with minimal effort and should thus ideally not have been asked, then that in my view is a problem, both in terms of the harm done to the site and in terms of me feeling welcome here with the judgements that I do sometimes have about what sorts of behaviour I find worthy of criticism. (Note that I'm pointing out that you're making me uncomfortable, so you should stop and apologize. ;-)

Comment: The "sole judge" argument hits the nail on the head. It's one of the things that were wrong with Jay Hanlons earlier "welcoming" blog. And now some SE staff wants to enshrine it in a new CoC. There are two sides to every story; the person who feels uncomfortable is not automatically right.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Not to mention that in any conflict, the person who first decides to summon down punishment on the other party by uttering the magic words "you are making me uncomfortable" needn't be the only one who is uncomfortable. At that moment the one thing you know - in an environment where a CoC like this exists and is well known - is that the person uttering those words has made a deliberate, conscious choice to exercise power over the other person and compel a public signal of their submission. *That* user, in my view, is the one who is likely to be toxic - not their target.

Comment: (It *also* has the effect, of course, that people who *are* uncomfortable will no longer be able to voice that to their peers in good faith and try to have a conversation steered away from an uncomfortable conversation amicably, because the CoC makes just uttering those words the web equivalent of obtaining a restraining order against the other party. It robs the uncomfortable person of the chance to reach an amicable, non-coercive resolution to the situation without aggressing against the other party, even though that's likely to be what they actually want most of the time.)

Comment: @MarkAmery: Plus one for pointing out the extreme polarization inherent here, that this kind of binary "everything is fine until suddenly someone's feelings are hurt and then bans all around" is actually *anti-cooperation*.

Answer (score 26):

> **No discrimination of any kind.** This includes any language likely to offend or alienate people based on (but not limited to): race, gender, gender identity or expression, English fluency, sexual orientation, disability, mental illness, nationality, neurodiversity, physical appearance, body size, or religion.

English is not my native language and maybe I'm nitpicky, but people cannot be *discriminated against* on the Stack Exchange network in ways that are public or actionable. Why? Because discriminate against means to take unfair action. Suppose I downvote all christians. Or Close-Vote all women. Or never edit post into shape that are from gay people. Or make any other kind of distinction. Even if that happens, it's impossible to catch and/or proof.

I think what you mean is no insults, bullying and harassment. If someone calls me the N-word, that's not discrimination. The site works fine for me, I get answers from other people, I can vote up or down, no functionality was lost. But it's obviously insulting and probably harassment.

So this point should really by a subcategory of "**No harassment.** This includes: (...) as well as any language offensive to ..."

Comment: The point about offensive/alienating language being harassment, not discrimination, is a good one that has been brought up by others, but I disagree with this claim you make: "Even if that happens, it's impossible to catch and/or proof." The SE staff actually does have the utility to investigate something like that. If a user is downvoting people, for example, because they are women, that means there is some way on the system to know they are women. The voting patterns can be compared against this information.

Comment: @called2voyage So assume you find a pattern. Then what? Are we telling people how to vote now? My last information was "everybody is free to vote however they see fit" (as long as you have only one account doing the voting and don't serial-vote a specific other account).

Comment: A down-voting campaign on women would be form of serial voting. It breaks the voting system because it is voting based not on content but on user.

Comment: It may just be my interpretation, but I think this has more to do with targeting users based on affiliation, with disparaging words. More about people writing nasty things in comments, answers, and chat, than about voting.

Comment: I'm just saying "discrimination" is... fishy. If a person harasses others on the street, you don't see a cop being like "Sorry sir, you have now harassed 58 slender white women in the past 3 hours, if I don't see you harassing a brawny black dude by 6 PM I have to arrest you for discrimination". I would simply hope we go with the very first harassment to nail the offender, instead of patterns and statistics of what might be discrimination.

Comment: @apaul nvoigt's point is that what you describe is usually referred to as harassment, not discrimination.

Comment: @called2voyage harassment is bad, harassment *for reasons* tends to be an extra level of bad and is probably worth escalated consequences.

Comment: @apaul I agree, but for example in my workplace harassment for reasons is still listed in a separate section than discrimination. Both discrimination and harassment sections have the list of the categories that you should not discriminate against or harass on the basis of.

Comment: @called2voyage kind of a 6 vs half dozen then. Discrimination would be a biproduct of harassment, right?

Comment: @apaul Not necessarily. Someone can discriminate without harassing someone due to subconscious bias.

Comment: Matter of fact people can discriminate against others on purpose (just think not hiring women on purpose) and be super-polite about it. Just because somebody doesn't swear or insult people doesn't make it ok to discriminate against others. But posting racial slurs or personal attacks based on any of the mentioned attributes is not discrimination, it's harassment.

Comment: Half of the premise of this answer seems untrue to me, at least in principle. If I were to declare on Meta that I will henceforth not accept any answers from white people, and then follow through, that would not constitute "harassment" of anyone by any ordinary interpretation of the word but *would* be a clear-cut, detectable case of discrimination. I'm not sure whether we've ever had a case like this in the entire history of the site, but it seems fair enough to declare in the CoC that, hypothetically, such conduct would be against the rules.

Comment: @MarkAmery That's correct. And I would not mind such a rule. I just think that the current CoC did not *intend* to handle what you describe. I think it means to make sure nobody is harassed with language targeting one of those attributes. Should your interpretation actually be what was *intended*, I stand corrected. But I doubt that.

Comment: @nvoigt Yeah, I agree there's at least a mismatch between the wording of the rule and the examples given.

Comment: You cannot guess from the user what is race or gender. In fact, what I have suspected, and a couple of times see proof (reflection on photos) is users posting with a female named and photo on the belief they will attract more help.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro For some sites on the outer rim of SE, giving that information in the post is needed for a good answer. For example questions on "Parenting" mostly start with "As a mother of" or "As a father of". And IPS.SE... well, if you have interpersonal problems, it gets *personal*, there is no way around that.

Comment: @nvoigt There are ways around that too in those sites. "My friend, my fiancee, my ..."

Comment: I think this paragraph is trying to say "no hate speech" without getting hung up on the highly charged term "hate speech".  And indeed, I'm glad it *does* avoid that term, but I agree that the content is mostly covered already as harassment.  What isn't covered there would be covered by broadening "No name-calling or personal attacks" to simply "no put-downs or attacks", i.e. of individuals *or groups*.

Answer (score 25):

I like this.  I'd like to tweak the language about enforcement a bit; right now it says "this is how moderators generally handle misconduct" and then describes warnings, suspensions, and expulsion.  That's all good, except that we sometimes see users test limits.  "Well, I did that and I didn't get a warning, so it must be ok -- how 'bout I try this?  No warning?  Great, then I can..."  While often this is malicious, we have to assume that in a worldwide, diverse community where not everybody speaks English well, sometimes it's more innocent.  Either way, we don't want to give people the impression that no mod response means they're doing fine; on larger sites we might not have noticed.  (Which is why people need to flag, but I digress.)

I think all we need to clarify this is to inject a phrase like "aware of", as in:

> This is how moderators generally handle misconduct **that they become aware of**:

It feels like that small change could prevent a fair bit of drama on metas and in chat.

I'm talking about the section on penalties, not about specific examples in the document.

Comment: Stackexchange has been pretty good about shutting down excessive rule lawyering imo

Comment: @ChristianRau I think examples *that are clearly examples and not definitions* are helpful; whether the ones in this document need to be tweaked is a separate matter that I hope you'll address in an answer.  (My answer isn't about examples; it's about how we describe application of penalties.)

Comment: Of course adding the awareness bit lessens the expectation of something happening because you explicitly mention that moderators might not be aware which isn't necessarily something you want to do in an enforcement section of a CoC. Especially the enforcement section should make the impression that breaking the rules has consequences, not that breaking the rules have consequences if and when arbitrary things apply.

Comment: @Helmar that could also be "when they become aware", so the fact that you sneaked it past people a week ago doesn't protect you when somebody finally notices and flags it.

Comment: Sure, it's a question of emphasis. Should the document emphasize that "appropriate action will be taken when there is CoC violation" or emphasize that "things that look like the CoC is ignored might be due to moderators being human and not because it's accepted." I'd argue the CoC should emphasize the first one while the description of what moderators on SE are hold a valiant defense of them only being human.

Comment: I know I've mentioned this elsewhere, but people of different cultures, people with conditions such as autism, and people who are not very fluent in English can wander into what seems like trying to push boundaries when they simply do not know.

Answer (score 25):

**Our Mission**

To expand on other comments on the same sections, these are concerning to me.

> Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel
>   welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or
>   language. Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share
>   what you know, join us in building a learning community that is rooted
>   in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

I thought out mission was to develop a searchable community of answers to common questions?

This doesn't feel like it describes the community as a whole, and is explicitly at odds with many of the largest communities which are predicated on referenced facts, not discussions.

We can be respectful of each other, but the rest of that statement just feels like something pulled from modern US politics and doesn't seem to really serve the SE communities in part or as a whole.

> No discrimination of any kind. This includes any language likely to
>   offend or alienate people based on (but not limited to): race, gender,
>   gender identity or expression, English fluency, sexual orientation,
>   disability, mental illness, nationality, neurodiversity, physical
>   appearance, body size, or religion.

Ignoring the fact that the statement is pretty much cut and pasted from US law, which is by nature inconsiderate of the other nations that participate here, the broader scale impact of such subjective language is something I think needs more thought before including it in the SE Code of Conduct that applies to all the communities within Stack.

**We are all just a little circular picture** and a bunch of words on this site. Almost none of those identifying characteristics are known or possible to be known without our own act of making them known. Including it just doesn't make much sense here. We are as anonymous as we wish to be.

**Each Stack Community is by nature, exclusionary and discriminating**.

The English Language communities require posts to be in English, the German community requires posts in German, etc.

The SO community requires questions to be technical in nature with regard to software development. Questions about computer hardware, politics, management techniques, or puppies are closed as off-topic.

Are you going to shut down the board on Catholicism, or Judaism, or Islam because discussions there could offend someone from a different religion?

Are you going to shut down Language Specific boards because they exclude someone who is not fluent in the language?

Are you going to remove the downvote button, as receiving downvotes (for a poor quality question) is likely to make someone feel unwelcome?

**I think the SE code of conduct should remain as general-principal as possible**, and allow each community to further restrict the conduct as makes sense in that community. This one-size-fits-all type of Code of Conduct under-serves our community as a whole. As written, it disallows the more fact-based communities the ability to be concise without dragging feelings into everything; and I fear the discussion communities will be dampened because no discussion is without risk of offending someone.

Comment: "We are all just a little circular picture and a bunch of words on this site. Almost none of those identifying characteristics are known or possible to be known without our own act of making them known. Including it just doesn't make much sense here. We are as anonymous as we wish to be." True, but some sites such as IPS may require divulging such information from time to time if you wish to ask about yourself instead of phrasing it as "asking for a friend". Even if you are "asking for a friend", you could still get targeted for, say, asking about LGBT issues.

Comment: That doesnt hold true for most of the communities, as most of them are on topics where asking questions that would reveal that about yourself are irrelevant to the topic, and usually edited to be agnostic. To me, it sounds like that would be a consideration to add to some form of Community Specific addendum to the Code of Conduct for communities where those types of discussions are acceptable. In principal, I'd say the global CoC should be rather loose, and the various communities can tighten the loop where it becomes necessary.

Comment: It should be a consideration because people are allowed to divulge information about themselves in their profiles. As long as they are allowed to do so, we should protect them and not allow for them to be discriminated against based on what they share there.

Comment: @Stephan: "*We are as anonymous as we wish to be.*" And those who do not wish to be anonymous should not be exposed to any greater threat of harassment or other bad behavior than those who wish to remain anonymous. Saying that you could have been anonymous must ***never*** be a defense against these kinds of behaviors. Anonymity is a choice, and we should not punish those for making a choice different from our own.

Comment: I absolutely agree with both of you. I'm saying that there is not way to blindly discriminate on this site. We as users have to make ourselves known, AND someone has to harass us. I don't see how the verbiage changes the already present and enforced harassment policies. Maybe I'm not thinking about it the right way, but that's why we're here: to discuss :) thanks for the feedback.

Comment: "I don't see how the verbiage changes the already present and enforced harassment policies." I don't think it does--it just makes it a clear part of the CoC.

Comment: With regard to *"We are as anonymous as we wish to be"*, here's my answer to [Is it possible to know the gender or race of another Stack Overflow user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366670/7586). **tl;dr**: This can be interpreted as the suggestion people should hide themselves to avoid harassment - that's essentially blaming the victim. Most of the conversation here is about people who do identify themselves.

Comment: There seems to be some impression that there is such a thing as perfect security. What is making me uncomfortable is there doesn't seem to be that acknowledgment. How far are you willing to go to ensure that there are never any victims?

Comment: I also find it very interesting that everyone has zoned in on that one particular sentence and made no comment to the rest of my points. That hyper focus is just reinforcing my point about current US politics rearing it's ugly head in stack.

Comment: I just find it funny that the description of discrimination, something everyone knows what it is without it being spelled out, is more discriminatory against non-English readers than the actual dictionary definition. When was "neurodiversity" ever a problem? How many English readers had to look that up? Also, discrimination is a subset of harassment, so technically, that section is redundant anyways.

Answer (score 24):

"No discrimination of any kind" means no voting, no flagging, no closing, no deletion, no account bans.  It means anarchy.

I know "discrimination against wrong or harmful answers, plagiarism, spam, and foul language" isn't the kind of discrimination that is intended, but it clearly is included under "any kind".

How will the Code of Conduct be enforced without discriminating against violators?

Answer (score 23):

> - No harassment. This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.

One of these things is not like the others, not just in this item but in the containing bulleted list.  Let's give it more emphasis somehow.

I'm talking about:

> sustained disruptions of discussion

If you ask most people to talk about types of harassment, they talk about personally-directed stuff -- harassing a person (like stalkers) or a category of people (like bigots).  But the disruption you're talking about here, I think, is the kind of behavior that derails chat, stirs up arguments in comments, edits destructively, posts inappropriately... the category that a community manager once explained to moderators as "breaking the site", even if no individual action is sanctionable.

As a moderator I've seen many users dance on that line, and seen mod teams struggle with how to handle them.  The CoC won't make that struggle easier, but could we try to clarify this a little in hopes of reducing occurrences or at least better warning people?  Maybe "sustained disruption" merits its own bullet point?  Maybe there's some other way to work it in?  I don't have an answer here, but especially as there's been some concern raised about rules lawyers, I'd like to clarify that if your target is *a site* or *a chat room* instead of *a person* or *a specific group*, that doesn't make it ok.

Answer (score 22):

I like this policy a lot, especially the "Our Expectations" section. I think that this section does a great job of covering all-too-common mistakes that *well meaning* users can make, which end up sparking fights and alienating other users. I would be proud to strongly encourage all current and new users on the site I moderate (Mi Yodeya) to read this policy.

One point I'd like to discuss:

> **No discrimination of any kind.** This includes any language likely to offend or alienate people based on (but not limited to): race, gender, gender identity or expression, English fluency, sexual orientation, disability, mental illness, nationality, neurodiversity, physical appearance, body size, or religion.

There are matters that are subject to intense disagreement between people who ascribe to different national, religious, or ideological identities, where simply stating the position held by one group, even from a [NPOV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Neutral_point_of_view), is likely to offend some large subset of members of another group.

Some examples (adjectives chosen to *not* align with any particular examples I can think of, but are realistic in tone):

- "`Religion R` considers `Religion S` to be in the category of 'wackiness.'"
- "`Religious Text T` refers to `Practice P` as 'outrageous.'"
- "`Nation N` considers `Nation O` a 'rogue nation.'"
- "`Nation N` forbids `Practice P` based on their `Ideology I` which considers people who do `P` as akin to 'thieves.'"

Given that many people with certain identities are likely to be offended by each of these statements, do these statements constitute "discrimination," which we must not tolerate at all? I would hope not, since that would make it impossible to ask and answer about the quoted sources, even if they're within the scope of a given site

On the other hand, the policy can't be "you can quote anything you want as long as you voice it from a NPOV," as that could open the door to people making statements of exactly these forms, but actually with the intent to offend or alienate, rather than to discuss.

Clearly, at the end of the day, determining how to balance the merits of information and inclusiveness with respect to particular statements is going to come down to moderators' discretion. I'm wondering, though, whether this "None of any kind" kind of policy will make moderators' jobs harder in some situations. I'm sorry, but I don't have a good idea for alternative language, and I am not at all advocating striking this important point.

---

<sup>I note without surprise that this sort of consideration [was discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240888/179) with respect to the last iteration of "Be Nice."</sup>

Comment: Quotes deserve special consideration otherwise stuff that's considered discrimination is not voiced from a neutral point of view.

Comment: Related: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1100/47309, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170143/134584, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361661/18356, https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/57985/47309

Comment: Excellent point.  I personally think that trying for a ***neutral*** point of view is (a) probably unattainable and (b) a very bad goal.  Trying for an *objective* point of view is a great thing to do.  Attempting to be *neutral* results in quoting a small bunch of sour grapes in an effort to give "fair" treatment to both sides, or quoting strawmen disagreements with your own view.  Neutral writing feels slimy to read.  No one is neutral, but it *is* possible to be objective.

Comment: @Wildcard, actually, I think I meant something more like "objective" when I wrote "NPOV." Either way, you can end up with statements that are part of worthwhile discourse but that will offend some people.

Comment: That's true.  I think it's better to take responsibility for your own point of view—some people use "NPOV" to avoid responsibility for what *they* have chosen to share.  I think you nailed it with: *'...the policy can't be "you can quote anything you want as long as you voice it from a NPOV," as that could open the door to people making statements of exactly these forms, but actually with the intent to offend or alienate, rather than to discuss.'*  That's why I find so much of Wikipedia feels slimy to read.

Comment: I have not yet found any organised religion that compiles without warnings/errors.  Same goes to most governments.

Comment: @MartinJames this just means you didn't try the right programming language. (E.g. try Whitespace.)

Answer (score 22):

> 1. Even if you don't agree with all of it, do you feel that this is a
>      reasonable code of conduct? Does it affect your recommending Stack
>      Overflow as a resource in any way? How so?

The focus of the CoC in my opinion puts too much effort on the existing user-base that has learned and follows the SE-rules to be nicer rather than asking new potential users to learn our rules and adhere to our standards.

On the other hand, I do know a lot of people that refrained from actively using StackExchange sites because there was no CoC in place and that they will feel more safe with one in place.

In total, I consider the CoC a good thing if we could get more people on board that bring the platform forward.

The focus shouldn't only be to become a welcoming and inclusive community. We should not forget the quality and usefulness of the overall content.

> 2. Is anything in this document, including its purpose, unclear to you
>      in any way? Are there any instances where you'd suggest alternate
>      language or copy? Where? Why?

There are certain places where I find the direction off or unclear, e.g.:

> If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. Learning how to participate in our community can be daunting, especially if someone is new. Be supportive while others are learning.

This can backfire and increase the culture of always-helping even in spite of questions that better should have been deleted in the first place.

There is a certain noise level of new-member questions that don't fit our standards, yet which that are encouraged by reputation-farming / helpful-to-a-fault helpers.

Also to what extent should I be *welcoming* and *supportive*?

Do I break the guideline of being supportive by downvoting a question of a first-time poster? I don't consider it very welcoming to receive a bunch of downvotes on your first question, yet the high standards for content made the platform as successful as it is today. You should embrace that also within your CoC.

> If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Our community is made possible by volunteers. Follow our guidelines and don't worry if others suggest changes or edit your question - they’re trying to make your question helpful to as many people as possible.

Please link to the appropriate how-to-ask-pages for each StackExchange network page. Make it mandatory for new user to read the how-to-ask-page. That's something we should be able to expect from new users.

> Be friendly, clear, and constructive. Editing, commenting, and sharing feedback are healthy parts of our community. When giving feedback, avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online. Be open to receiving constructive feedback.

Better: *be friendly and concise*. Avoid noise by not writing "Can somebody please help me?" in your question or posting "Thank you!"-comments.

> If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it.

Please explicate this. As it reads, it the perfect way to completely disengage potential helpers because of fear that they *might* make someone uncomfortable. People may stop giving valid criticism and feedback just because one person thought a comment made somebody else uncomfortable.

*Nobody likes* to hear that their question is too broad, off-topic or should contain a better code example. *Nobody likes* to hear that their answer won't fit the need of the OP.

Should we stop pointing out flaws because it may make someone uncomfortable? Some people are very direct, others feels uncomfortable very easily.

**I won't know, despite my best efforts to be constructive, how my text will be perceived.**

When you want to be a member of this community, you should be able to handle and accept feedback. That very *feedback might make you uncomfortable*, which can be a *good thing* as you have a chance to grow as a person because of it.

> No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language. Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle put-down.

What's the alternative? Downvote and not comment? Just flag the question because of low quality? Without giving the OP a reason to why I did such action? Or should I just let the question stand, because we-as-a-community want to be inclusive? How does this help the quality of the overall content?

I understand that RTFM-comments and lmgtfy-links are not helpful, yet it also showcases a problem this platform has with newcomer questions.

There is a reason why people react with these kind of comments. That should be addressed as well, even though not necessarily within the CoC.

> 3. If you're a long-term contributor, how does this document impact 
>      your feelings toward new users and their needs, if at all? How does
>      it impact your feelings toward the company? Or, more broadly, did
>      this document inspire any metacognition at all?

It's a good thing to explicate the rules beyond a fuzzy "Be nice". I think the current draft does not highlight enough that new users should also put in more effort than on other platforms.

> 3. If you're someone who wants to contribute more often, or have felt
>      yourself sort of stuck on the fringes, how does this document change
>      your perception of the site, if at all?

I may refrain from commenting or pointing out flaws because it may make somebody uncomfortable. I need my stackoverflow access as it is a professional resource for me. I most likely would use only the downvote and flagging option in the future.

Comment: "On the other hand, I do know a lot of people that refrained from actively using StackExchange sites because there was no CoC in place and that they will feel more safe with one in place." – do they refrain because no CoC document is in place, or because actually people are not conducting nice?

Comment: "I won't know, despite my best efforts to be constructive, how my text will be perceived." This underscores one of the biggest mistakes with the tone of this entire document: no Code of Conduct should require the members to read minds in order to comply with the Code of Conduct.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Depends on who I talked about stackoverflow at tech conferences. Some won't contribute to any platform not having a CoC. From other's perspective, people are not conduction nice on StackOverflow. (I don't share that sentiment. I find SE refreshingly direct, yet I may be part of the problem.) It's worth noting that mostly women and/or junior developer are having a hard time engaging or even being "bold enough" to ask their first question.

Answer (score 21):

> **Apologize and move on**

I'd drop the apologize part personally.  Just because someone felt upset about something doesn't mean they are owed an apology.  The person who meant no harm may not feel they did anything wrong either and should not have to apologize.  They should avoid further offense if reasonably possible, but it's somewhat dangerous to expect an apology for reasonable behavior that is misconstrued and may be seen as overly sensitive by the speaker.  Sure, it would be nice for them to apologize, but I don't think it's a necessary requirement and requiring it is likely to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: A requirement to apologize is likely to produce non-apologies such as "I'm sorry you were offended", which don't make anyone feel better.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I'm afraid the non-apology would rather be: "I'm sorry you *felt offended* by my remark, which *wasn't offensive* at all." Comment flamewar almost guaranteed.

Answer (score 18):

My biggest question is whether the "be nice" emphasis of this policy is really directed at *comments* or whether it affects *moderation* actions as well.

Should we interpret this new policy as discouraging downvotes and other quality moderation actions? For example, a new user posts a blatantly off-topic, unclear, and poorly researched question. Should I *refrain* from downvoting, closevoting, flagging, or taking other moderation actions on the question out of sensitivity for how the OP might feel to see their question moderated, or will I be allowed to proceed as normal and just be discouraged from *also* posting potentially snarky or condescending comments *about* the poor-quality of the OP's question (e.g. "Do your own homework", "Please stop posting off-topic questions, you are going to get a question ban", or "Did you read the Help Center?")?

On SO, I can sit on the "new questions" page for an hour and use up an entire day's worth of close votes and downvotes just on zero-effort homework dumps, wall-of-code debugging requests, resource requests (always off-topic) and "omg my puter no worky halp" posts. The Question Ban exists [to help ensure high quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60294/336163), and downvotes, closevotes, delete votes, and flags are the primary tools *by which we indicate quality*. By refraining from non-comment moderation actions, we could soon end up with a dramatic drop in quality, both by leaving bad posts on the site and not shutting off people who continually make poor posts. A few low-quality posts can be edited into shape by the community, but many can't. Do we want to just start allowing those posts to stay (decrease quality because it's rude to censor low-quality questions) or do we want to just be nicer while at the same time taking action to ensure high quality? Similarly, I can hang out in the SOBotics chat room and get notified of dozens of "me too" 'answers' that are being posted at every hour of the day and night. Should we be 'sensitive' to the feelings of those who post NAA answers ("I was just asking for help, they didn't have to get all medieval and downvote me and delete my post!") and fail to remove the posts, or should we just downvote, flag, and delete these inappropriate posts silently, avoiding confrontation with the posters but also not telling posters what they did wrong and what they should do next time?

To some extent, it does makes sense to cut the snark and simply silently downvote, closevote, and delete low-quality posts, but there is another issue. A few times a week, someone comes onto Meta.SO *complaining that their posts are being downvoted and closed with no feedback, and begging for information on what they are doing wrong so that they can improve*. I'm in a quandary.

@JohnHascall 's idea of canned comments for common downvote/close reasons is intriguing. If there was a pre-vetted 'nice' way to ask someone not to post zero-effort homework dumps, I could see myself using that instead of trying to come up with a phrasing myself that could be misinterpreted by the poster or a mod as unnecessarily snarky or rude. That could be an interesting solution - we could have a process to provide feedback to users to indicate what it was that they did wrong, but by having those comments pre-vetted, we can protect *ourselves* against having our attempts to 'educate' the user misinterpreted as not being nice.

Comment: (Re your first sentence) That's a good question.  I think the fundamental point that must be more widely realized is that allowing [Stack Exchange's *real* mission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312206/307622) to become secondary, and failing to take actions to accomplish that mission, ***is NOT nice.***

Comment: +1 to the canned responses for poor quality questions part. I have a document with the links to various how-to-ask links that i use to moderate the first-timers. This is kind of a no-brainer feature that would not only save us volunteers a ton of time, but also provide helpful feedback to the first-timers. That alone might be enough to do away with all of this CoC nonsense while achieving the goals it's intended to achieve.

Answer (score 17):

I like what's in your Code of Conduct. That's pretty much common sense and good to be manifested. Apart from that, I don't think it's necessary. I'm very active on Stackoverflow, and **I haven't seen a single quality post where the user had to suffer from anything of what you've listed under**

> Unacceptable Behavior

*What you are doing with the Code of Conduct is like treating the symptoms of a disease, not the disease itself.*

**Instead of spending time on rewriting / extending the be nice policy, I'd suggest to put all your effort into**

**How can people be taught to write good questions**.

Once things like [“Ask a question” wizard prototype](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype) are implemented, improved and really used, most of the so called unacceptable behavior will vanish, because it's no longer needed to ask someone to google before asking a question (and the other things) - **your question filter and wizard should already have handled this**.

---

> No discrimination of any kind. This includes any language likely to offend or alienate people based on (but not limited to): race, gender, gender identity or expression, English fluency, sexual orientation, disability, mental illness, nationality, neurodiversity, physical appearance, body size, or religion.

That's common sense, I've never seen anything of that on Stackoverflow

> No harassment. This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.

That's common sense, I've never seen anything of that on Stackoverflow

---

Apart from that, like said above - it's always better to be in a friendly environment; that's why I like the manifestation.

I strongly recommend though, to look on what is StackExchange doing to force unacceptable behavior. That is, letting people bully existing users with tons of unanswerable/no effort/... questions. It's on Stackexchange to do something against that.

Stackoverflow is the best source on the internet to get answers to programming questions, no matter how hard they are to solve. We shouldn't do everything to bring the quality level to reddit. That exists already.

Answer (score 17):

As briefly as possible (with full knowledge simply stating this will make many believe I am a villain:)),

> If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it. Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. Even if this wasn’t your intent, apologize and move on.

This is highly problematic because people can choose to be offended by anything, and people have different tolerances for what makes them uncomfortable.

**Stack Exchange needs to be a civil space**, but it's also a public space, and community guidelines have to reflect the median, not the extremes.  (The extremes may be said to include both the most uncivil individuals *and* the most sensitive individuals.)

The likely result of this directive is an inverted hegemony by which people who choose to read in malicious intent to innocuous statements end up becoming the harassers, attacking those they believe have transgressed.

Answer (score 16):

> Respect requests to stop behavior that is making others feel uncomfortable. Remember that no question, answer or comment is worth getting worked up over. If someone is making you upset, ask them to stop. Do your best to resolve it civilly with the other person or take a break from the situation. If they still won't stop, we may consider that harassment (see Unacceptable Behavior).

This will prove to be the mischievous hobgoblin of the policy. The potential for abuse of this one is of legendary proportions as anyone with any sort of difficulty can claim that practically anything is making them uncomfortable.

Comment: In my experience it's what comes *after* the "hey, can we not talk about $TOPIC because $REASON" that really drives things. When I've seen that taken seriously and met with "oh, sorry, I didn't realize. Do you have a minute and are you willing to explain the discomfort a little more so I can understand better..." there's a real moment for people to grow in understanding and connection. Or to smoke out a mischievous hobgoblin who, frankly, won't be able to genuinely engage with that sort of response and it's obvious to everyone in the room that they're trying to bully others with the policy.

Comment: OTOH when it's *assumed* that the intent is bad and it's met with "oh, another of those, shove off jerkwad..." things go badly. Maybe not at that moment, but that's a room whose "culture" is being set at "don't assume good faith." In other words, **bad-faith actors are the mischievous hobgoblins, not bits of policy.**

Comment: @nitsua60 the corollary to that is, of course, if the bad faith actors are the problem, why assume a policy that can easily be exploited won't attract them.

Comment: That's where users who habitually engage in such behavior and abuse the policy will be quickly detected by moderators. Someone cannot claim everything on SE makes them uncomfortable. Even if it does, then this probably isn't a site they should be comfortable being on and it should be rethought as to whether they actually should be here. e.g. A user is offended by just programming. Not a particular bit of offensive code or variable names. Just the act of programming is offensive. They obviously shouldn't participate on SO.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck There is more to SE than just SO, and I'm already seeing this abuse on the softer sites.  Furthermore, this behavior is **NOT** quickly detected, and it does drive people away

Comment: @nitsua60 at The Workplace, we've had a spate of people going around changing all the pronouns, BTW, so this DOES happen and it was not resolved quickly, for a real life example to prove that this is not just navel-gazing on my part.

Answer (score 16):

Unfriendly behavior is not a cause in itself, but a symptom of a deeper problem. Stackoverflow sends thousands of newbie questions to everyone, flooding the reading stream of willing experts with what is spam *to them*.

Stackoverflow provides insufficient ways for askers (or others) to mark their questions as newbie question, and insufficient filters for experts to allow them to choose what they want to see. What works for thousands of participants does not work for millions.

As an example I prefer to just look at questions who are 5 hours old, have no answer and have a positive score. I might miss a few interesting ones, but avoid most annoying ones. But to do so I have to use a clumsy browser bookmark and a userscript to hide all my search options. Why can't Stackoverflow provide such options conveniently?

This is a sample search query that I bookmarked:

```
intags:mine answers:0..1 score:2 is:question closed:no duplicate:no hasaccepted:no created:3m..1d lastactive:9d..0d
```

Facebook has a button labelled "Show me posts like this less often". Not sure how that works, but why can't stackoverflow use this mentality to help readers avoid seeing posts that they do not wish to see?

A different CoC does not change this, just like the last 10 years what was missing was not a better CoC. The CoC is just a meek attempt to appease the PC activists, it wont change a thing.The next logical step is to remove downvoting, because of all the hurt feelings of askers who get downvoted a lot. Downvoting is also "a subtle put-down".

Give experts an easy way to see only expert questions, and experts will stop leashing out against what is spam *to them*.

This would also help keeping experts interested in the platform, rather than turning away in disgust of all the spam.

Comment: How do you envisage the impact of your proposed feature on non-diamond-mod moderation tasks? My instinctive reaction is that by hiding a lot (perhaps the majority) of questions from some of the users with sufficient rep to moderate them, poor quality questions will accumulate and dilute the usefulness of search results. Although there's a tradeoff against burning out expert responders, so please don't see this observation as a black-and-white rejection of the idea.

Comment: I cannot predict the impact on how much moderation will happen on what posts, and what kind of questions would accumulate. Users who enjoy to moderate would still be able to see all posts, I think of better filtering as an opt-in feature. For search, the search algorithm handles quality filtering. The internet is full of trash, but search engines manage to get useful results to the first page. Moderation is most valuable for frequent search results, and those still would get a lot of attention.

Comment: I like this idea. Maybe it could be turned into a feature request.

Answer (score 15):

Does non-discrimination mean we ought to lower the bar to be more accepting of patently dumb questions?

I co-moderate the Christianity StackExchange and there are any number of awful questions one could ask about Noah's Ark for instance.  We pretty much allow 'em if they're objectively answerable, but to be objectively answerable they have to show a little bit of research and come from an identifiable perspective.

If we were any nicer we'd allow all manner of craziness.

So, basically, we've created our community rules (same as all the other communities) that supersede base policies.

Could we have 10th amendment to this CoC that says users should abide by community rules as well?

Comment: Superseding base policies is indeed the biggest problem here.  [Our mission is to build a **library of detailed answers,** *not* to build an "inclusive community."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312206/307622)

Comment: @Wildcard, not any more. I wish it was, I've upvoted you, but it just isn't. We, the interchangeable punters, don't decide what the mission of the Stack Exchange business is. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct/312272#312272 Heck, we aren't even customers - *we are the **product***.

Answer (score 15):

"If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it. Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. Even if this wasn’t your intent, apologize and move on."
The way I read this is that if for any reason anybody feels uncomfortable in response to something I have written, the source of their discomfort is my unconsciousness and they are automatically owed an apology.

I think this needs serious rethinking and reworking.

Comment: Beyond the dicey meaning, I think it's also just too long a way to say what they want to say, which can discourage readers from looking at it.

Answer (score 14):

Tiny but extremely bothersome: the structure of the "unacceptable behavior" section.

The heading is "Unacceptable behavior". I expect a list of bad things which a person can do. Instead, I see

> No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language. Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle put-down.

That seems to say that not subtly putting down people is unacceptable behavior, if you read it without any common sense. It pinches a bit. It doesn't effectively damage readability at all, but it does seem a bit imperfect and weird.

Can we remove the "no" at the beginning of each line? Think of it...

> Unacceptable Behavior
>
> - Subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language. Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others. For example, saying “You could Google this in 5 seconds” is a subtle put-down.
> - Name-calling or personal attacks. Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").

Comment: oh, wait, I guess someone *could* rules lawyer it into non subtle putdowns being ok....

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Well, I _did_ warn you that it doesn't damage readability at all ;) It's just... weird... to leave it like that.

Answer (score 13):

There's a subtle aspect to the rewrite that I think is a HUGE improvement.  I don't know to what extent it was deliberate, but I hope that it will be preserved when incorporating any feedback.  And that is: attention to the *positive* behavior we want to encourage, rather than emphasis on the negative.

Glancing over the current (to be replaced) write up of the "Be Nice" policy, the words that jump out are:

- **jerk, name-calling, rudeness, belittling, bigotry.**

Glancing over the new writeup, the stand out words are:

- **help, patient, welcoming, friendly.**

All by itself this is a dramatic improvement.  I feel it will have a disproportionate impact on the actual effect on people reading the "Be Nice" policy.

(By the same token, I've always been sort of ironically amused at "safety" posters that show people banging their heads into things and getting hurt.)

This goes beyond the bolded words and into the more subtle word choices.  The "tl;dr" version of the flagging bullet point has a beautiful phrasing for the follow-up sentence: "Every person contributes to creating a kind, respectful community."

The writing overall show a good grasp of the subtle effect (sometimes not so subtle) of word choices on emotional responses and actions.  Good on you.

Answer (score 13):

> Flag the harmful content. Depending on the content, flagging will alert moderators or trigger an automatic deletion.

Since this is supposed to be for everyone I have to point out new users [can't flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) untill they have atleast 15 reputation.

Comment: SE team folks recently [bragged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311544/165773) about the plan to test allowing new users to flag comments on their own posts

Comment: @gnat As soon as that plan becomes reality, I will remove this answer.

Comment: based on past observations on proposals of real changes that could improve SE network I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for this to happen

Comment: @gnat the doctor told me that holding my breath for six to eight weeks would possibly be damaging to my health.

Answer (score 13):

The other posts cover most of the concerns pretty well. So I will add what I think this document missed out on.

Namely, **Actionable Items**. Sure you mention flags and contacting and telling others off (at your own risk); But as a user, when I want an expansion of "Be Nice", I don't care about the definition of harassment. I know what harassment is.

What I REALLY want to know, is how can I take `Did you Google this first?`, and turn it into something more acceptable without losing the important message (that you are expected to Google this before asking)?

As a new user, I had to stumble into Meta, and how to properly use it to resolve conflicts (like an edit war, or why a post with no comments or answers has 5 down-votes despite appearing to meet all the site requirements). The CoC should link to supporting resources like how to use Meta. (Don't put this all in the same document or it will become a swamp. Just link to related support content with a quick reference)

The CoC also takes the position that only you are at fault. While "An eye for an eye makes the world blind", There really should also be a link to another resource for **How should I deal with problem users/content?** This policy discourages giving factual constructive criticism, and leaves people with down-votes/deleted content. Giving people electric shocks for "bad" conduct is very harmful to both parties. If **I** am the problem, I should be directed to a resource that clearly explains why, and what I can do to correct this. (This is currently done with sharing Meta topics, as that is the best way to deal with SEs fluent nature, but is done rarely. The CoC should give guidance to do this short of practice.)

As a semi-casual user, I find the new CoC useless. It conveys no information to me that "Be Nice" didn't. (Other than implying having a sense of humor is a suspend-able/ban-able offense) What it really needs is references to addition resources related to common "Be Nice" issues (like no effort questions).

---

One last note `Unacceptable Behavior` and `No ...` is a double negative. I get what you meant to say, but better to remove the extra Nos.

Comment: Many of the per-site metas have a question containing some pro-forma comments to be used when welcoming new users, from the review queues, etc.  These could be the basis for a similar resource containing comments pre-vetted as sufficiently welcoming.

Comment: This answer seems to take a lot of inspiriation from the modern practice of Criminology- that it's possible to systematically and sympathetically help people who engage in inappropriate behaviors (theft, rape, second degree mopery, etc.) without condoning those behaviors.

Answer (score 12):

### Reporting and enforcement

> We take your reports seriously. Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct in good faith may face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team. This is how moderators generally handle misconduct:
>
> [image: Warning/Suspension/Expulsion]
>
> *All actions will be taken on a case-by-case basis at the discretion of our moderators.* Here are a few examples:
>
> [image: Behaviour/Action table]

1. The two tables don't match. Content deletion just appears almost out of nowhere in the second table. Warning doesn't appear at all. The mismatch could be fixed by standardising the two tables to say *Content deletion and warning* or *Warning and content deletion*.
2. What about chat suspension? AIUI that falls between warning and account suspension on the severity scale.

Comment: "will remove offending content" => content deletion

Comment: Yes, I spotted that while I was writing the answer and changed "*out of nowhere*" to "*almost out of nowhere*". IMO the point still stands.

Answer (score 12):

The draft has a section on enforcement that confuses me. Account expulsion is mentioned there, but that is not actually something we do now (spam, trolls or socks are removed, but that's not really relevant for the code of conduct).

Suspensions are mentioned to be "one day or more", but actually in most cases they start at 7 days. The escalating suspension lengths are not mentioned at all, and they are probably the most important aspect to know about the enforcement in general.

I'm not sure what is to gain by the examples given there, I don't think they can represent the way this works well enough to be useful. Most of the enforcement is about patterns of behaviour, not individual actions, so this gives a bit of a wrong impression.

One thing I'm wondering is whether this new code of conduct is actually meant to change the way we moderators enforce the rules, or is it meant to represent the existing rules and customs around enforcement?

Answer (score 12):

I agree that there needs to be an element of nice, although I'd prefer to talk more specifically about being "civil" than "nice" given our tight Q&A format and huge community.

The lack of conforming to requirements by users plays a massive part in the fact "nice" is currently missing. In a huge online community with people ignoring rules and with great potential for nonconformity, "nice" will only maintain civility to a certain degree and mostly only with those who are naturally nice anyway.

People who are naturally nice will all get on with it and in a civil manner, without the need for a CoC. Some just need a nudge and get a bit caught up in the frustrations etc, but those who really won't be nice or who don't adhere to requirements simply need strong rules, not telling "please be nicer" as why would they *suddenly* just do that?

This is (sadly) the fundamental issue with any large community, including ours I believe - the issue that:
**The users who are not affiliated with "nice", who ignore rules for their own means and are uncivil, they drain the resources without giving back which means other "nice" users have to put extra in to compensate. Then those who *are* being nice are being taken advantage of, which is "not nice", and suddenly those nice users are the ones dealing with a lack of "nice", and as a result "nice" will naturally dissipate from it being unfair - precisely one of the main issues we face now.**

We do need more "nice" but that will only happen if you strongly tackle the ones breaking the civility and not conforming to requirements. Being nice will not stop most non-nice people from causing problems, they do it *because* they are not nice and, as with any community, rules are needed to *force* them down certain paths! I wish it were not true, but ignoring this in the name of being "nice" will hinder fixing the problem and ironically hinder bringing about more nice.

It's a bit of a gloomy picture I paint on top of all this "nice" talk, but without hard rules in place, made clear, and importantly *enforced*, we will not have civility, let alone "nice".

***What* "nice" should mean and *where* it should be applied**

(taken from another answer of mine but is very relevant here)

- **Comments** should "be nice" and explain the rules and requirements of this site in a more welcoming way rather than short and blunt. This has the chance to make people feel welcomed and possibly more likely to improve their question/answer.
- **Question** askers should "be nice" and recognise their question is very important site content which if is bad has potential to be harmful to the site in various ways - bad search results, the need for moderation, bad content, etc. Questions produce much work and resource usage, by bringing about the need for edits, comments, votes, flags, and answers. This is a lot of power, and with it comes great responsibility.
- **New users** should "be nice" as they're new to a site, and should take some time to learn its ways (we should make this easy of course). E.g. when someone informs them their question has an issue, they should look to fix it. They should be nice and not want to come to a new site and expect everything to be their way, on a site that's been here for many years with specific ways. Once a new user posts their question there is no "us and them" they're entirely part of the "us", and should care about the site and the quality of that question.
- **Answerers** should "be nice" and recognise that answering poor questions may well give that one person information they wanted, but the site repeatedly makes it clear this is not what it wants. It adds poor content, which in turn attracts more poor content, and brings about the need for moderating. We have millions of questions and answers, and it only needs a small percentage of those to be bad for it to be fairly noticeable and have a negative impact.
- **Stack Exchange** company should "be nice" and recognise that those arguing over the poor and lazy questions, and those who answer them, have to heart the very interest and goals Stack Exchange declares it has.

Some return points on what I've seen debated so far:

1. Site rules cannot only apply to those who have read and understood them! This would be unfair, so even new users without knowledge should be expected to learn, or need to be issued any relevant penalties (perhaps some new less severe ones to get them to the info about expectations). This can be done while being civil and nice, but is a necessity to maintain order and this civility all round.
2. Being a new user is not an excuse to not fix a poor question once learned of that requirement. They are getting all the benefits of the site's resources, functionality, and people's time, and it is therefore only fair that they uphold the requirements that make the sites great in the first place which is providing them with the aforementioned goodies!
3. "Be Nice" is great, but should not mean "leeway to let the rules slip by". That includes bad question after question after... and nothing done about it.
4. This should be about "all users" being nice, and regardless entirely of any particular action taken. So rather than focussing on commenters being unkind, also see that *poor questions are unkind* to both people trying to help and quality of the sites.

**Most importantly:**

5. If question quality rules were perhaps a bit stricter, but definitely enforced much sooner so bad questions don't stand a chance, then there'd be much less of a problem with people not being nice, because there will be much less to not be nice about!

If we could make a ton of bad questions not happen, and more go away quickly, it would greatly reduce bad comments and people not being nice, because laziness and no care for the site's quality is where a lot of "not being nice" comes from.

We have the Help Center (etc) which lists dos and don'ts, but I think a lot of them read like "guidelines", almost optional in some case, rather than very important rules that keep the site in order.
An idea would be to (leave the Help Center as it full of info) and introduce a new page, linked in the top bar, with short and to the point info of the core requirements that keep the sites clean, organised, and civil. Such as a two column list with `requirement | penality`.

This should include all the things which on face value may seem trivial but harm the sites greatly, and as a result a knock-on effect to other things.
Such as not fixing a bad question causes bad content, low quality answers, snarky comments (not justified but it *does* happen). And, just for example, something like "3 strikes and cannot ask for a week" (or whatever, not really suggesting without a bigger debate)
3 bad comments and cannot comment for a day.
Etc.

I think "nice" is great, but let's not try to clean up a dropped broken jar of jam with a feather duster!

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to existing great answers:

I feel that this whole change of COC is focusing on improving new users' experience **AGAINST** existing users.

I mean I agree we need to be more welcoming and more respectful, however this should happen by improving everybody's experience. This whole story sounds like SE will change to be more welcoming for new users and a lot more strict for existing ones, and that's a very bad direction; might loose a lot of established users contributing to the site in favour of new users who might not want to contribute at all.

My substantial problem with this change that is doesn't offer help for existing users

- writing comments asking for clarifications in questions and explaining issues with them takes time, writing them polite could take even more for those who aren't very good in English
  moreover explaining close reason is kind of a useless activity from the perspective of the comment's author: just explains things again what should've been read by OP before asking the question
- down-vote: as mentioned already in other answers, already a down-vote is seem offensive by some people who just come to ask for help. And I've to agree with that, getting a couple of down-votes when you arrive to a site isn't welcoming. (honestly I'd disable down-voting on new users' questions, and just close them if appropriate. Answers are different as those can't be closed).
- close: also mentioned already that close reasons are not in a friendly tone, that should be improved too
- my suggestions: we should look for ways making pre-written comments for the cases which occur most frequently (off-topic, unclear, missing details...), which maybe automatically added with close vote / flag, or inserted manually and could be edited easily. Currently OPs see the close reason only when the question is closed, which may even take a couple of days.
- also, give positive examples for us, I can accept *“You could Google this in 5 seconds”* is a subtle put-down, but I still don't know what I should write instead of it.

Comment: Yes, answers can't be closed, but the reason for downvoting answers is usually completely different. Questions are usually downvoted as off-topic or something similarly StackExchange-specific.Answers are usually downvoted due to factual inaccuracies or low-quality link-only, which is frequently taken correctly by the author. Such problems aren't frequently as SE-specific: downvote reasons are the same on a lot of internet platforms. Question downvotes are made against people _looking_ for help, and are thus more likely to be taken with concern and disappointment.

Answer (score 11):

One major question I have is:

### How much of this is considered new policy, versus simply formalizing existing policy?

It seems like there may be some new policy here, but I'm unsure.

---

I have a few thoughts on the Reporting and Enforcement section.

> [image]

Is this a new policy? Does this mean that when a comment is removed for being rude/abusive (or simply unnecessary?) a warning is generated? As is I don't think this happens, but maybe I'm just not aware of it.

> [image]

Well that escalated quickly. This list jumps right from some annoying noise to sexual harassment and voting fraud. I'm concerned this may give the impressions that certain classes of comments between these edge cases may be considered only minor infractions live "did you Google it?".

Also, is a comment like “This is obvious, just Google it.” something we should flag as rude/abusive under this policy?

Comment: That comment has been deleted by mods hundreds of times and personally I've rated those flags helpful in the past as well.

Comment: The escalation is really weird though

Answer (score 11):

Most of this document I do not consider to be a "code of conduct".

In a comment to [Kobi's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312050/248268), a moderator (Kristina Lustig) states: "I think this is a point of clarification: the team of us working on this stuff's mission is as stated - it's a separate mission from our overall company mission. Having a specific team mission helps us scope and direct our work appropriately"

How are we to know which content the proposed, public "code of conduct" comprises, and about which we should comment, and which is "internal"?

The "code of conduct" should be short, so that people will read it through. It should be to the point. It should be stable and not subject to frequent minor changes; details belong in supplementary material (Help, FAQ) that can be updated at need.

IMO the topics "Our Expectations" and "Unacceptable Behavior" belong in a Code of Conduct.

"Reporting and Enforcement" is a border-case, and I wouldn't go into much detail. A link to general Help or FAQ that covers the information would be better.

What does *not* belong IMO is the detail of how moderators handle "misconduct". A link to an article in Help or FAQ where moderator responsibilites, etc. are described would be as far as I would go.

A problem I see with the content is that some examples are listed, but the lists aren't exhaustive, nor should they be - this isn't the place for details. Instead, a topic should link to more in-depth information. Example: the second point under "Our Expectations" says: "Follow our guidelines..." This should be a link to the guidelines, where various things are listed, in addition to the fact that other users may edit a question. The way this reads, that's the only thing people will expect. But they also need to realize they could be asked for more information, that they should include code, etc.

The logic of the wording "Unacceptable Behavior", followed by a list beginning with "No" is contradictory? No subtle put-downs is unacceptable? I propose: "Subtle put downs and unrespectful address can have a signicant negative impact on others, regardless of intent."

"Unwelcoming language" is ambiguous - who's to decide what that is? What's welcoming in one culture may not be in another. I'd much rather see "Be professional" or "address others respectfully".

Under "No discrimination" - What follows is actually further admonishment about what I'd term "unwelcoming". Better might be "Intolerant references directed at others. Refrain from remarks alluding to race, gender..."

Answer (score 11):

There are several issues with this CoC...

First of all, it isn't an instrumentation of the SE sites core mission, heck, it doesn't even link back to any meta post. There's nothing about it that makes users to collaborate and respect each others. Yeah, it covers name calling pretty well, but so also does respect, and without any of those issues that were already pointed out.

Secondly, this thing also segregates users into groups and give weapons to attack each others. You ABSOLUTELY do not want this. It's called tribalism and while it allowed us to focus our collective towards a single goal, in this case it only serves to separate all users into classes/castes and tell them how to treat the other castes. Remember, tribalism thrives on making other tribes look bad, independently of how they actually are (see this [CGP Grey](https://youtu.be/QC-cMv0e3Dc?t=4m30s) short about it or look for "human tribalism" in Google Scholar). This behavior leads to absurd results because, a) it only allows us to collaborate in specific stuff and b) such stuff is usually meaningless (see SO position on editing). This goes against your intent of "together" and is more like "us". This is dangerous if codified, and surely the end of a collaboratively site like SE.

Thirdly, most of the CoC can just be summarily deleted. Yes, it has examples, and yes, people loves examples, but only give those if they don't understand simpler and blunter words and not in the CoC. The entire thing could be summarized as "be nice to each other and don't be a dick" and it would apply to all of it, from the interactions between any level of users privileges to the humans with the system. Don't codify <s>m</s>badness (stealing straight from Shog's fingers), the CoC should be a framework and as such it should be very simple. It should be easily digested. Just leverage meta if you want to make a point or dive into a topic.

Now, this is for the ones that wrote it: remember, your opinions are not what you are. It's human to feel aggravated, but it's also possible to humans to be reasonable. Stop what you are thinking right now, it would be meaningless trying to be introspective right now. Cool off, then read this 3 times over, read what you wrote 3 times, and this post 3 times again. I took up until now to write 4 measly paragraphs and I already had read the CoC when there the Google Doc didn't have an absurd amount of animals in there. Others also did a fair amount of work trying to mince the whole thing along with all the context surrounding it. What's the worse it could happen, anyways? Writing it all again?

Answer (score 10):

Separate answer because of separate feedback / criticism:

> Address it directly. If you’re comfortable addressing the person who
>   instigated it, let them know how this behavior affects you or others.
>   You can also remind them of the Code of Conduct. If the behavior
>   escalates, disengage immediately -- staff or moderators will take
>   action.

This seems to only make sense for chat.

Let's assume a instance of this occurred in comments, and let's assume the best possible outcome for both parties involved:

> A: You didn't even google this huh?
>
> B: That wasn't very nice, I tried my best there.
>
> A: Oh, sorry about that.

Now, unless both B and A know about the ability to self delete comments, these three will stick around. They all need removing (comments not being the place for off topic chatter and all), and you've just created three clicks of work for a moderator instead of one.

In addition to this, people might lash out and/or engage in long term discussions in comments about what is and isn't nice. It is my reading of the code of conduct that it is NOT the intention of Stack Exchange to invite a platform for people to discuss the validity of each other's feelings about comments. Even the second paragraph about encouraging disengaging in my opinion does not go far enough to redress this - I would forego this bullet point entirely or limit its application to chat.

Comment: There's still an obsolete/no longer needed flag for comments.

Comment: @Helmar, Perhaps `flag` needs to be renamed to `provide feedback` or `help us improve the content`, because I could never have guessed that it is possible to mark comments as no longer necessary.

Comment: Yeah, "address it directly" is pretty much never good advice. It's explicitly inviting people who have been criticised to derail the technical conversation with a discussion of how it makes them feel. Yet that's obviously not the right thing for an offended user to do, even if the criticism was genuinely rude; future readers shouldn't have to wade through a discussion about people's feelings in the process of reading programming Q&A.

Answer (score 10):

Minor pedantry on wording:

> Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or language

This phrasing could be misunderstood by both non-native speakers of the language or those who may take words literally (as noted by @empty). The word "language" is ambiguous representing use of wording within the English language and the use of a non-English language. It could imply that it is OK to use non-English and it would be "not-nice" to remove or sanction other world languages when used.

I know that is not what you meant, but I can see it being argued about.

I notice @KorvinStarmast suggested a better rewording.

Comment: Does the Code mean "...or native language" ? If so, that's great. But it leads to a question: Some SE properties require particular languages. For example, StackOverflow requires English. How does the Code relate to that requirement? Does it need more explanation?

Answer (score 10):

When I first saw the notice of this Meta post, I immediately felt a sense of weariness and impatience. Now I've spent over an hour going over the document, the post, and about half the answers and associated comments, because I decided to soldier through it because in the end I care about this that much.

My biggest reason is I want to speak for all the people like me who decided not to look at this at all because their immediate reaction is that too much is being asked of volunteers. Much larger again is the group of people who never get invested in Stack Exchange because of that feeling, and the limitations on their behaviour imposed by the culture here.

Some answers have already eloquently expressed this aspect but I think it deserves expansion. I'm concerned SE doesn't understand how much this community has developed a personality which attracts those of like mind and repels others. This whole thread inherently has an aspect of preaching to the choir, it can't avoid it. The bulk of those who disagree won't bother putting time into this, and there are those who only come to SE for a bit and then leave because they smell an atmosphere they don't like. That includes lots of good people.

I think in particular of a person who was drummed out of SE because they said a series of really offensive things. Okay, I get it. But that person also made a lot of valuable contributions. More than that, I have a strong feeling SE was important to them because it helped them with their social problems. It helped them with their isolation. And now it's gone. That must have hurt. I know their intolerance was a burden, and it was wrong. I just wish we were in a place that could allow things like that to roll off our backs just like we allow being called to an extremely high standard when we are only human to roll off our backs. People like that need that sort of support, and we are all that person every now and then. Get rid of offensive comments, sure, warn them, ban them for a bit when they need to cool off and reflect. But be welcoming to them too. They are human too. Why are we distinguishing between some weaknesses as being deserving of understanding, and saying others aren't? At least let's be honest with ourselves about what we are doing. We are taking the easy way out.

What we need are tools. A page of rules is not the real solution to this. The problem here is that text cannot satisfy the human heart, and yet all committed users have an emotional attachment to SE to one degree or another. Maximizing the ability of Stack Exchange to accommodate the widest range of human interactions possible is the solution here.

I wish moderating duties were distributed as widely as is possible while maintaining a minimum standard of moderation quality. A casual assessment might think that is the case, but I disagree. It's where things get sensitive that the bulk of responsibility falls on only a few, and that's where the ball gets dropped, usually because it is too great a burden to ask of a volunteer. I wish it was easier to have private interactions with other users.

99% of what this place is, is thanks purely to volunteers. I wish all the stuff from Stack Exchange staff made clear how much they owe to volunteers. My God, we're awesome.

Comment: If the person you spoke of, really cared, they wouldn’t have said the offensive and intolerant things.  If people are allowed to insult people intentionally, for example acuse them of doing drugs “again”, that’s going to drive away a lot more people than that one person who is being intentionally offensive.

Comment: `...a person who was drummed out of SE because they said a series of really offensive things. ... But that person also made a lot of valuable contributions.` Allowing a person that says "really offensive" things to remain in a community just because they contributed some content that was useful is not good for the long term health of the community. Volunteer communities need a constant influx of new members and if I see that kind of toxic behavior tolerated, I don't join a community.

Comment: I'm not inclined to argue, i've already spent more time on this than my better judgement indicated. I've tried to adapt to seeing this as not a community and just use it for what i need. Just don't tell me this is about tolerance. This is about getting traffic and preventing lawsuits.

Comment: Alright, i put in an edit to expand on the part that's controversial.

Answer (score 10):

My largest concerns are already addressed several times over by other answers, but, oddly, no one seems to have recognized that **most of the "Reporting and Enforcement" section does not belong in the document at all**.  In particular, all of the enforcement details belong elsewhere, perhaps in the Terms of Service, or maybe in a for-purpose policy document.  That stuff is not about how members should conduct themselves.  Moreover, putting it in a separate document will mean that SE can change enforcement policy without modifying the CoC document.

Here's my take on how that section should be rewritten (with minor additional editorial suggestions):

### Reporting

Every person contributes to creating a kind, respectful community. If you find unacceptable behavior directed at yourself or others then you can help by

- **[Flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) the harmful content**. Depending on the content, flagging will alert moderators or trigger an automatic deletion.
- **Addressing it directly**. If you’re comfortable addressing the person who instigated it, let them know how this behavior affects you or others. You can also remind them of the Code of Conduct. If the behavior escalates, disengage immediately -- staff or moderators will take action.
- **[Contacting us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?)**. We’ll respond as quickly as we can.

[From there, straight to:]

---

We created this Code of Conduct not because we expect misconduct, but [...]

Comment: Lest it be lost, the extra editorial suggestions are mostly centered around changing "you can" to "you can help by".  This couches the recommended behaviors in a less confrontational context, and also does not lend itself to an interpretation that a person observing abuse is *obligated* to take one of the three listed actions.

Answer (score 10):

You have summoned some trouble. Your COC is defective in certain ways that will result in the COC actually implemented not equivalent to the COC stated. Unfortunately, it's also too long. If you can't get it down to one screen it won't be read.

Particular defects:

- "No discrimination" conflicts with "no subtle put-downs". There's no way you could forsee this unless you already know about the inherent problem, yet it remains. Mental illness vs subtle put-downs is going to get into a fight. I'm sorry, it's extremely difficult to explain why. The same words end up meaning different things depending on which perspective you project.
- "No harassment" is going to be its own can of worms. I've seen too many cases of flagged offensive in a debate where whether or not it was offensive depended on which side of the debate you took. Something's wrong with the wording here.

Answer (score 10):

I see a lot of answers here concerned about "No discrimination of any kind" or "No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language" and rightly so. When you start getting into the realm of policing language in the broader aspect *"of any kind"* then you start sounding like the politically correct "social justice warrior" world that has done nothing but bring cancer to politics, news and YouTube.

I understand the need to deal with actual hate speech or speech that incites violence. However, we should not be policing at the level of *"any kind"*.

Think of the way this "WILL" be abused. Anyone can come on and claim they are uncomfortable with a post or comment when it is by all rights benign or mildly sarcastic. Everything from frustration to being candid can be considered uncomfortable and will limit the interactions of the users.

It will get so bad due to the complaints of trolls or those who are offended by the drop of a hat that most users will no longer wish to comment, ask questions or even answer them in fear of being labeled as hate speech or unwelcome. You may say this won't happen, but given the history of social media, news and YouTube, history will repeat itself here at Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites. This will only serve to degrade this community and eventually make Stack Exchange too toxic to want to use.

As a final note, I will say that one cannot know the mind of the readers and to not say something out of fear of offending is not going to be constructive or worth one's time to contribute to this site that we all love.

Do provide guidelines to improve, but do not provide guidelines that restrict speech to the point of choking the communities creative speech and need to voice their opinions.

Comment: I was looking to have a conversation on this topic but no one seams to want to comment. As of the time of this comment I got 7 up votes and 2 down votes so far. That tells me that some agree and some don't. I would like to know others thoughts on this as I feel it is one of the most important section of this CoC and will have the biggest impact.

Comment: This has played out in chat and resulted in a pretty lengthy conversation about it if you want to read through it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309645/were-more-aggressively-enforcing-self-moderation-in-chat and... *"It will get so bad due to the complaints of trolls or those who are offended by the drop of a hat that most users will no longer wish to comment, ask questions or even answer them in fear of being labeled as hate speech or unwelcome."* has already occurred there.

Comment: @KevinB good to know and I will go look at it. It is in a separate Q/A and this is part of the discussion on this specific portion of the CoC proposal. So I would argue that this should be discussed in context of this CoC proposal and not part of a separate Q/A post.

Comment: Agreed, just pointing out that there was such a discussion regarding rule lawyering and it resulting in people just not participating anymore.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the info. I am reading it now. Good to know that there is already evidence of just the thing I (and others) are concerned about.

Comment: The big difference WRT comments is that losing people here will be far less visible; there's always more users to leave comments and answer questions. With chat on the other hand, it's a much smaller community that grows at a far slower rate, so the impact felt far greater even though we really only lost maybe 3 active users, the rest just stopped discussing things there.

Comment: @KevinB No I think it will be visible. There are smaller groups within Stack Exchange. Look at the Tkinter group of people who answer Tkinter questions. It is normal the same dozen people and if we start to lose them due to this then we have lost most of the active knowledgeable users on Tkinter. I would say there are sever small groups of people within specific tags and the same will happen within those spaces as well.

Answer (score 9):

**Bottom line: way too long.**

This amount of detail doesn't help.

Sure, people wrangle over what "Be Nice" means.  But as you can see from the other answers here, they're going to legalistically wrangle over every sentence in this 4 page document now.  That's not an improvement.  And it sets up the expectation that you can lawyer your way out of being disruptive on a Stack if "well it doesn't list the thing I'm doing in this long document..."

Someone go ask Joel about the KISS principle. In this case, less is more. If you can't sufficiently expand on "Be Nice" in one paragraph then don't.

This CoC is not acceptable and really only one that is much, much shorter and consumable (especially to internet attention spans) would be.

I don't disagree with any of the sentiments in it... Well actually I can't say that, because I got bored and stopped reading halfway through, but let's just say I'm not against it because of any specific thing in it, it's just a poor fit for what we need for a guiding principle.  In fact, I'm not sure we need more than the current, maybe with a blog post or meta post with a couple examples of common use cases or something.

Comment: Can you add some details about what parts you think should be removed? For example, I was under the impression that a CoC doesn't need to go into such great detail about the suspension levels for reach offence...

Answer (score 8):

I think that this is a great start and will go a long way to changing the SO culture.

I have some suggestions for improvement.

## Unacceptable Behavior

> - No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language
> - No name-calling or personal attacks
> - No discrimination of any kind
> - No harassment

In addition to the suggestion above about reversing the ranking of the above steps, I would like to suggest that for every example of unacceptable behavior there be a counter-example of acceptable behavior. In supporting neurodiversity, you also have to help those who don't already understand social cues. A lot of folks I work with are on the [autism spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism_spectrum). And I think I'm safe to say we're almost all introverts--if we weren't we'd be outside playing with the other children instead of sitting in a dark room with a bright box.

For example:

- **Don't say:**  "You could Google this in 5 seconds."
- **Do say:** "Could you help me answer by posting what you've tried so far?"

In fact, I'm actually uncomfortable with that Google example.  There are a lot of [Let Me Google That For You](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Stackoverflow%20politeness) questions on SO.  Perhaps a "lacks effort" flag we can hit?

An additional point is I would like to see some clear guidelines for moderators.  Many of my unpleasant experiences have been with moderators who work hard but need to also work on their social skills. And if you get hit by a cop who are you going to call?  Just saying "contact us directly" isn't enough.  Doing so, puts the poster at risk for retaliation.

Comment: How is your googling example better? Removing the time span barely makes it more subtle.

Comment: Also I don't get your last paragraph, the community team is the escalation level when moderators are concerned...

Comment: @Helmar the issue is with users who do absolutely no work at all on their question and expect their question to be answered.  I have seen numerous examples of cut-and-paste homework assignment being the entirety of the question when the Google answer is the top result.  I'm sorry you don't like my wording.  How would you word it?

Comment: Try Googling is still a subtle put down.

Comment: @Helmar it would be helpful to me if you could give a concrete example so that I can improve my post.  Thanks!

Comment: Add a 'In order to avoid giving you suggestions you've already tried' to the 'what have you tried so far'? That way, you give people a nudge as to why you're asking :)

Comment: I thought that the "lacks effort" flag is a downvote (based on the text in the mouse over of the down button on questions)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It is, but a downvote without a comment is almost as unwelcoming these days as the comment saying "there was no effort."

Comment: @Draco18s OK, I see the point.  FWIW, downvote without a comment is acceptable Stack behavior.  I am pretty sure that won't change.

Comment: And I don't think it should, but I see people all the time saying in comments on their own question, "Why did I get downvoted?" Comments shouldn't be *required* but at the same time comments *that are made* in addition to the downvote *are often the ones targetted as not welcoming.* And I don't want those to go away: **they are helpful feedback.**

Comment: What is unwelcoming is yet another question about ECC compatibility, that is answered by reading some document released by an OEM, and when you ask for specifics to reduce the number of documents you need to read to answer the question you are told the question isn’t “too broad”.  So after you decide the question will not be improved you downvote the question, you are accused of horrible things, and you end up feeling horrible about being unable to help someone with their problem

Comment: -1; considering that we literally have a filter to prevent asking "what have you tried?", it seems unlikely that the site is going to use it as an example of acceptable behaviour in the CoC.

Comment: @markamery such a filter seems to me rather odd, since folks get downvoted or flagged for not showing what they've tried.

Comment: "Many of my unpleasant experiences have been with moderators... And if you get hit by a cop who are you going to call? Just saying "contact us directly" isn't enough. Doing so, puts the poster at risk for retaliation": I agree with all of this 1000%

Comment: @MarkAmery `considering that we literally have a filter to prevent asking "what have you tried?"`... do we though? I see this question all the time. Almost every day. I don't think the filter is working.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Go try typing `What have you tried?` in the comment field on a question on Stack Overflow and posting it, and you'll see a big red popup boxing telling you that doing so is forbidden. I don't know the precise criteria and whether you can get around it with e.g. a longer message, like the `-1` filter, or whether it applies to answers, or whatever, but there is *some* sort of filter in place for these comments.

Comment: @MarkAmery yes the filter exist but my point is that it is a simple matter to get around that filter.

Answer (score 8):

### Re: "Chat TL;DR"

I wish there were another bullet, before "**If someone points out...**" along the lines of

> If something bothers you, speak up! Ask someone to stop what they're doing, explain your reason, ask a room owner or other experienced chatizen for help.

This, in my opinion, is one of the first places chat breaks down: people fail to *use their words*. Let's encourage them to do so. When chatizens use their words (rather than flags or just letting thing fester) it reinforces good behavior, it provides good examples to others who might be nervous about speaking up, it smokes out trollish behavior... a nice virtuous cycle.

Comment: On the other hand...[there was this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42306470#42306470). real_ate was kicked from the room for those messages and then later [kicked again](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42306624#42306624) after people called him a troll. I'll emphasise that this was the Javascript room.

Answer (score 8):

Lame attempt at virtue signaling.

Anybody can be anon on SE, so I won't even spend time on isms part.

Part about becoming safe space:
Life is not safe space. If you think somebody is gonna suffer because somebody told him to RTFM, wait until that person gets into fun practice of code review with real human sitting 2 meters from him.

Also there are bad questions, there are people who do not know basics about programming and it is impossible to give them introduction to C/Java/PHP in an answer.

In other words:
beside hurting people in the long run mentally(safe spaces do that) I fear you will turn SE sites into heaps of junk questions that nobody closed because that would be "oppressive".

If you wanted to really improve the SE experience for newcomers you could provide them with a bit more detailed feedback wrt why their question was closed.

Comment: *"Anybody can be anon on SE, so I won't even spend time on isms part."* - this doesn't seem an adequate reason to shoot down any discussion about discrimination here. A gay in Saudi Arabia can avoid punishment by keeping their sexuality secret, but it would be an odd view to therefore argue that gays in Saudi Arabia are not oppressed. Likewise, *if* it's the case that some identity group - say, women - faces discriminatory treatment on Stack Overflow, it seems an inadequate response to argue this doesn't matter because they can just hide that aspect of their identity. They shouldn't *have* to.

Comment: You are missing the point. All this sexism and oppression and you can avoid it just by changing your name to ZX40 . Ignore the ideals, let's save victims here and now.      As for discrimination: it is another words that have lost meaning. It used to mean something, now it basically means: your choices I do not like.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: "*All this sexism and oppression and you can avoid it just by changing your name to ZX40.*" Then he got your point spot on. You're saying that if someone faces discrimination, they should become anonymous to "avoid it". That's ***absurd***. "*As for discrimination: it is another words that have lost meaning.*" So, you declare that a word has "lost meaning." That doesn't mean it isn't still happening; it simply means you don't think it's happening. Why should your view be heeded over those who say that it hasn't "lost meaning", that it is happening?

Comment: @NicolBolas no it is not absurd. It is a perfectly valid solution to a problem(that btw does not exist, but it is hard to convince some people that it does not exist). So I gave you a cure to the "fan death". Just use it. As for discrimination: my view should be heeded over others because it is correct. Science is not a democracy, and neither is my answer.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: You genuinely don't see any problem with the idea of telling someone "if you don't want to be discriminated against, just be anonymous?" That's like saying that the solution to racism should be to develop a cheap salve that turns everyone into the same race. Or the solution to sexism is to turn everyone into the same gender and solve reproduction technologically. It's ridiculous. You solve the problem by *getting rid of the jerks*, not by making the jerks *right*.

Comment: Your problem is that you are not trying to solve the problem. You are trying to make everybody think like you are. So yes if THE ONLY problem of gays in Saudi Arabia was that they can not say on their passport/ID that they are gay I would told them to just pretend to be straight. There are real problems, and there are problems that you should ignore since they do not matter that much.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Using your Saudi Arabia idea, straight people would be able to say that they're straight on their passport/ID without any fear of discrimination. But gay people couldn't, because they're far more likely to face such discrimination. Therefore, they don't have a *choice* to be anonymous at all. They can either choose to face discrimination or choose to hide who they are. Whereas straight people don't need to hide themselves. And you don't see that as being fundamentally discriminatory, when one side has their choices made for them by the intolerance of others?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Everyone should have the *same freedoms*. If one group of people can feel free to express who they are without fear of prejudice or discrimination, then all groups should have that same freedom. And if they don't, then that's a problem with the community/culture, and that should be *changed*. The answer should not be "just pretend you're part of the in group even if you're not."

Comment: @NicolBolas The problem I see with your argument, is that SE is not a country, it's a help archive. 99% of the time, your race/gender/beliefs are off topic/noise, and will be erased from content. Similar to how phrases like "Thanks for your help" are stripped from questions within 5 minutes of posting. In the exceptions where your beliefs are important to the question/answer, that SE requires you to tolerate it. In the rest of the world, this would be suppression of freedom of speech. Here, it is content quality improvement. Be Nice/No Harassment cover this already, so what is left to discuss?

Comment: @Tezra: Direct discrimination doesn't happen because someone injects some aspect of themselves into the question/answer itself. It happens primarily because someone chooses not to be anonymous: having a picture of themselves as their avatar/using their real name/having information about themselves on their profile. This is perfectly valid to do (that's why we let people pick usernames, avatars, etc), and in a reasonable community would not provoke unwanted commentary about their person.

Comment: @NicolBolas But that is rude/abusive in both the original and new CoC. Since nothing in the CoC has really changed about this, what is there to talk about as it relates to the new CoC? It may be a valid talking point, but you need a point directly related to the CoC to be relevant *here*, under this question/answer.

Comment: @Tezra SE is more than just the technical sites.

Comment: @Tezra It was NoSenseEtAl's answer, not Nicol's comments, that brought up discrimination (through apophasis) as its second paragraph. I don't know whether you're right that nothing has really changed (there's some discussion in other answers about the implications of changing the word "bigotry" to "discrimination" and listing a bunch of new characteristics compared to the old Be Nice policy, and I'm ultimately unsure what the intended change in meaning is, if any), but if you are, your first beef should surely be with the answer rather than people addressing the argument that it presented.

Comment: @MarkAmery As I read it, the answer chooses not to talk about a point, and sites a very weak reason for that choice. In honesty, that line should be removed because it doesn't actually state any point (except maybe that the user has no ground to speak from on that topic) With the commentators, They raise valid points, but non that can be tied back to the CoC, or to improve the answer. Your first comment hit that point. The rest I don't think have actually contributed anything of value further. And I'll leave it at this because I think we are just doing circles now. ^^;

Comment: @Tezra To your first sentence, that's precisely the rhetorical technique of [apophasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis) at play. Besides dropping that link, I'll likewise leave it that.

Answer (score 8):

> No discrimination of any kind. This includes any language likely to offend or alienate people based on (but not limited to): race, gender, gender identity or expression, English fluency, sexual orientation, disability, mental illness, nationality, neurodiversity, physical appearance, body size, or religion.

1. *"race"* should probably be changed to ethnicity. Humans are all one race.
2. I'm unsure what the difference between *"gender"* and *"gender identity or expression"* is - doesn't *"gender identity or expression"* encompass *"gender"*? Also, *"sexual orientation"* is closely linked; put them next to each other rather than splitting them up with *"English fluency".
3. As other answers have mentioned, we have to discriminate on the grounds of *"English fluency"*. We cannot understand those who have very poor English, and thus have to treat them differently.
4. *"mental illness"* and *"neurodiversity"* seem to be closely linked. Put them next to each other.
5. "*body size"* is *"physical appearance"*. There's no need to seperate them.
6. You've missed age from the list.
7. There's no real need to split all of these up. You've given a long, non-exhaustive list with a weird order and some nonsensical groups. Just say "No discrimination" - or better, "No personal attacks". There's no reason to split a community up into 100s of individual characteristics just to keep people nice to one another.

   Discrimination will be hard to prove - what will you do to a user who never answers questions from users with Chinese usernames? Do you even have measures in place to detect this? How will this code of conduct help stop this behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps the order was deliberately random because making the connections between some of these things shows a bias.

Comment: @apaul I mean you can call bias, but it’s a fact that the ones I mentioned are linked - and not putting them together is confusing: jumping from gender to English fluency to sexual orientation is confusing; the sentence doesn’t flow.

Comment: The Chinese-characters-in-usernames is a particularly good example. This could happen if the user had some peculiar settings (perhaps a screen reader unable to deal with Chinese characters). Or the user could be on the bad side of the Great Firewall. It would register as discrimination even if it wasn't the user's fault at all - or a result of the user's own disabilities. (NOW who's discriminating...?)

Comment: `Humans are all one race` No, we are all one species. There are different races, but that does not mean some races are inferior to others. As for age, we do discriminate based on age, and are legally required to.

Comment: @forest It's not quite so simple - the term "race" has biological connotations (at least for some) and there is a scientific argument that biologically speaking humans comprise a single race (i.e. the human species cannot be meaningfully split up into any discreet groups based on genetic differences). I believe that is what Tim is referring to.

Answer (score 7):

> No discrimination of any kind. This includes any language likely to offend or alienate people based on (but not limited to): race, gender, gender identity or expression, English fluency, sexual **orientation**, disability, mental illness, nationality, neurodiversity, physical appearance, body size, or **religion**.

Please add 'political orientation' and 'religion (or lack of belief in any religion)' to this list.

Comment: Political orientation and religious orientation might actually be relevant on some SE sites though involving those subjects. So that might need to be thought about a bit more before adding.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck 'Political orientation and religious orientation might actually be relevant' - yes, it's relevant but discrimination based on it is also relevant? E.g., on a certain SE site for religion, one user said something like 'this fool [Richard] Dawkins...' in comments and my flag to edit/delete the comment was declined. If one's religion cannot be ridiculed on any of the SE sites, I thought one's lack of religion shouldn't be either. As for political orientation, I'm not sure one can use terms like wingnut, libtard, etc. Anyway, I will leave it to the community mods to decide.

Comment: I agree it's harmful to mention religion without mentioning lack of religion. There's no need to give privileges to religious people.

Answer (score 7):

## Introduction

This is yet another answer about "the mission" stated on the CoC.

My first language is Spanish, I'm from México and I posted a draft of what I'm thinking to say on this answer on [La propuesta del nuevo código de conducta empieza con un problema de congruencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3565/65)

## Tl;Dr

There is a lack on [coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(linguistics)) between the title and the first paragraphs of the CoC R7

## Explanation

The title is *The Stack Exchange Network Code of Conduct*, then the first paragraph says "Our mission is to build an inclusive community..."

The lack of coherence occurs because the title clearly states that document is a code of conduct  but the first paragraph says "our mission...". A Code of Conduct could have a purpose or an objective but not a *mission* in the sense of a value proposition. Missions are for people or organizations.

Ok, it's fine if you want to use *mission* as a synonym of objective or purpose but please don't use the first person of plural. Besides that it makes me feel uncomfortable as I already explained on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312383/289691, using "our mission..." is confusing because it was not clear who are "we" and why there are several missions. The discussions on this Q&A reinforce this idea on me.

I like the point made by Mark Amery on their [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312391/289691) by quoting Shop9's recent comment on a chat room, actually I think that I read the same idea before.

> ## The Stack Exchange Sites missions are to be reference sites for their topic. Asking and answering questions is the mean to achieve that.

I add to the above

> ### Learning is a byproduct of participation on this process either by doing this actively or passively

Regarding how to modify the CoC

- Add an introduction to describe  the what, when, where, how, who of the use of CoC

  - Maybe a backlink to this Q&A is fine during the next stage but if it will be linked somewhere else like the email that I received today form Stack Overflow, consider to include enough details to answer the following:

    - Will this be part of the site tour or will they include a link to it?
    - Will be this document part of the help center or will be include on the legal section?
    - Does the Stack Exchange Inc. team working on this has name or other way to identify them?
    - How this CoC is aligned to the Stack Exchange Network mission?
    - Is the deadline of July 11th a hard or soft deadline?
    - How will be addressed the cultural and language concerns of the users of International sites that doesn't speak English?

Regarding the first paragraph, here is a example of how it could be reworded

> The purpose of this CoC is to serve as a behavior framework that supports the efforts to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or language.

Comment: I like your rewritten first paragraph, and agree that explicitly stating the mission as being a *reference site* rather than a Q&A site suggest that one may learn via searching more effectively than by asking a duplicate question.

Answer (score 7):

The idea of a CoC is good, but your new draft is too detailed. Writing "any language likely to offend" is no more helpful than "be nice". Trying for some exhaustive list ("race, gender, blah, blah") is no more helpful than simply stating that references to personal attributes are inappropriate.

Worse, by listing all these vague-but-objectionable things, you provide ammunition for professional whiners. These clauses can and will be abused by people who want to take offense, who will attempt to weaponize your CoC against someone they dislike.

Delete needless words. Keep things simple.

Comment: +1'd. "you provide ammunition for professional whiners." Awesome forecast! this is going to happen!

Answer (score 6):

I think the word 'nice' has a different connotation these days (i.e. nice = polite and therefore when you don't agree then a lot of passive aggressive behaviour comes out), but in its original meaning I do believe that it covers all the things that the current CoC mentions.

I feel like in the past being nice (in a gentlemanly or lady-like manner) involves:

- Being **honest** - say what you believe and believe in what you say
- Being **respectful** - you don't have to agree with people but you should respect their honesty
- Being **considerate** - realizing that we all have a role to play in helping each other and the community to make this a great place for learning and sharing
- Being **positive** - try to find the good side to things and turn risks and challenges into opportunities

If that's still what being nice means, then I think nothing needs to change in the CoC. But I guess the fact that there is a perceived need to add to it means that the meaning is not the same. However, I think it is still important to retain the 'Be Nice' mantra to remind ourselves of where we were and why we need to move forward.

Comment: The irony with this is of course that _in a gentlemanly or lady-like manner_ in and of itself might be percieved as discriminatory by those with non binary gender expressions. I think the paragraph about discrimination needs a bit of work in the face of vastly differing cultural expectations and norms of the many users of the network.

Comment: @Magisch the discrimination (or perception thereof) towards those with non binary gender expressions is unintneded :p I merely wanted to illustrate the point that what we refer to as being nice in the past is probably not the same as what it means now.

Comment: I was referring to the paragraph in the CoC, not in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

0 tolerance policies are always an easy solution to complex situations ("No discrimination!" makes it clear you don't support genocides), but they almost never work well ("No discrimination!" makes it hard to justify discriminating later, for example on the basis of content quality or a history of repeated bad behavior without undermining the legitimacy of the policy).

Instead, consider "We do not tolerate hate speech, and we know it when we see it".  What you actually want to stop is people doing the evil thing that is like racism and sexism and stuff, and while that's called 'discrimination' without any qualifiers often enough it's reasonable to consider that a normal use of language, lots of other, totally fine, things are properly called 'discrimination', too, and that's a problem for a rule (c.f. "No electronic devices in the classroom").  For example, downvoting a post *is* discriminating against the position(s) expressed in it, and that's okay.  Some positions are better than others and nothing evil is done in evaluating that a post is wrong and acting upon that judgment. The bad things happen when we discriminate between *people* as if they were somehow more or less valuable because they were dark-skinned or rich or female or identify as nonbinary or have thirteen kids or Catholic or wrong or have a different rpg playstyle from us or whatever.

It's the people and the value bit that's important, though, not the deciding one things better than another.  We can't ban discriminating everywhere all the time with everything and actually mean it and be Stack Exchange cause then we can't upvote or downvote posts, or flag offensive content, or do basically anything that involves sorting or categorizing user-provided content. We can totally ban 'hate speech', though, and we should do so.  And it fixes the problem, cause no one uses 'hate speech' to mean anything other than exactly what sort of thing we want to ban.

Answer (score 6):

A few thoughts :

1) The code of conduct could be more concisely worded. Many online users "skim-read"

e.g.

> Be friendly, clear, and constructive. Editing, commenting, and sharing feedback are  healthy parts of our community. When giving feedback, avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online. Be open to receiving constructive feedback.

to

> Be polite and constructive when giving feedback. Tone can be
>   misinterpreted online, so please avoid jokes and sarcasm.  Be open to
>   constructive feedback.

2) I noted there was no hyperlink where it said "follow our guidelines" (perhaps this should link to the ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page?)

3) The fact that many new users do not take the tour or read the "how to ask" page prior to asking, makes me doubtful that new users would read a Code of conduct?

4) Overall I agree that it's good to have a code of conduct, but I too would question the mission and would expect unacceptable behaviour to be listed in reverse order (to current).

5) In my experience what one person deems as "unwelcoming" varies, so what constitutes as "offensive" in my opinion needs to be clarified by the moderators.

6) It may be more helpful to use the code of conduct to highlight **what** "makes it easy for others to help" them  (A clear explanation and *providing code* etc. ) rather than advising users not to worry and bringing to attention that other users may improve their question if needs-be. Minimising the need for edits would be positive.

Comment: +1 for point 6, which I haven't seen raised yet. If a newbie posts a bad question they cannot expect to get hand-held through improving it and ultimately walk away with their rep intact; there's a shortage of users inclined to perform such hand-holding, a good chance the question will get closed and never be reopened even if it's improved, and a good chance that even if they do get hand-held and the question stays open they'll be hammered with downvotes during the time that the question is bad. Overemphasizing improvement by the community risks setting an expectation we currently don't meet.

Comment: @MarkAmery thanks for drawing attention to this point, I do think it's important.

Answer (score 6):

A small one: "Expulsion from Stack Overflow" in the table, should probably say something along the lines of "Expulsion from the Stack Exchange in question", since with over 90 beta sites now, there are some people that don't know what Stack Overflow is! If what was meant by "Expulsion from Stack Overflow" was actually the much harsher statement of "Expulsion from the Stack Exchange Network", then it should say so.

Since this is a code of conduct, I would recommend that it is made written somewhere, perhaps even in an appendix, what exactly would allow for "Expulsion from the Stack Exchange Network" to be enforced, just like referees are given specific circumstances in which they are to issue red cards, and judges are bound to specific laws regarding what sentences they can issue. This will ensure that no one is permanently expelled in error.

Comment: I think it means expulsion from the entire network, not a specific site. The company name is *technically* "Stack Overflow" and, particularly internally, refers to the whole network, not just the site stackoverflow.com. So, adjusting it to read "The Stack Exchange Network" would be the appropriate equivalent.

Comment: That is absolutely what it should say then! "The Stack Exchange Network" !

Answer (score 6):

## A text that doesn't translate cleanly will fail

Other answers have discussed a number of potential issues with how people will understand the language of the proposed text. The code of conduct is supposed to be read by millions of users and help them behave better. Most of them, while reading the text, will mentally translate it to their own native language or locale. If a word or expression doesn't translate cleanly, this means that in practice SE will be operating under dozens or hundreds of different codes of conduct.

## Professional help to let all English speakers understand the text

Solutions for this problem exist, if you're serious about this effort and you put your money where your mouth is. Hire professional experienced translators to translate the text to your top 10, 20 or 50 target locales (including English variants!). Ask them to include comments about the expressions which translate poorly, and suggestions of alternative English expressions which would be clearer. Rewrite the original text using those expressions which maximise translatability. Just remove the concepts which cannot be translated well in a significant number of languages.

This is what OECD does for its PISA tests. Of course that's a very expensive program, but you can pick your own size. If you have an extremely limited budget, try at least 2-3 languages of different families.

## If your real audience is another, be explicit

I can also understand if you prefer to have a legalistic text which will be understood only by few persons, but will help them do what you expect. If so, be explicit and make sure that this smaller population understand the text.

If this text is meant as a guide for staffers and moderators when they decide how to moderate content and suspend users, call it a moderation guideline that they have to understand and follow. Even if you don't have resources to let all users understand it fully, you can state that you're releasing it for everyone to read for the sake of transparency.

Comment: Consider to pick the languages of International SO sites as most of them are from different language families: Russian, Japanese, Spanish/Portuguese

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**

- Encouraging us to be more welcoming is acceptable. Forcing us to do so is not.
- Being even more polite costs even more time and time is very expensive (not in a monetary sense).
- We can't please *every single new user*.
- Be careful with reducing content quality; it's SE's main reason of success.
- Political correctness is reaching scary levels.
- "Behavior and typical action" needs to be expanded.

---

## New user participation

> our goal is going to remain to include people [that simply aren't comfortable coming here]

Could you tell us what makes them uncomfortable? Since you haven't given us any data on  what new users are afraid of on SO / SE, I'll assume based on personal experience that the following are the issue (from most stressful to least):

**1. Down-votes, question being closed / deleted, being told they are wrong**
If editing and asking clarification can't save it, a bad Q is a bad Q. That's life.

Linking to respective policy in a downvoted/closed Q is the way to go. It's not perfect; many will not read it or simply feel too unwelcome by the downvotes and never return. But there is no way around that.

**2. Being told their question is easy to google**
Addressed in other answers.

**3. Snarky comments**
Should be discouraged. Simply deleting them might leave the poster unaware of his wrong doing. Contact poster explaining what's wrong.

---

## CoC feels as if it encourages us to be an overprotective parent

> No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language

So should I always be afraid of speaking in case he interprets it as a put-down?

For example, being told I'm wrong is somewhat stressful but also extremely useful, so I encourage it. However, not everyone responds the same way to such feedback. Some people can learn to love criticism, others never will. Personally, I don't have the time to educate every single user. Perhaps create a page that explains to new users that:

- *'Being wrong doesn't make you an incompetent person.'*
- *'I gave you for free my time by pointing your mistake; be thankful not defensive.'*

I'd rather spend 30 secs on a succinct comment than 4 minutes typing *"hello, thanks, would you kindly"*. If you start deleting comments that were perceived by an overly sensitive butterfly as "uncomfortable", I will not waste my precious 30 seconds again.

Now to address the inevitable strawmans from politically passionate users: Not being offensive based on religion, sex, race, etc. is great. I dislike people trying to dominate others using those as pretext. However, users that are overly sensitive to *constructive* criticism need to address their issues and forcing us to make sure they feel cozy is both time consuming to us and harmful to them.

---

CoC also mentions avoiding terms like "ignorant". I am not a native english speaker, but isn't "[ignorant](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/337225/177920)" == 'lacking special knowledge or information.' Why should it be avoided?

---

## CoC effect on recommending Stack Overflow

> Does [CoC] affect your recommending Stack Overflow as a resource in any way? How so?

Currently my comments when recommending SE are:

- Often excellent quality advice from SO and a few other SE sites.
- Strong left-wing bias on political subjects (sometimes even in STEM fields); avoid discussing politics even in designated sites.

With CoC I will add:

- Political correctness has reached the usual insane levels you see in every day life. Avoid politics at all costs.
- Emphasis has switched heavily from quality to userbase-growth (if quality indeed drops)

A while ago you were warned about the political echo-chambers that are forming all over SE. Political correctness-inspired policies are alienating non left-wing even more. Perhaps you are surrounded by left-wings and you think you aren't left-wing because you are slightly more to the right. If that is the case, I don't think you'll notice the echo-chambers in time.

---

Finally, a tricky question:

- How much havoc would CoC cause if you add "political beliefs" in **No discrimination of any kind**?
- Would you include it in CoC? If not, why not?

Comment: Re: "ignorant", there's a nuance to how the word is used that you're missing. If I say that you are *ignorant of* or *ignorant about* something, that's typically  inoffensive and just suggests you lack that particular piece of knowledge. But if I just describe you as *ignorant* without any further qualifier, it suggests that you are just generally poorly-educated and unknowledgeable;  in that context it's an insult, much like calling you stupid or uncivilised. ("Ignorant" is also, weirdly, used by some leftists to mean "bigoted", but I don't think the CoC is alluding to *that* meaning.)

Answer (score 5):

In the point about flagging

> Flag the harmful content. Depending on the content, flagging will
>   alert moderators or trigger an automatic deletion.

Could you clarify whether or not a "Rude or abusive" flag will always be appropriate for content that breaches the code of conduct? And perhaps link the code of conduct from the flag UI. Using/validating "Rude or abusive" as opposed to "No longer needed" is a slight negative mark against the user so it's worth having clear expectations on all sides about when it is appropriate.

Comment: Also, would Rude or Abusive *Red* flags be appropriate for *answers* that contain slightly condescending statements? For example, "You could have easily found this information by reading a basic C++ book, but the answer is...." The last time I checked, we were supposed to just silently edit out the inappropriate stuff.

Answer (score 5):

I think what the code of conduct is missing is a sense of collaboration. We want people to be collaborative in solving on-topic problems (with apologies to Code Golf.SE, Puzzling.SE, etc.), not antagonistic. Both questioners and answerers need to meet each other halfway. Behaviour that deviates from this should be discouraged.

The draft Code of Conduct is about the individual, where it should be about communities or teams of people, even if that's only two people. Perhaps something like the following:

> Stack Exchange works when two or more people come together to solve a specific, well-defined problem, and fails if **you or another person** are not sincere or respectful.

The Code of Conduct should focus on collaboration, and everything else is off-topic or just distracting. Certainly, offensive behaviour should be flagged and dealt with as quickly as possible.

> A user's religion, gender, race, etc. is off-topic on Stack Exchange, and has the potential to be considered offensive or abusive. Be considerate of others' feelings.

Just about the one thing we all have in common is that we all make mistakes and are fallible. We shouldn't be punished for honest mistakes, or for having a grumpy day. It happens to the best of us! There should be four levels of moderator action (not three):

1. Minor off-topic, unoffensive noise - silent content deletion (no warning issued)
2. Major, repeat off-topic, unoffensive noise; minor offensive comment - warning (and content deletion)
3. Major or repeat offensive comment - account suspension
4. Demonstrated lack of willingness to improve behaviour - account termination

What we're against is **disruptive** behaviour. If you don't disrupt the site, everything is fine. If you do disrupt the site, you may have actions taken against your account (not you personally) for minor disruptions, and you **WILL** have actions taken against your account for major disruptions.

There also needs to be a sense of common sense when the moderators are involved, and it shouldn't matter which moderator deals with an issue, there should be accord as to the proper course of action. This implies that moderators should be "reasonable" people, but even moderators have bad days.

Comment: I kind of like the idea, aesthetically, of framing Stack Overflow's process as one in which an asker and answerers *collaboratively* create a resource of use to future readers. I'm not sure whether that framing makes much difference to anything in the CoC, though. As for your four levels of moderation action, they're actually all already in the CoC; it's just that only 1, 3, and 4 appear in the examples, and only 2, 3 and 4 appear in the diagram above the examples - a weird inconsistency that others have commented on already.

Comment: Minor detail, but in the case of Sock Puppets, mods will take action against you personally (to the extent of banning all of your accounts)

Comment: For the record, users on Puzzling.SE *do* commonly collaborate to provide a high-quality answer to a question.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain What I meant is that they're not there to solve problems, but to have fun. A riddle is mentally stimulating but won't prevent you from achieving anything except solving the riddle.

Comment: I'm afraid "religion, gender, race etc" is *not* off-.topic on SE in general. Just browse [IPS.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) for example. And I guess [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) would be empty, too. I know it feels that way when you use the programming related sites, but the focus has shifted slightly.

Comment: @nvoigt Of course it's off-topic! Otherwise non-Christians wouldn't be able to use Christianity.SE, etc.

Answer (score 4):

`No subtle put-downs [...] "You could google this in 5 seconds" is a subtle put-down`

In that case could we get a flag for questions like that?

Comment: Actually I would classify that as non-subtle :)

Comment: @DavidPostill And I wouldn't classify it as a put-down. It's a friendly reminder to use one of the most basic tools before spamming a community. People here are just being weird about it.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler It's definitely not friendly. But it is sometimes necessary, particularly if a user shows a pattern of repeatedly asking tripe without any research. A friendly version will not condescendingly note that googling the problem is a very obvious and elementary thing to do. I'm quite sure that when you tell a friend to do some research, you don't emphasize the fact that they messed up by not checking things out properly first.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler It's definitely not friendly. You have to realise that not everybody has expert level google-fu. A better and more friendly comment would be something like "if you google with {this search string} you will find some helpful links that you can use to clarify your question  and/or guide you towards an answer. Remember that some people (more so in the case of non-native English speakers) may not know the right words (terminology) to search with. Teach a man to fish is perhaps the best summary I can give as to why the approach of asking for a new flag may not be the best one.

Comment: @Chair to me anything that isn't outright hostile is friendly. I guess you belong to the people that have it the other way around? Nothing wrong with that, I just find it weird.

Comment: A new flag to close isn't going to help the OP in any way.

Comment: @DavidPostil see I would consider half of that as null-speak. There is no information transferred. It makes it harder to read and skim over if it's part of a comment chain. I agree that in some cases adding appropriate search terms to the comment is helpful or necessary.

Comment: Yes it helps the OP. It's giving a fish vs. teaching to fish all over again.

Comment: The only part in the comment would be "if you google with {this search string} you will find some helpful links that you can use to clarify your question and/or guide you towards an answer." The rest was explaining *why* I think that way.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler One can always add [How To Use Google To Search](https://searchengineland.com/guide/how-to-use-google-to-search) to the comment :)

Comment: "You could find an answer using search terms x,y,z". I do concede that the 5 seconds thing in the example is null-speak as well. Sorry.

Comment: Regarding the link, I'm pretty sure that would count as a put-down as well.

Comment: What you should do is close the question as unclear.  If we assume good faith, you must be misunderstanding the question if it's solved in a 5 second Google search, since obviously using Google didn't solve the user's problem.  That means that you're unable to find the actual core issue in the question, and presumably other site members are as well, so it should be closed until the OP can clarify

Comment: @thedarkwanderer That is a horrible idea. Going under that pretense is just going to confuse the asker. Questions should only be closed as unclear when they actually do not make sense when reading them. Good faith does not assume one did research. Good faith assumes that they actually want the question answered or at least believe it will reasonable for this site. It does not mean that the user checked google. Closing as too basic or something like that would be far more applicable *and we have close reasons for that*.

Answer (score 3):

This seems very clear and reasonable, standards we all ideally will have adopted from childhood.
The CoC is a signal that SE/SO is trying to reach out to new users -- maybe there are growing pains but that is ok, and maybe even a good thing. But I am a newbie and thus perhaps somewhat biased in that direction.

> Are there any instances where you'd suggest alternate language or copy?
> Where? Why?

`"...and don't worry if others suggest changes or edit your question -"`
This is great, but it is a good opportunity to manage a new user's expectations more:

`"...and don't worry WHEN others suggest changes or edit your question"`

`"Others WILL suggest changes or edit your question."`

`"Others WILL suggest changes or polish up your question."`

The uniqueness of SO is what makes it both so charming and so difficult to maintain: there is no other site out there quite like SO, therefore new users have no frame of reference for the, ahem, experience that awaits them after they post. Yes, I know the asking page tells you how to ask a better question, but by now everyone has embraced the reality that most people just skim that page *because they are so used to skimming posting guidelines on other sites* (some like @Lundin, who [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312167/395138) that such people are rude, seem to prefer to ignore this reality and rail against it)
Such new users have absolutely no idea that 10 or 15 people are waiting to swoop in on a new post to grammatically, syntactically, and academically critique and deconstruct. So when the newbie gets back to read their answer and sees, not only NO answer, but that their question has been all marked up and edited, they are surprised/irritated because they were not AT ALL expecting it. I think if you manage those expectations a bit more, the initial shock will be greatly reduced -- first impressions are so huge.

I read the asking guidelines the first time and foolishly thought I had understood them, but it had to be experienced before I understood more deeply. Same goes for downvotes because new users DO NOT EXPECT to be downvoted. Remember, their only frame of reference is most likely *netiquette*-related likes/dislikes. (see [answer by @k0pernikus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312113/395138)  `“Do I break the guideline of being supportive by downvoting a question of a first-time poster? I don't consider it very welcoming to receive a bunch of downvotes on your first question, yet the high standards for content made the platform as successful as it is today”` – basically you WILL be downvoted, and being prepared for it will help.)

Because people don't read all docs before proceeding, seeing the CoC as another eyeball opportunity, and then giving it a tone suggesting SE/SO does not work the way most other sites work, might be worth considering. Perhaps add an eye-catching phrase like 'SE - Where Persnickety = Points!', and link it back to the guidelines.

> If you're someone who wants to contribute more often, or have felt yourself sort of stuck on the fringes, how does this document change your perception of the site, if at all?

I won't ask any more questions on SO despite this new CoC, unless maybe I am extremely desperate. But if most new users feel like me, eventually SO will only be an archive of old stuff.

I'm reminded of a case where a judge cried while reluctantly sentencing a young conscientious objector to prison because the letter of law didn't provide any alternative civilian service -- I feel a glimmer of hope that folks will start adhering not just to the letter of the law asking/answering, but more importantly the spirit. But it's only a glimmer, because the incentives for points remain with adhering strictly to the exact letter of the law (and I don't yet see any way around that, short of creating a new votes structure with "reluctant downvote," "downvote with extreme prejudice," "pity upvote," etc., but that would certainly be a slippery slope!) My overall perception of the site is that the vibe is changing from 'Younger Spock' who was too serious, towards 'Seasoned Spock' who didn't rigidly cleave to logic and was more fun.

Comment: "*the incentives for points remain with adhering strictly to the exact letter of the law*" ... huh? You don't get "points" for downvoting, voting to close, or commenting. You get points for answering questions that attract upvotes. So someone who is solely interested in "points" will *not* downvote things, *not* vote to close. They will answers everything they possibly could.

Comment: @nicolbolas I meant incentives for being the first one to edit grammar, syntax, links in questions and the general scoring structure.

Answer (score 3):

Generally I think the Code is reasonable.  However:

1. If the code is for the whole SE network, it's odd that (on p 3) it refers specifically to Stack Overflow.
2. The **No Discrimination** section might also refer to country. On Economics SE, many questions relate to particular countries, and some (in my experience invariably relating to the US) fail to specify which country.  The likely reason is that people simply do not realise that SE is an international site.  Nevertheless, not being from the US I find this somewhat alienating.

Comment: Serious question: are you going to use the Code of Conduct against people who don't add a country tag to their questions, especially when most of them omit it out of ignorance, not malice?  (For what it's worth, if we must have a list, I support adding country to the list of things we shouldn't discriminate based on, because I've seen some anti-Indian animus on Stack Overflow.  But I think your concern is better dealt with with site policy instead of bringing out the big Code gun.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom The Code includes options for Reporting and Enforcement. One is Address Directly, which would include a comment asking the OP to identify the country. I agree that in this case heavy-handed action such as deletion of a question would be inappropriate except possibly for repeated instances. I see inclusion in the Code as not just about providing a basis for enforcement, but also about making people (or at least those who read it) aware of issues that they may not have considered but are of concern to others - as the question puts it, to "set behavioural expectations and norms".

Answer (score 2):

A few things to share and suggest:

Disclosure, my perspective is that of a frequent lurker on the Java and c++ forums.

It's a good thing to try and improve the rules, so kudos for trying this, but let's also be pragmatic and "careful what we wish for."

Your original history, suggests that the initial site policy was not wrong, or initially inadequate; it observes that : 
a)  it did not scale when the community ceased to be the original group with existing relationships.
b)  the attempts to tweak it were largely overwhelmed by the effects of massive growth.

Perhaps there is (in reality) no adequate solution for larger scales, that does not impose so many restrictions that it must also destroy the primary benefits.  Just because we want there to be an answer to a question, does not mean the solution exists.  Example of such a fallacy:  What is the programs/projects % complete?  See CM*

So, rather than seek a "one size fits all scales" policy, perhaps a solution is to allow the self-formation of smaller communities, wherein the growth of real (as opposed to "'virtual")  relationships can form.  Where new seekers after knowledge, can find a path to the community that best matches their needs, level of understanding, and encourages actual relationships.

Humans, being what we are ( ignoring the politically correct euphemisms and wishful thinking for just a moment ), treat others with the level of effort, respect, and encouragement we each think the others own efforts deserve.  Our gifts, (in the form of responses to questions) are directly proportional to that implicit assessment, YMMV.

Given that trust and respect must be earned, which may take a long time, it follows that any such community will need time and opportunity to get to know one another.

Communities with civility and trust may form much more quickly, and effectively, when the qualities can be attached to a real person, someone to care about,  rather than an abstract handle, chosen on a whim.  My nom-de-plume, for instance, is ShinyPixel, a common and annoying defect in a digital display, who could love that?

Suggestion:  Encourage and enable small groups, (like the original community) with shared backgrounds and interests, and allow them to moderate in/out others that meet their criteria.  Sure, maintain some generic and over-arching levels of legality, decency, neutrality and all the many other (insert the latest zeitgeist)'ys you need.  But don't expect them to be identical in all ways, permit a diversity of each community and promote shared trust and civility.

Technically, and speaking only about my preferences, most of the answers focus too much on competing for syntax and expressions in code, rather than the underlying Idioms, an unofficial online "debug to correctness race", kicked off by each posted question.

The idioms, algorithm, and concepts the questioner generally needs to learn, to find a pragmatic solution to their problem may be omitted or unstated.  The result is a stream of random code suggestions get posted, for people who haven't done their homework, which is, IMHO, unproductive and wastes the good will of contributors.  See JB* Foreword, for a much more perspicuous definition of "customary and effective usage."

Finally, and then I will return to lurking:  may I respectfully suggest checking out Confident pluralism, by John D. Inazu, 2016.  A recent and highly readable tome that addresses the topic of  "Surviving and Thriving through Deep Difference" JI*

Best wishes to all, and thanks for the many answers, past, present, and future.

ShinyPixel.

References:

- JB*  Effective Java Third Edition. Joshua Bloch. 2018
- CM*  Extraordinary popular delusions and the Madness of crowds. 
  Charles Mackay LL.D. 1852
- JI*  Confident Pluralism. John D. Inazu. 2016

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what exactly you're suggesting with "Encourage and enable small groups". It's entirely possible to only review (or browse the site) within a single tag (or several). However, it's not beneficial for everyone to do this, since that means that low-quality content could fly under the radar.

Comment: "Just because we want there to be an answer to a question, does not mean the solution exists." Wisdom is there.

Answer (score 2):

I see this as an example of broader issues with certain styles of codes-of-conduct, so here are the issues I see with it in long-form (I am not a regular on StackOverflow though, I just follow someone prominent on Twitter who works there; adjust your "how much I care" scale suitably with that understanding)

Inspiration: [We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct)

I first note:

- Implementing policies like this will exclude some people, make others uncomfortable, and make others more comfortable
- That is true of all other policies too
- It is not possible to please everyone, or even avoid making some groups deeply uncomfortable
- Wading into this is messy

I have two large issues and one smaller issue with this proposed policy:

1. It is unnecessarily restrictive
2. It would culturally align StackOverflow with censorious elements of the far political left to the exclusion of leftists that are not aligned with that strand, centrists, and right-leaning people
3. It makes operating with integrity impossible by commanding people to apologize in certain circumstances. A commanded apology is not an apology and should never be demanded or given

#### In the first

I believe it is desirable that excluding people or behaviour from a community should be done as lightly as possible. Unnecessary guidance and rules starve a culture of natural diversity, and do so in a fashion that's usually not-upfront (it is impossible to get most people to read an EULA), waiting for people to have a bad day and get unexpected and unnecessary pushback from moderators on something (whereupon they'll leave or be booted). Sometimes people are grumbly or less-than-friendly. Unless they go hard in the other direction, they're still capable of providing good advice, even in that mood.

#### In the second

the use of "likely to offend or alienate" combined with the list of areas of difference leads to expansive coverage of concerns of liberals. Some of these easily conflict (religion with any of the rest, it being the sole broader concern), and many are not areas where there is a broad societal consensus (e.g. body size, mental illness/neurodiversity, or even gender/gender identity/gender expression) that these should be barred. Very broad interpretation leads to extensive censorship of common language, leaving only a hyperconscious "woke" kind of liberal, or others who do not mind others considering their views unacceptable, comfortable in the space. Without more clarity or limitation, inconsistent application is very likely unless there is an internal guide for moderators that goes into more detail. Even outside these social justice topics, someone asking "how do I block all access to my content on a service from people in China?", a potentially reasonable thing to do for some services if the signal-noise ratio or market focus leads that way, potentially may face sanction. Some of the communities that claim to represent particulars in these categories are themselves almost uniformly radical and are very easy to offend; importing their judgement is a bad idea.

#### In the third

it suggests if someone is said to make someone else uncomfortable, they should apologise and move on. Uncomfortable situations will and should happen often in life if people are to have diverse perspectives in lives. The usual way people deal with discomfort is to ignore it or blow off steam elsewhere. This traditional perspective allows for far more diversity than requiring speech be sanitised, allowing people to be deeply uncomfortable with each others views while coexisting. A policy aiming to squash this diversity (either in speech or in actuality) is, as I have argued in 2, flawed, but requiring apology is to ask people to express regret for who they are. This is unacceptable.

#### How to fix the proposed policy:

- Never demand an apology or offer rewards for one. No apology can be real in that circumstance, and it limits people from offering a real apology if they choose
- Don't demand people be near your notion of their best, just look to restrain the worst
- Focus primarily on reasonable interpretations of intent, looking to give people a time out (and eventually the boot) if they appear to be aiming to get a rise out of people rather than advancing discussion or some other (leave this unspecified) acceptable social end
- Keep enforcement visible - hide content (but let people get to it) or mark it as acceptable, so people can trust and verify that the moderators are not misbehaving (or too politically radical to make acceptable decisions). Do not undo this if people end up making third-party sites to analyse moderator behavior (Wikipedia has some shadow sites that review admins and have people let off steam about them; this is healthy even as much of the content on some of them is not)
- Commit to evaluative standards that lean against enforcement except in the most clear of cases
- Ensure political radicals are not mods (particularly those into Critical Theory, as they have an incredibly broad notion of oppression and no commitment to diversity in expression - these lead them into poor judgement)
- If some discussions are too destructive, ban entire topics of discussion rather than perspectives within them

There may be additional ways to encourage good behavior, such as having profile badges for being friendly, good-to-work-with, concise, and having other personality features that mark a good poster (beyond the existing rough-grained feature).

Comment: FWIW, I see no good reason that the content of that Google doc couldn't just be inlined in an answer. All the formatting you use there - titles, numbered lists, bulleted lists - is supported by Stack Exchange's markdown, and I'm not sure it'd even be the longest post on this page.

Comment: Mark: Fair, and Tezra has demonstrated this is true.

Answer (score 2):

My first language is Spanish; I'm from México. I have being participating actively on several Stack Exchange Network (SEN) sites for years, and I still found the use of "we" and "our" weird, the first person plural, when someone is talking about the SEN workings. The same happens with the CoC wording.

When I read "our mission...", "our expectations..." my first impression is that someone from a very closed group is talking and that I'm not being welcomed. I will feel more comfortable if the wordings use the third person neuter.

---

Below is an example of what I meant by *the third person neuter* could be applied.

---

<strike>Our mission</strike> **The Stack Exchange Network Code of Conduct mission** is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or language. Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know, join <strike>us</strike> **the Stack Exchange Network Community** in building a learning community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

<strike>We commit</strike> **The Stack Exchange Community, for now on the Community, is committed** to enforcing and improving <strike>the</strike> **this** Code of Conduct. It applies to everyone using the Stack Exchange network, including <strike>our team</strike> **the Stack Exchange Inc. employees**, moderators, and anyone posting <strike>to our Q&A site</strike> **to the Stack Exchange Network Q&A sites** or chat rooms.

<strike>Our expectations</strike> **The Community expectations**

- If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. Learning how to participate in <strike>our community</strike> **the Community** can be daunting, especially if someone is new. Be supportive while others are learning.

...

---

Comment: What should we use? “The Stack Exchange community...”?

Comment: There is no "neuter" in English... we can use *plural*, which is what is used in the first person version, as you note, but the only non-gender-specific for third person is plural... additionally, for standard English, using third person "their mission" or "their expectations" makes it sound like the person writing the content is not part of the group at all, for example, if someone on the outside were to be talking about SE, they'd use "they". Could you specifically rephrase things in a way that makes sense to you so that it's more clear what you're suggesting?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, "The Stack Exchange community" and maybe include "for now on the Community"

Comment: @Catija: I took the term neuter from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_person

Comment: @Catija: In the mean time that I wrote some examples for this answer, [here](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3565/65) and [here](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3566/65) there are a couple of "contribution drafts" that I made in Spanish. The first has a stronger relationship with this answer.

Comment: But "it" isn't appropriate in that situation... "Its mission" or "Its expectations" is an odd way of phrasing this. It has the same problem as "their"... it makes the writer *outside* the network. This sort of document (in English) is nearly always written in first person, using "our". For example, the Django CoC: https://www.djangoproject.com/conduct/ "Our" is pretty standard practice... now, when translating it for non-English sites, I'm guessing that this is an important consideration but, in English, I think the current phrasing is correct.

Comment: I know that my answer implies a greater effort than just making a "find and replace" :) Bear in mind that the OP said that is open to feedback on a broad sense and that this isn't a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Tim I added an example of how could be applied of what I meant by the third person neuter as an attempt to be clearer.

Comment: The Spanish language carries more weight on words than English does. I don't think this kind of change is helpful in the least. The fact that you are here speaking your mind on the matter is proof enough that you are included in the conversation. Please keep in mind that the wording is not "exclusive" in any way. They are simply referring to Stack Exchange as a whole when they use words like "we" and "our". Its actually very inclusive and to change it to something more "neutral" would make it sound robotic and less inviting.

Comment: To a native English speaker, the way the CoC is currently worded is more inclusive and more natural than your suggested changes. That said, it's worth considering if there might be a third possibility that allows native and non-native English speakers to understand the connotations a little better.

Answer (score 2):

How about

1. Be nice
2. Understand that there are people here from many different cultures. They may say something that sounds offense in your culture but isn't offense in theirs. And recognize that they aren't necessarily trying to be mean.

Or, in other words: "Try not to offend anyone, and try not to be offended".

Answer (score 1):

From the code:

> If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it.
>   Sometimes, people unconsciously say things that negatively affect others. Even if this
>   wasn’t your intent, apologize and move on.

Where is the use of the chat rooms in the code of conduct segment cited above?

Using comments to point out someone's behaviour publicly, if they have been a member for a while, and screwed up on something site related, isn't always the best way to deal with a problem.  A quiet word (or a shout, depending on the behaviour) from a moderator or more experienced user on a private basis could be more effective at getting a valid point across.

Comment: "You could Google this in 5 seconds" is an opinion, not a statement of fact. Agree that Code of Conduct should clarify use of comments vs. chat to correct bad behavior. Usually people don't bother, because it is much easier to downvote.

Comment: @dmi3kno yes I stand corrected, thanks

Comment: And see @countto10, even though you have edited your post after the comment, downvotes stick. It might be intended behavior, but I find it devastating for newcomers

Comment: @dmi3kno it might depend on the site, on PhysicsSE if you take things too personally or can't move on, you are bound to be upset eventually :)

Comment: I can't work out what this answer is about. Is it one point or two? If it's two, what part of the CoC does the second one address? If it's one, I assume that the connection is that you're saying that people should use chat rooms rather than comments to suggest that people change their behaviour, but it would still be clearer if you quoted the part of the CoC that it addresses.

Comment: @PeterTaylor thanks Peter,  I followed your advice, it's just one particular point.

Answer (score 0):

I take the warning about there being MANY answers to this already to heart .. but I feel my summary of issues is of value:
You do not need a mission statement .. the goal of stackoverflow is to provide answers to questions. Some will be from experts, others not, but you are taking advantage of the Delphi effect in the medium of the internet .. but there is no "mission”, just a service .. a very worthwhile one with a laudable motive, that of knowledge sharing .. so please keep it simpler, brilliant people

2 These guidelines are not for the well behaved .. they might possibly serve as a deterent by warning trolls they will not be tolerated, but probably not as it is unlikely that trolls will read them, and less that they will be detered. So .. guidelines are not needed by the sensible and honest contributors .. and not a deterent .. so suggest to beef up the “Be Nice” guideline to something like “Be Nice, Or Else” where the guidlines rough out the sorts of behaviour that will not be tolerated, and what will be done about it.

So .. keep it as simple as possible by not bothering to instruct the ones already behaving nicely as they make their contribution. You only need something to point to when someone tries to make a stink about having been banned .. along the lines of “You contravened that guidline so we bounced you” is all you need

Answer (score 0):

First of all, THANK YOU for using a comma before "and" in every list of three or more items. (We shall overcome the goofy rule that says to omit it!)

Second of all, this is a dynamite document, but I'm not sure if everybody will read it. (How will they find it?) Everybody should, just as everybody should read the agreements that they routinely agree to without reading at so many web sites (a personal sin).

But if they DO read it, you're coming through clearly, loud and clear. (Loudly and clearly??) In short, “act professionally with empathy” is the behavior they will realize is expected.

I recommend a few changes:

(1) If your point of using "yourself" is for emphasis, you should use "you yourself" in the second sentence under "Reporting and Enforcement". Using "yourself" in the current context is not gramatically correct.  There’s no such problem under  “Chat” where you say “whether it’s directed at you or others”, but saying “you yourself” for emphasis could be good.

(2) I like “but isn’t limited to” wherever it’s used and wonder if it needs to be added anywhere, such as under “Account suspension” before the word “harassment”.

(3) It could be better to “open  link in new tab” for the links “Flag” and “Contact us”.

(4) I really like “not because we expect misconduct”—you have definitely articulated and reinforced "the high level of respect our community expects”, but in the last sentence in that paragraph, I think a comma between “culture” and “should” could improve intent a bit. (Note: I certainly understood your point without the suggested comma.)

(5) THANK YOU for saying that “’You could Google this in 5 seconds’ is a subtle put-down.” I’m not sure it’s “subtle”, though! (I’ve never taken such as subtle, no matter its context!)

(6) Where you say “If the behavior escalates, disengage immediately -- staff or moderators will take action,” should you add “if you will flag the content”?

BTW/FWIW: This is the first I’ve heard of “sock puppet voting”. Thanks for the link and the education. I guess the intent is clear. What I certainly don’t know is just how prevalent it is at SO. Obviously more than tolerable. (I’m so naïve.)

Here is a response to "If you're someone who wants to contribute more often ... how does this document change your perception of the site, if at all?"

My personality (and experience) has made me somewhat fearful of posting questions because of the put-downs directed at them/me that, over time, I've become apprehensive about receiving. I've posted quite a few questions: a few, very good based on up-votes received; some definitely not as good. I have decided not to post quite a few, too, hoping to figure it out myself, which I usually eventually did. And if I didn't, I had tried enough things to include in the Question that I asked it anyway, with a rare put-down. (Same applies to Answers, though the put-downs are relatively rare. I post this "Answer" with similar trepidation, context notwithstanding. However, the new Code says my attitude should be along the lines of "Ask the question, bridgekeeper; I am not afraid!" where the bridgekeeper is my personality!)(Working on it.)

Continuing my response, my personality also has caused me to respond inappropriately ("angrily" or "sarcastically" would be good adjectives in this context) to a few comments and Answers in which I felt "attacked". It's clear that I gotta rein that in. (Done.)

However, I'm gonna have a hard time reining in jokes in comments and Answers. Ya *gotta* laugh sometimes. (I'm sure I can make clear the humor intended.)

Thanks for the CoC. As I've indicated, it's definitely needed. I wish the moderators good luck in enforcing it. I more wish the members good luck in following it.

Answer (score 0):

I like everything, especially the **examples**. I like the examples so much, I think there should be more of them, and I think a few examples added to the FAQ TL;DR would be helpful.

The reason why I like the examples is because they solidify aspects of the CoC that would otherwise be broadly interpreted. Calling out specific language as being not what we want here could lead some to think that anything not called out is appropriate, but I doubt that. On the other hand, specifically mentioning "you could Google that in 5 seconds" (which seems blatantly rude, even though I'm sure many would argue it's not) goes a long way in clarifying what is covered in the CoC.

Answer (score 0):

While the CoC is centered on observable behaviors it should make more emphasis on **the importance of voting** on the Stack Exchange Network model as it is explained on [Vote Early, Vote Often](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/)

Maybe saying something like

> - Be friendly by voting early and often
> - The Community shows its friendliness by voting early and often

regarding reactions to votes

> - It's fine to show that you disagree with the votes received by your own post or on posts from others but show it without using *sarcasm* and *irony* as it could be to hard to say if it was said using a friendly tone or it's an abusive behaviour.

Comment: [Here](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3566/65) is the early version in Spanish of the above.

Comment: Voting often should not be part of the CoC. You should vote when you are capable of judging the content. Good content -> vote up. Bad content -> vote down. Unable to judge? Don't vote.

Comment: @S.L.Barth The main idea is that the CoC, IMHO, should do *more emphasis on the **importance** of voting*. I think that you agree on that part. Do you?

Comment: We disagree on this one. If the CoC emphazises the importance of voting, then people can be called out for "not voting enough". But, if we cannot judge a post, we should not vote on it. I don't think people should feel coerced to vote - and that is what I believe will happen, if the importance of voting is part of the CoC.

Comment: I agree with you that we should not be coerced to vote +1/-1 but that doesn't make the voting less important actually deciding to not vote (abstain to vote or "skip" as is called on the review queues ) should be made because the importance of voting and we never should vote just because we gained that privilege .

Answer (score -2):

For the most part, the new CoC looks OK as of posting this. However, there are a few points to consider:

- While the CoC is supposed to address Stack Exchange as a whole, it refers to Stack Overflow instead of SE at a few points. Those points are generally true for the entire network, not just SO.
- Content like "Good grief, people voted this question up?" or
  "This is obvious, just Google it." aren't *subtle* put-downs, they're very clear and obvious ones. The suggested typical action is content deletion, which I also disagree with; such content is simply rude, and should be handled with account suspension. Of course, that's only my humble opinion. ;-)
- Voting isn't the only way sock puppets can be used to abuse the system. Another example is ban evasion, possibly through a VPN so that the banned account's IP address isn't visible on it (mods only). I suggest changing the text to cover all cases of using sock puppets to do something in bad faith you can't with only one account, for example:

  > Using "sock puppets" to act in bad faith or abuse the system.

Comment: Note that the sockpuppet voting item is *not* meant to be part of an exhaustive list of offenses; using sockpuppets to troll, circumvent restrictions, etc. are also problematic, but so is, uh, sexual content *not* aimed at a specific person - the disruptive behavior item at the end is kind of a catch-all.

Comment: @Shog9 And neither did I suggest that. ;) I mean changing the text to something like *Using "sock puppets" to act in bad faith or to abuse the system, in ways not possible with only one account.*

Comment: The question asked for good faith responses.  This looks like a good faith response.  How can anyone vote it down?

Comment: @Itsme2003 If they disagree, they vote it down. Simple.

Answer (score -2):

A code of conduct is an OK thing.  Making it easy for people to do the right thing is a BETTER thing.  My suggestion would be to come up with appropriately worded comments for common issues (with links to how-to-ask etc as relevant) and then put a row of buttons up above the dialog box when somebody clicks "add a comment".

```
[no homework] [no recommend] [no effort]    ...    [no blah]
[ the comment dialog box is located here                   ]
[                                                          ]
```

then when somebody clicks one of them, the nice, helpful text is copied into the dialog box.   Simple, quick, easy, and a good comment.

Comment: -1; I would always prefer to receive criticism that a real human being has actually written - even if its clumsy and rudely-expressed - than a generic autocomment. That's even leaving aside that these autocomments will inevitably get used inappropriately.

Comment: There is also the issue of just how far SE can restrain its users. The more controlled everything is, the more creativity and usability are harmed.

Comment: I would prefer that people spent their limited time and energy answer good questions, rather than clumsily reinventing ways to say "this is not a homework service".  And, you will note this is what happens with flagging.  And I will allow that maybe what we just need is more specific flagging texts to choose from.

Comment: I think there's a Stack App for that: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Comment: @jkdev That's pretty cool (for the 3 people who know about it)

Comment: Maybe the app needs to be publicized more. There are some standard canned comments in review queues, but I think those are sort of sterile and not so welcoming, and they can’t be customized.

Comment: I would say that automated comments to appear when certain close votes or flags are made would be useful, however.

Answer (score -2):

Keep it Simply Stupid and:

- Use [expandable links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122899/collapsing-expanding-link-on-click) for anything not in bold in the CoC
- Only use words on the [1000 basic English words](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_1000_basic_words).
- Be nice in the CoC yourselves. **:-)**

Comment: [1000-word simple English has been considered before, and generally rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269289/our-words-are-too-complicated-lets-make-them-simpler/).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sorry, but I don't see any rejection: 144 upvotes for using simpler language and 53 upvotes for the highest upvoted answer not to.  In my book that's **an approval to use simpler language...**

Comment: @Fabby that's 144 votes to *discuss* the idea and 53 votes on our reason for **not** doing that.  The actual margin of difference is 7 votes (~14% difference), when compared to the 46 vote answer in favor of the idea.

Answer (score -2):

...I can support this fully. I've been a (mostly) silent consumer at Stack Overflow for years, as have many of the engineers I talk with in my work. Many are put off immediately by the near-miss on the Be Nice policy.

It will take culture change, as I see from my reading here. Many think the new policy won't work, but I believe the success or failure will come from commitment. If most of the participants, the staff, and volunteers commit to an elevated standard for Be Nice, it will work. That's how communities grow.

I believe in it and I would work for it.

Comment: The far more likely outcome (in my opinion) is that people will reduce the amount of comments they make and use the niceness-agnostic tools of moderation to clean up instead. So instead of getting 5+ comments telling you why and what's wrong with your question, you might get nothing, -6 + closed and no further actionable feedback. I'm unconvinced that's going to be better then some snarky yet relevant comments.

Comment: nice comment @Magisch . maybe you should put something along those lines in your Answer, too.

Comment: It is telling that this answer, a model example of someone making an effort to provide constructive feedback in a welcoming tone, has net negative votes. Yet I agree that snarky+relevant is better than silent downvote. Maybe SO should consider two forms of reputation: competency ("does that person know what they are talking about") and community ("is that a person who I want to be in the same community as"). while that's outside of the scope of a CoC, imho without a structural change to accompany the words in the CoC, this cultural change will not happen.

Answer (score -3):

Now I will first preface this with a simple statement of that I did not read the entire code of conduct. This is more of a response to the general impression I'm gathering right now. Everyone seems to think the following.

**Banning rudeness means banning criticism and punishment and anything someone claims to be rude even if it isn't.**

That might be true, but I think the problem with that entire mentality is that Stack Exchange is not an idiot. These guidelines are not a source code to be plugged into some automated robot that is going to follow them to such precision as to allow rules lawyers. Furthermore, I think it is worth noting who actually uses these COC. Moderators, staff, and users are who are bound by these. Changing the COC only matters if the moderators actually change how they behave. Obviously they will attempt to follow these COC, but they aren't going to just ban anyone who happens to incite a report from a user or happens to inadvertently make someone feel unwelcome with a downvote.

The point of the rules about be nicer to new people and try to be welcoming is to avoid the opposite behavior where moderators and users downvote posts or have them closed simply *because* they are new. Discrimination can include which posts you answer. Of course it can, but nobody is going to punish you for refusing to post on some user's questions because of discriminatory reasons. First of all, you are free to choose to *avoid* interacting with just about any user you please on this site (except users who help moderate the site). I doubt that SE is going to make a "quota" whereby if your responses are more racially biased or gender biased that you get a ban. It would be pointless. The purpose of such rules it for people to be aware that *targeting* users with rude comments and whatnot because of race or other reasons is not allowed as well as posting broad hateful remarks about race. I know I'm being specific with "race" but this goes with any discrimination. Unless of course the context actually warrants such comments such as discussing a story on Worldbuilding involving discrimination. We shouldn't be censoring just to avoid people seeing such things. Unless it's getting above a general content age restriction that SE wants to have as an unspoken rule, we shouldn't expect them to outright censor nor should we.

Now I know I haven't really read the entire codes of conduct yet as I was mostly reading through these posts, but I mostly wanted to point out that the purpose of this COC document is to serve as a general guideline for moderators to use when deciding what should and shouldn't be allowed. I imagine the COC say this but if not then this is by far the most important thing to keep in mind here.

> Stack Exchange and the moderators at Stack Exchange ultimately reserve the right to discretion when deciding what conduct is and isn't allowed this document does not take away any of Stack Exchange's power to have the final decision on what is allowed on this site.

Basically this means that SE can ban someone for a reason not in that list and SE doesn't have to ban/punish someone for reasons in that list unless actual laws force them to remove certain content (such as someone purposefully attempting to physically harm someone by finding their address or engaging in illegal activities).

Now this isn't to say that SE might not have certain opinions on things (such as treating newer users nicer than veteran users). I just mean to say that SE definitely understands that downvotes and comments asking for clarification and whatnot aren't rude or should be  outright banned for making people uncomfortable. I think it is just worth saying that they are not idiots and we can expect that they have enough common sense to know those things are vital to the sites existence and identity. When they make these policies they are mostly referring to how users interact outside of basic question criticism bantering.Clarification for users who might misinterpret is great, but I think there are a few people here overreacting and thinking this will result in the site starting to ban people for no reason.

Comment: Maybe I'm steamrolling over nuances that you'll think are important, but it seems to me that this answer boils down to "what's actually written in the rules ultimately doesn't matter, because we can trust the enforcers of those rules to use common sense". That may even be *true* - we have a lot of thoughtful, articulate mods and staff who handle case-by-case moderation intelligently, fairly, and transparently. But if your best possible defense of a rule change is that it'll be ignored, then it seems like it's still a bad rule change, or at best a pointless waste of time.

Comment: @MarkAmery no what I mean to say is that people are taking the rules change to mean something too literal then it should or does mean. For instance people think that a rule about not talking about things that make people uncomfortable means that any random person can just declare that and end any conversation whenever they please. In practice, that will never happen. They also aren't going to ban people just for giving criticism. It would break the site.

Comment: The primary concern I've seen here is that trolls will use the rules to abuse the site, and I just don't see how that could possible occur. Ultimately if a person starts declaring C code to be offensive to them or uncomfortable to end every conversation and shut down the chats whenever they please, a mod is just going to tell them to get out because if the very basic subject material that this site discusses makes you uncomfortable or is offensive to you then you really shouldn't be on here in the first place.

Comment: But *"if a person starts declaring [things to be] uncomfortable to end every conversation and shut down the chats whenever they please, a mod is just going to tell them to get out"* sounds precisely like the rule being ignored, to me. What's the common-sense, non-insane interpretation of the rule that differs from how people would've just naturally behaved under the old Be Nice standard? If there is one, then it could do with clarifying. If there *isn't* - if the literal meaning is crazy and the *intended* meaning is to do exactly what we would've without this rule - then why have the rule?

Comment: @MarkAmery the purpose was to elaborate the notion of being nice and to give a rule that applies when good faith is intended. If a user truly is made uncomfortable by inappropriate discussion or harassment then that rule applies. If the user is simply walking into a chat, declaring they are made uncomfortable and then immediately leaving then common sense would dictate that the rule doesn't apply. Surely the rule of "don't spam" comes into effect when a person declares 5 subjects in a row that people start discussing to be uncomfortable for no reason.

Comment: The rule is to not discuss things that make people uncomfortable, not to stop discussing something simply because someone *claims* it to be uncomfortable. "Be nice." is a vague phrase. Saying, "don't discuss things that make users uncomfortable" is an elaboration of that. Taking it to the logical extreme is just being a rules lawyer and nobody in their right mind should accept deliberate rules lawyering to intentionally cause harm to a community. Of course, what I say here can always be used to revise the rules. I'm merely saying that I feel it isn't as large of a problem as some claim.

Comment: Wait, is your common-sense interpretation that any conversation that *genuinely does* make someone uncomfortable should be ended, and that the only time we should ignore the rule is if somebody is being clearly dishonest? Because that's *still* a terrible standard. For one thing, plenty of valuable conversations that matter are liable to make people uncomfortable, including this one. For another, it means that to justify carrying on a conversation you care about and think should continue after somebody else demands it be censored, you're *required* to accuse them of lying about their feelings.

Comment: @MarkAmery That is indeed my standpoint, but I would say to some extent that the rule more involves the chat system in the upper right corner of every page (where it is nigh impossible to escape an uncomfortable subject in your primary SE subsite) than it does chats like this were a user coming into the thread doesn't have as much reason to be in the thread in the first place to be claiming it excludes them be making them uncomfortable. But yeah my general opinion is that aside from chatting that *must* occur for the site to function the rule should apply when genuinely involved.

Comment: @MarkAmery "For another, it means that to justify carrying on a conversation you care about and think should continue after somebody else demands it be censored, you're required to accuse them of lying about their feelings." I'm primarily referring to absurd examples such as a user claiming that "Integration makes me uncomfortable, don't ever discuss calculus" in the *math stack exchange* chat isn't going to ever be enforced or taken seriously. If such a person truly exists then they wouldn't be in the chat to begin with. Trolls are not *that* hard to sniff out. The few that do abuse it...

Comment: ...aren't going to cause that much trouble because chances are the conversation was already on a subject that could be taken as offensive to begin with. So a troll claiming they were bothered isn't any more likely than a normal user claiming to be bothered. It's the cases where there is absolutely no way it could bother someone (such as discussing how to answer an on-topic question) that I think people are concerned about getting shut down. That wouldn't happen.

Comment: I should note that a person habitually and politely claiming that the same subject bothers them when people bring it up is probably legitimate, but a person coming along every 2 hours and saying that some 10 different subjects of conversations offend them and then immediately leaving for another 2 hours is either an indication of a systemic issue far beyond just the chat accidentally offending them (i.e. the chat is harassing them) or they're making it up. Those would be situations where a mod should clearly step in and discern whether the user is lying or not.

Comment: Some examples of topics that are genuinely likely to make some readers uncomfortable and which are relevant on either Stack Overflow or its Meta: tradeoffs between making software accessible for the disabled some other objective; data formats that include a two-option gender field; code that openly violates licenses or Terms of Service; criticizing an answer for being hard to understand due to poor English; how Stack Overflow should handle censorship laws of countries that may nationally block Stack Overflow if we don't comply; and literally any Meta discussion about the Code of Conduct.

Comment: Fair point. I hail from MSE. Pure math is pretty hard to shoehorn into making offensive. I forget how big this site is external to that at times. To that I concede. Hopefully this thread of discussion serves as good back-and-forth for the people at SE to use when balancing out their delicate wordplay.

Comment: Per the standard you articulated before, it seems like we should just never discuss any of the topics I just listed. Yet here we are discussing one, on a question where I think it's clear plenty of participants are at least "uncomfortable" (and where a handful could perhaps be described with stronger language!), so I figure that's not actually how you think things should work. And if somebody *were* to come along and complain about a conversation on one of those topics making them uncomfortable, *I* at least certainly don't think that should be grounds for shutting the conversation down.

Comment: @MarkAmery I was partially thinking I guess unconsciously that the rule should apply to people coming into a conversation in a place it is otherwise impossible to just avoid. I.e. comments on a post someone made should be courteous to them in what is uncomfortable whereas posts in a question or answer should only be shut down if it is actually off topic because the user is coming into the conversation and therefore has no right to complain. On the other hand, the official site wide chats should be open to everyone. So I was primarily taking this as a rule for the site-wide chat system.

Comment: Such as for instance https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: Eh, I'd also be opposed to a standard that required commenters to give greater deference to the feelings of the person whose post they're commenting on... because one of the most important purposes comments have is to be a means of criticising posts, and critcism is often uncomfortable but still needs doing for the good of *other* readers. Chat is the only place I can think of where the rule wouldn't be *obviously terrible*, although even there I'd still be worried about conversations other people were getting value out of being shut down by someone oversensitive.

Comment: @MarkAmery I meant to say that a person entering has no real grounds to claim it bothers them as they can simply go to a different post or a different question. The site is large enough for them to go elsewhere. The primary main chats on the other hand are essentially community grounds where everyone mingles. It's not as easy to "go elsewhere" in such a situation. But as I said before, the things required for SE to function obviously cannot be blocked. However, criticism and rude criticism are completely different. This is getting long though, and I have a feeling we are agreeing right now.

Answer (score -7):

The biggest problem is not the code itself, but rather, the lack of its fair or accessible enforcement. In my experience, while most moderators do not violate, the worst violators are moderators, who are beyond reproach for us little people and who can impose their subjective opinions with little or no oversight or recourse (or at least none that is available in a practical sense).

Just to clarify, I am using the term "moderator" to refer generally to users who have elevated privileges to do things like mark questions as dupes, close/mark as off-topic, and by "worst violators", I am referring to behavior that is mild compared to some of the CoC examples. SO seems to already do a fine job of eliminating anything really bad-- I certainly have never seen any behavior like that described in the CoC examples (well maybe a "just google it" from time to time, but not the others).

So, "worst" for me is very mild on an absolute basis, and generally falls into the category of what I would say varies between offputting, rude and/or condescending behavior.

I suppose that is a good thing-- the really egregious stuff has literally never made it into my SO experience.

On the other hand, I'm not sure what a CoC re-write accomplishes if it does not raise the bar, and I do not see this new CoC raises the bar, and in my opinion, the "bar" is currently at a pretty decent place, but if it is going to be raised, it should start with how moderators interact with plebians.

I can find numerous examples where very different standards are applied to subjectively determine whether questions are off-topic, or dupes, overly broad etc. When these things happen, *sometimes*, but *very rarely*, the moderator who made that decision offer some constructive feedback. Instead, the feedback is usually some useless canned reason-- which is all the more frustrating when the canned reason seems to be applied inconsistently depending on which moderator is reviewing a question. Trying to discuss it to the moderator, the feeling I often get back is: you're wrong, I'm right, and even if that's not the case, the lines are too blurry for anyone to overturn my choice. What I am describing is not too different from the typical SO gripes e.g. https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/. I just do not see anything in the new CoC that addresses these issues.

Here is the problem: if there is no mechanism to create an incentive for offputting behavior to change, the subtle changes in the language of the CoC that no one ever reads (I admit, being invited by SO to answer this question was the first time I read it and the prior versions) will not be sufficient to drive any change. Change must be driven by more than words on unread pages. In my view, a different enforcement mechanism is needed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be feedback on the Code of Conduct rewrite at all.

Comment: Complaints about moderators can be addressed directly to staff via the "contact us" link on the footer of every site. I imagine if actual misconduct is going on that's going to be stamped out really quickly.

Comment: Just trying to understand here, are you primarily concerned about _selective_ enforcement, as in mods making excuses for toxic behavior to be tolerated, or are you talking about mods taking part in it themselves, or both? I'm all for adding language that Stack Exchange has the responsibility for long-term detection of the _former_ (more systemic) type, but outright violations by mods are immediately actionable by reporting it to us directly (though, arguably, _both_ are, the first can be harder to document and articulate).

Comment: @Wildcard, I will update the response to clarify that I think the new policy does nothing to address the shortcomings of the existing policy, which in my experience is that for the most part, the users I have found to be most rude are the moderators. I'm not saying it's the majority of moderators, but I am saying it's the majority of the bad SO experiences I've had. And I know many who share this opinion (or at least say they do)

Comment: @Magisch: the problem is that most of the un-"welcoming" behavior I have witnessed would not be called "actual misconduct". It's not misconduct, but it does make me walk away from the computer saying "I hate SO" until eventually I make my way back to it

Comment: @TimPost: I should have been more clear and I have updated my answer try to address your valid question. I am not referring to what would be clearly "toxic" behavior such as is in the CoC examples. Rather, I'm referring to more subtle behavior of the sort described by SO itself as a problem (see link in edited answer). My point is that these CoC changes do nothing to address the condescending culture that is often perpetuated by users in elevated positions.

Comment: @user9399 So when you say "moderators" you mean users and not the diamond moderators? Because the terminology probably got lost in translation there then.

Comment: @Magisch I am referring to users with special privileges to be allowed to unilaterally do things like close / reopen / mark as dupe etc. I guess they are not the same as diamond moderators but they definitely have special privileges-- whether because of their reputation or something else, I don't know. If there is a better word than "moderators"-- and I hope there is-- please suggest and I will update.

Comment: @user9399: Only diamond moderators can open/close questions *at will*. Gold-badge holders in a tag have the power to unilaterally close/reopen a question as a duplicate (called "dupehammering"). But other than dupe-hammer powers,  regular users have no more control over content moderation than any user with 3000 rep and thus is able to vote to close/reopen.

Answer (score -8):

Account suspension criteria:

- Sexual content directed at another user, e.g. “@cass do you do that
  with your clothes on or off? ;)”
- Using “sock puppet” voting to game the reputation system

My observation has been that when people post anonymously, the inclination to engage in inappropriate behavior is likely to increase. While anonymity is important to offer, I really don't understand why would we give some anonymous account a second chance. All they need to do is create yet another anonymous account. Just remove them.

Comment: Anonymous accounts have no power to comment.  Anonymous accounts can definitely *post*, but posts that contain that kind of material are dealt with quickly enough that it doesn't matter if they are or are not anonymous.

Comment: The issue is comments like these coming from somewhat established members of the community, not drive-by users. Or drive-by users who have the association bonus so automatically 100+ rep on any site.

Comment: @Makoto: what do you mean anon accounts can't comment? I can comment and I'm anon.

Comment: @user1271772:  [Your profile does not have "anonymous" in it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/391772/user1271772).  *That's* what I mean by "anonymous".  Otherwise registered accounts can comment when they reach the right rep level.

Comment: @Makoto: but isn't OP talking about people like me that don't have their name in their profile>

Comment: @user1271772: I'm talking about people whose real name is not available.

Answer (score -8):

> they're trying to make your question helpful to as many people as possible.

This is a huge issue I'm having with the policy that I just can't get past. People come here wanting answers to *their* questions and then those questions either get changed to be more general and sometimes no longer end up being the question the original poster wanted answered. This doesn't help those people and it doesn't come across as very nice. It can seem like a very bad experience and is likely to turn away some first-time users. I understand wanting an archive of questions that might help everybody, but the asker needs to be the main focus with the benefit of the many being second. The asker's question shouldn't be changed to suit the needs of everybody, it should be edited to make the question clearer to everybody so that the community can help them with *the asker's* specific problem.

Furthermore, I think that we shouldn't close questions simply for asking "what should I do?" instead of "how do I do this to reach this result?" because not everybody knows what result they want or what the end results of something could potentially be. If they ask "what should I do", they need help figuring out what to do and how to go about it. Demanding they change their question to ask for something they can't give is pointless, frustrating and incredibly rude and is likely to lead to conflict.

My proposed edit to the section mentioned above:

> **If you're here to help others, be patient and welcoming.** Learning how to participate in our community can be daunting, especially if
>   someone is new. Be supportive while others are learning. Don't change
>   the fundamental meaning of a question when editing and put the asker
>   first.
>
> **If you're here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you.** Try to use good grammar and spelling and make what
>   you're asking clear to others. Our community is made possible by
>   volunteers. Follow our guidelines and don't worry if others suggest changes
>   or edit your question - they're trying to make your question as clear
>   as possible so the community can help *you*.

Comment: I agree with your proposed edit, and most of the first paragraph (after I split the paragraphs). However, in my opinion, the now second paragraph should be discussed in a separate question. It seems like you came from Interpersonal Skills, which has an explicit policy against "what should I do" questions. If so, I suggest reading their meta discussions as to why they implemented that policy, and if you disagree with it, start a new discussion there explaining why you think their reasoning is wrong and why they should reverse course.

Comment: By the way, fundamentally editing someone's question is an explicit reason for rejecting suggested edits. I'll admit that there isn't very much oversight to binding edits from privileged users; you should do some research and file a request on that.

Comment: ["You have it backwards, I think..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/839601)

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, questions are closed not mostly because users feel like being jerks, but because they don't believe the site can provide good answers in the state it's in. If the site can't provide good answers the way it's written, and the asker can't write it any other way, well, that's just how it's gonna have to be, isn't it?

Answer (score -10):

### Avoid hierarchies

There is a point that is not addressed in the list of behaviors. I have not much time in StackExchange, but in several answers or comments I have seen some insistence on establishing a kind of hierarchy, more than once from the same user, such as:

- I've been many years more than you in this site
- As a teacher / professor in this field... and after comes the answer or comment (the worst)

Knowing that not any kind of curriculum or experience is required to participate in the site, this type of comments are also a type of discrimination that does not contribute anything more than the satisfaction of the one who uses them to establish a false virtual hierarchy.

It goes against the base of your mission: to build an **inclusive community** where all people feel welcome and can participate, **regardless of expertise**, identity, or language.

I am sure there are more constructive alternatives that don't even condition negatively to the person who has to read them:

- A few years ago I saw a similar situation to the one you expose
- In classes we usually apply...

Comment: Ehhhh, appeal to authority and ego-stroking aren't good, but trying too hard to erase legitimate markers of actual topical expertise is no good either. Some of the best SE answers on a lot of sites are based on the kind of practical, experiential know-how that doesn't really have a tidy citation. If someone has spent twenty years programming Java and knows that you just don't *do* XYZ, forbidding them from mentioning twenty years of Java is not inclusive: it is anti-expert, in the same trap Wikipedia all too often falls into. ("We don't need experts, we can just read everything ourselves!")

Comment: I understand, I don't want to eliminate the "presentation card", but, as in everything, the problem comes when it's a vice. If someone has spent 20 years programming Java and uses that as a presentation card, it can be valid once, twice, three times, until it reaches the point that the contribution to the answer stops being valid to intensify the fake hierarchy. Even if someone has 20 years of experience in whatever, it's immediately perceived, no credentials are necessary. Maybe I participate more in a kind of more subjective areas, where experience counts a lot, but titles absolutely nothing

Comment: FWIW, anyone who begins an answer by talking about how long they've worked in a field or by identifying as a professor is likely to instantly lose credibility with me. (Well, except on the rare occasion where they're directly calling upon their personal observations over the course of their career as a basis for their answer, and those observations couldn't be demonstrated with a code example or cited from a more authoritative source. Examples of such cases are vanishingly rare on Stack Overflow, but probably exist on other sites.)

Comment: The only times I can recall someone claiming expertise like this (as a preamble to the actual content) is within long comment threads where an argument has broken out. At that point, SO's model has already failed (since we're not a discussion site), so getting rid of it won't help. But yes, if you see this sort of thing in an answer, feel free to cull it.

Comment: @MarkAmery Citing your qualifications seems more common on stacks like IPS, where there is no standard to reference but the answer-er has personal experience that directly relates to the question. In comments though, it usually is irrelevant to the point. But as a casual observer of ISP and a few other stacks, I don't have solid data to back that. =P

Comment: Setting aside whether "regardless of expertise" should be included or not, being a tenured (or not) professor is quite germane on Academia.SE, and similarly having X years of teaching experience is relevant on Math Educators.SE.  An admonition against stating one's qualifications doesn't belong in an SE-wide policy.

Answer (score -10):

I just read an answer on the question:

[Array-syntax vs pointer-syntax and code generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373516/array-syntax-vs-pointer-syntax-and-code-generation).

The answer by M.M. is upvoted 12 times but includes the following.

```
"Pretty tragic that such garbage (...) is still published in this decade."
```

And

```
"IMHO the best way to use this book is to burn (...) it or otherwise discard it."
```

A community with a "Code Of Conduct", any "Code Of Conduct" for that matter does not lower itself to calling things "garbage", instead a long list of intelligent arguments should qualify it as such.

That posts with remarks about book burning are upvoted instead of =massively= downvoted makes me quite pessimistic about any future "Code of Conduct".

My point being that the CoC should include rules to abandon such posts.

Comment: Is it unfair to call a book garbage when it is indeed garbage? The community doesn't seem to think so. Would "flat out wrong and dangerous advice" be more amenable? Why?

Comment: The use of "lower", "pessimistic", and "abandon" (and perhaps the emphasis in "any Code of Conduct" and "intelligent arguments"), all of which imply value judgements, strikes me as exactly the same rhetorical device the answer being criticized used. Namely, combining concise arguments with punchy, evocative language so that both reason and emotion are stirred up. This answer might ironically be more logically convincing if it followed its own guidelines, for all that it would undoubtedly lose considerable emotional impact.

Answer (score -10):

Good Morning,

I’m a 20-year veteran system administrator, 10-year veteran coder, 10-year team leader, and long-time user of Stack Exchange. I very much appreciate the site, and also appreciate the invitation to comment on the new Code of Conduct.

=== TL; DR ===

As much as I love and depend on Stack Exchange – **a certain amount of callousness and “annoyed eye rolling” seems to be built into the site, which then affects how users view each other**.

**There are as many tools and guidelines (designed for both users and moderators) for marking something/someone as “stupid” as there are for marking something as “appropriate”.** I realize this is an attempt to keep the site professional, but – in fact – it reduces professionality and **simply reminds people that “a certain amount of negativity is OK”**. At no corporation I’ve worked at in the last 20 years, would “negative reinforcement” be seen as an acceptable leadership policy.

I would recommend removing these inherently negative, or passive aggressive feedback loops – and focus on only positive-based feedback loops.

=== LONG STORY ===

In my initial review of the new policies, I see many good things. But it seems to be missing a strongly underlying cause of the negativity on the site – which is built into the philosophy of the site itself.

When I plan a question on stack exchange, I think long and hard on whether I want to post, and risk the inevitable negative blowback should I make a mistake, or even just a typo. There seems to be a surplus of “ego” encouraged in both moderators and users, as well as built into the very mindset of the site. This ego then becomes inherently combative, instead of supportive.

**Instead of creating a "helpful" environment, it creates one that is combative and competitive, where "noobs and stupids are not tolerated"...which has *already been demonstrated in the comments to answers in this very thread*. This is where the negativity you're trying to correct with the "Code of Conduct" actually stems**.

Please let me explain…

For example, this is seen in the reputation system. There’s two aspects …

1. “Upvoting” to gain reputation. I.e. “This was a good answer/question”. Very positive and helpful. This helps you know who’s answers you can trust.
2. “Downvoting” … even into negative points. A way to say, “That was stupid” (inherently negative). The very fact that this is allowed, ***unintentionally creates a mindset within the site that “pointing out stupidity” is valid and useful***. This influences the entire personality of the user base.

This is also seen within the rules guiding moderators.

Some common moderator tasks are:

```
-   Halting questions that may be redundant, or similar to other questions. 
-   Halting questions that may be “in the wrong forum”.
-   Halting questions that may be poorly formed.
```

You’ll notice a common thread here: “Halting”, not “Helping”.

I realize these are volunteers. And I understand a policy of needing to save server storage space and database access times (and users not getting glutted with 100 pages of answers that are all the same).

But when a moderator halts a question, versus helping correct it, it sends an unintentional message to users and moderators alike that ***“Bad questions (and stupid users) will be shut out.”***

SUGGESTIONS:

- Get rid of the downvote, or at least prevent people from being downvoted into negative space.
- There’s very little valid reason in the modern internet to just “end” a question. The storage space and database thrashing (with modern cheap storage and strong databases) simply isn’t as big an issue as it was in the early internet.
- If a question is redundant, have the moderator post a link (as they do) but leave the question open for comments, suggestions, and answers. Don’t lock users out.
- If it’s a badly phrased question, have the moderator leave it open with suggestions as to how to make it better. Or have the moderator simply edit it to be better (as they can already do). Again, don’t lock users out.
- If it’s off topic – actually move the question to the correct forum (versus killing it and making the user re-do it).  In my experience with moderating sites, this usually actually takes less moderator time.
- If a comment is pointless (like a “Thank you”) – honestly, so what? With the cost of modern storage, the space is insignificant. In my experience with sites, this does NOT cause any glut in finding pertinent comments. But it does encourage community versus ego.

***“Professional” does not mean “callous” or cold.***

Comment: 1. Why? How do we determine which questions are bad if we don’t have downvoting? 2. The questions aren’t deleted from the server. People with enough reputation can see and even undelete them. 3. The questions are left open for comments. 4. The questions are left open for comments. 5. There normally isn’t a correct forum for off-topic questions. 6. If it’s pointless, why keep it? It’s a waste of time for people to read.

Comment: Stack exchange's entire selling point and point of differentiation is the adversarial system they got going on. It's what keeps this from turning into yahoo answers (an unhelpful cesspit)

Comment: Questions don't get removed to save database space, but to save human effort. The idea is that the highest voted questions are shown first, but on the site and on search engines. At least in theory, this provides quick access to the best questions and answers. (In practice it's all a bit murkier... but it does work as far as search engines go, in my experience.)

Comment: Regarding migration - we do have options to migrate off-topic questions to other Stack Exchange sites. Problem is, we only want to migrate the good questions. We only want to migrate the questions that will be welcome on those sites. No point in moving it if it just gets scorned at its new destination. Most off-topic questions are also low quality; the few exceptions generally **do** get migrated. (TBH, I'd be in favor for a quicker migration process, but I have no idea how it should work.)

Comment: I hear al your points, and am not surprised by the down-votes. But many seem to have missed the point. The question is"How to improve the Code of Conduct". Regardless of whether the "downvotes" are useful, the absolutely contribute the aggressive and adversarial nature of the site - which the site owner's have stated in their literature about he Code of Conduct that they want to lose. Unfortunately, they need to decide which is worse. The negativity of the general site, or the value of downvoting.

Comment: @Tim, you can tell if a question is "bad" by the lack of upvotes. But more importantly, as I mentioned, why do we care how "bad" it is? As has been discovered by most sites, traffic to valuable information can be discovered entirely by "upvotes". Down votes have little impact on masking the visibility of "good" comments. Also, as I mentioned, the ready and cheap availability of storage and database processing make "cleaning out" useless comments mostly pedantic and pointless. Its not 1997 anymore ;) I think you're confusing "score keeping" with "adversarial". One is good, the other is petty.

Comment: @BurningKrome How do you tell the difference between not very popular (i.e. nobody saw it) and bad? We care how bad it is because that's how we work out what questions we want. We have to limit the bad questions because otherwise the site quality goes down. As already mentioned,  the questions (and comments) aren’t deleted from the server. People with enough reputation can see and in some cases undelete them. We clear out useless comments because they're useless!

Comment: @Magisch. I would disagree entirely. Again, I think you're confusing "adversarial" with "score keeping of value". It has been well demonstrated that traffic to value can be maintained entirely with positive feedback (upvotes). Downvotes offer no real ability to mask low value comments. I think this is now an axiom in modern web design and self-evident. A score system is valuable, but downvotes do not contribute to it. However, they absolutely contribute to the "snarky" nature of the site - which the owners wish to dissuade. It says, "Saying you suck is OK" and it bleeds into the comments.

Comment: @S.L. Barth Yes. I agree. But, again, I'm not recommending the removal of the voting system - just the downvotes. It is well shown that downvoting (versus only upvoting) offers no real additional value for separating the good from the chaff - which is why most modern sites have abandoned them. However, it does set a tone for the site. The tone of, "Saying you suck is just as valuable as saying you're awesome." And this general attitude is what's leading to your code of conduct issues. The idea that negative pressure is useful.

Comment: @S.L. Barth As for wasted time, why police that. That's a bit pedantic IMHO. When Googling, or looking at a post, the upvotes still rise the good to the top. I use, and have been the Pm, for a number of large trafficked sites. The first half dozen, highly upvoted messages are shown first and get the attention. I would be deeply surprised if the removal of the downvoting portion (and some of the permissions to be negative) affected this in any way.

Comment: Ironically, I think this question is an example of the dangers of the downvoting system. I have stated an opinion that is unpopular, and as a result my reputation on this site is dropping. Not because of my technical skills, or because I've been rude, or even been particularly stupid. But I have been unpopular. This is the biggest complaint I hear about Stack Exchange. It's very "cliquish". And it drives traffic away form the site. I will probably  regret having made this post, due to the negative blowback. Which is why I felt it important to make it.

Comment: @Tim I hear you, but disagree. I'm not suggesting getting rid of the voting system, just the downvotes. Upvotes alone will absolutely drive the quality of the site, letting the value rise and the chaff fall. But I think you really hit the nail on the head with your last sentence. "We clear out useless comments because they're useless!". Thats seems like less of a pragmatic value, but one of "You (the commenter) are irritating to me, and I feel your participation should be pushed away". As I read it, this is the very attitude the writers of the new code of conduct wish to eliminate.

Comment: @BurningKrome If you get rid of the downvotes, you don't have a voting system anymore. Imagine a school where people only got gold stars - never a punishment. It doesn't work. You yourself described them as useless. Let's not keep them.

Comment: @Tim Well, I guess thats the point we disagree on. First, yes, actually you can entirely drive good behavior with "only gold stars". Your belief there is (IMHO) simply incorrect. But. more importantly, thats the attitude that many people dislike about Stack Exchange. You are not a school, or a parent, or a teacher. It is not your purview to "punish people for being <dumb, noob, annoying, whatever bothers you>". That sounds more like personality/emotional management versus site traffic management. And this is what makes the site so unattractive and intimidating to so many users.

Comment: @BurningKrome you cannot drive good behaviour with gold stars because not everyone wants gold stars. Go ask on [parenting.se]. And it is our job to punish those who ask bad questions because it’s our site. What makes you think anyone can post anything?

Comment: @BurningKrome First, let me comfort you about one thing -  having a low reputation score here says **nothing** about your technical skills. This site is not Stack Overflow, it's the place where we exchange ideas _about_ Stack Overflow and the other SE sites. Whether we agree or not, I appreciate that you bring your point of view forward.

Comment: Regarding the part about saving time - at least to me, this is what makes Stack Overflow useful. When my web searches take me to a forum, I spend a lot of time scrolling through irrelevant posts. When my web searches take me to Stack Overflow, I can find the relevant information a lot faster. Or determine that the solution to my problem isn't there.

Comment: All valid points. And I'll agree to disagree on some of them. I guess the bottom line is; the drafters of the new Code of Conduct floated the idea of (paraphrased) "We want the site to be 'nice(r)' ". While there may be value to a system of "punishment" in addition to "gold stars" (I don't agree), I CAN say that, after almost 10+ years driving teams, one can't encourage BOTH the use of negativity while simultaneously driving "nice-ness" - successfully. A choice will need to be made regarding which is most desirable. The site does have a bit of reputation for being "the mean girls" forum site.

Comment: @S.L. Barth Well said. As far as "... a lot of time [on other forums] scrolling through irrelevant posts." I agree with you here, but I don't think the negative reinforcement helps this. The upvotes alone still drive the best answer to the page top. And while a slew of pointless comments can be irritating, the separation of answers from comments (seems) solve that issue as well. Personally, I have never really found anything useful in any of the "comments" - just the answers. Comments are for individual clarifications. Usually irrelevant to me anyway.

Answer (score -12):

I took a look at the code of conduct:

> Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or language. Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know, join us in building a learning community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

That's great.

> We commit to enforcing and improving the Code of Conduct. It applies to everyone using the Stack Exchange network, including our team, moderators, and anyone posting to our Q&A site or chat rooms.

That's great too. There's been some issues with the chat flagging system, whereby if you flag bad behaviour people don't like it.

> Our Expectations •If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming... •If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you... •Be friendly, clear, and constructive. Editing, commenting, and sharing feedback are healthy parts of our community. When giving feedback, avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online. Be open to receiving constructive feedback... •If someone points out that your behavior is making others uncomfortable, stop doing it...

Yes, I think this is really good.

> Unacceptable Behavior •No subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language... •No name-calling or personal attacks... •No discrimination of any kind...

As above.

> •No harassment. This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language...

This is excellent stuff.

> Reporting and Enforcement Every person contributes to creating a kind, respectful community. If you find unacceptable behavior directed at yourself or others, you can: 
>   •Flag the harmful content... •Address it directly... •Contact us...

Really, what's not to like?

> We take your reports seriously... This is how moderators generally handle misconduct... subtle put-down...content deletion... Sexual content...Account suspension... sock puppet... Account suspension... Repetitive disruptive behaviour... 
>   Expulsion from Stack Overflow... If you have concerns about how a moderator has handled a situation, contact us directly.

Who can possibly complain about any of this?

> We created this Code of Conduct not because we expect misconduct, but because we believe that articulating our values reinforces the high level of respect our community expects from one another. Also, having a code provides us with clear avenues to correct our culture should it stray off-course.

Good stuff.

> We welcome your feedback on this and every other aspect of what we do at Stack Overflow. Thank you for working with us to build a kind, collaborative, and respectful learning community.

Yep, that code of conduct is just great. I really like it. I mean that.

But here's the rub: do you intend to live up to it? Your past performance is not encouraging. As far as I know you haven't addressed the chatflag issue, you seem to be content for moderators to turn a blind eye to bad behaviour, or even behave badly themselves, and you dismiss patently legitimate complaints. See for example 201807020711301960. Also note that Shog has a reputation for being unpleasant. There's a gap between what you say and what you do, and I think it's something of an issue. Yes, my experience is limited, in that I only frequent a few stacks, but I look at past contributors and current contributors, and I think this issue is driving good contributors away. Unless you live up to *your* side of the bargain, I think you're going to be left with a gamester cabal who resent both expert newcomers and inexperienced newcomers. You'll also be left with a bad reputation and a company that's worth much less than it could be.

Comment: This seems less like feedback, and more like a sideways rant about your own experiences with SE.  If you want to make a point, I'd suggest making it without the additional accusations.

Comment: @fbueckert : my last paragraph concerning "your side of the bargain" is a crucial point. And please note that phrases like _"a sideways rant"_ are not in line with this code of conduct, or the previous one.

Comment: Your last paragraph is the entire problem.  The rest is just piecemeal agreeing with the CoC.  Without that, what's left would be dismissed.  There are parts I agree with, but it gets buried in among the accusations.  If you want your point to stand out, then it would behoove you to make it clearer and more concise.

Comment: I've said my piece, I like the new code of conduct, and that last point is important.

Comment: *"Shog has a reputation for being unpleasant"* - well, uh, that's news to me.

Comment: Shog9 has a reputation for telling it "like it is". I find that very refreshing.

Comment: I'm flagging this post as Rude or Abusive because it is condescending toward Shog, unnecessarily implies that SE is becoming similar to a "gamester cabal", and for overall putting down SE's authorities rather than being welcoming and open toward them. And I, for one, welcome our new overlords.

Comment: Shog has a reputation for not beating around the bush and actually telling you what he thinks. I find that to be a great quality. He's also very approachable and willing to discuss things if you don't waste his time on purpose. Also, ironically, witch hunting CMs is one of the things that was always unacceptable.

Comment: Shog9 has a reputation for not suffering fools lightly. Fools tend to be unhappy with this.

Comment: @Ian Kemp : please note that the old code of conduct is in essence _be nice_ and the new code of conduct is in essence _be nicer_. And since  you have a reputation of [15,392](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70345/ian-kemp) on stack overflow, I rest my case.

Comment: @Tim Post : IMHO the real issue is that unpleasantness comes from moderators and their high-rep friends, and then SO staff are unwilling to address it because they need their "volunteers". The comments above and the chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45507061#45507061) demonstrate this.

Comment: Shog9 is the source of a lot of the problems around here.

Comment: @User : I disagree. He hasn't always been as nice as I'd like, but he isn't "the source of a lot of the problems around here".

Comment: @JohnDuffield Unfortunately his bad attitude sets the tone that makes all this necessary.

Comment: @IanKemp: You just violated the CoC and the old "be nice policy" by namecalling. People that are unhappy with Shog9's reputation should not be namecalled "fools".

Comment: @fbueckert: You say "Your last paragraph is the entire problem", isn't that type of comment against the CoC ? For example "no subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language" ? My mother used to tell me "if you have nothing nice to say, say nothing at all"

Comment: @user1271772 If you're unable to handle critique, on Meta, no less, then what good is feedback?  Not everything should be sugarcoated, and trying lessens the impact.  If something is bad, saying something nice about it validates it.

Comment: @fbueckert: People are able able to handle critique that is done in a "nice" way, as explained in the CoC and original Be Nice policy.  Nothing has to be "sugarcoated", the message just has to be delivered politely, for example without the use of the word "fool"

Comment: @user1271772 And, you'll notice, I didn't use that word.  I offered constructive criticsm throughout.  Also, there's nothing, "not nice" about what I said.  It's factual, to the point, and offers options on how to improve.

Comment: @fbueckert  it was IanKemp who used the word fool. You seemed to use subtle put downs in my  opinion, but you did it much more carefully.

Comment: @user1271772 As always, what is and isn't a put down is dramatically different between people.  Hence why trying to police it is tilting at windmills.  If we all subscribed to your version, no comments at all would be left, because nobody would be able to say anything without it offending someone, somewhere.  I feel it's much more productive to be clear, concise, and constructive.

Comment: @fbueckert: I disagree that no comments would be left.

Comment: @fbueckert  your use of the phrase _"sideways rant"_ was definitely not nice. It wasn't factual and to the point, it was snide and insulting. On this of all questions.

Comment: @JohnDuffield When you cast aspersions in your answer, this seems awful hypocritical.  Look to yourself before you cast stones.  I believe my statement to be true, factual, and that this answer provides zero value.  Regardless, I'm tired of all this niceness policing.  I'm done engaging.

Comment: @fbueckert : "I'm done engaging" isn't very nice either. And since you have a rep of 19,478 on one stack and 5,533 on another, you've proved my point.

Answer (score -12):

First of all, please excuse me for my approximative english.

I know SO since its beginning but I almost never participate on it. At the beginning, I was just not good enough at english-speaking to ask any question. Now, I come on SO only when I think I tryed everything I could and its really my last option, but everytime I dislike being here and actually SO never helped me to find a solution : it looks like what matter in SO is following the rules of SO , helping people seems to be less important than following the rules.

In my opinion, it's insane.

If it works like that, a cheap AI could do the moderator job. Today's AI are polite and explains what they do : don't expect that from the moderators of SO, they are like cheap AI and are only able to follow basic rules without subtlety ; worst of all, they are pride to act like robots

I used to be moderator for 6-7 years on a french-speaking-forum dedicated to Adobe Flash, called Mediabox.

Like SO at the beginning, there was only one rule : be nice.

Of course, this forum never been as big as SO , but for around 5-6 years, we used to have around 50 new questions every day, all about Flash/actionscript1-2-3 , it's not bad I think (don't know how much JS question are created everyday on SO).

On this forum, moderator almost never deleted messages and when they did, they open a subject inside the moderator room in order to discuss about it with other before acting.

If, as a moderator, you don't want to spend your time with that : just don't do anything !!! Nobody forced you to delete 50 message / day , it's not because you don't like something that this thing is trully bad, you are not a kind of god who can decide what is good or bad for the whole world wide web community !!!

Do you think the "be nice" model is just to beautiful to be true ? Well, one of the moderators of our forum actually became the CEO of Adobe Flash : Thibault Imbert. Then yes, I definitly think it's possible to dig your hole while being nice and tolerant.

Did I already been frustrated when I saw a noob asking 10 noob-question every day for month ? Sure. Did I deleted his question or close the subject ? No.

Instead, we (moderators) used to give some links leading to answered questions but we maintained the question opened, and guess what ? Sometimes, an outsider came with an unexpected solution that works very well. This solution exists only because we maintained the ability for other people to answer to that particular question. They didn't knwo the problem already have a solution then they found another one, keeping question open have a great potential while closing it have zero potential. Additionnaly, keeping noob question allow other noob to answer to theses question, and then they get confident, and another time it's a win-win !

On this page : https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

we can read : 'In the longer term, I’d like us to aim for something closer to what Jon Skeet told me about his experience attending a pride parade (as a cis straight dude): “I wasn’t just tolerated; I was made to feel like the community was actually better because I was there.” '

This is exactly how it was on our french forum, really.

For example, I remember someone who used to speak french very badly. At the beginning, we moderated his messages many times but when we understood he was not french but was doing his best to communicate with us, then we helped him to speak better and we were much more tolerant. 2 years laters, he was fluent in french and became a moderator too actually, because he was good at programming. It was definitly a win-win.

This kind of story is just impossible on SO and I really don't understand why you are so pride of your rules.

You should break them since it doesn't serve anymore the common interest. That's what I think.

EDIT : Another thing, it's just my opinion but I dislike how works the reputation point. Some people already wrote about its limits and its usage. 
https://www.outofscope.com/how-i-got-20k-points-on-stack-overflow/

In our forum, there were no reputation, you had a "score" based on the amount of messages you post. It was an indicator of how familiar you are with the forum, and that's all. In order to get good reputation (I mean a real good one) , you need to really help a lot of people, then these people respected you a lot by themself.

A lot of people hate the moderators of SO , that's not what I call "good reputation"...

To be honnest, sometimes it was hard to be nice all the time.

The fact is, even if there were no reputation-point, reputation was important too and the only one way you had to have (and maintain !) a good reputation was to answer a lot of question AND to be nice.

And actually, it may sounds weird but being nice on our forum was more important than being an expert, but we "built" a lot of experts.

It's much more easy to become an expert when every people around you really wants to help you. As a user, you want to help other people because you want to be a part of it, this is how it was... And because most of users started on this forum as a beginner, they received a lot of help too and they feel like normal to help in return...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1212/discussion-on-answer-by-tom-lecoz-wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-con).

Answer (score -12):

Here are my thoughts:

**"If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming."**

I don't find the site to be either patient or welcoming.  The people who have been here the longest seem so disconnected from that concept.  One of my very first posts on this site was intended to be informative, and was treated as though it were a commercial promotion.  I was simply trying to be helpful, and I was helpful, but I was dealt with harshly.  I still continued to use information from the site, but I didn't post any more for a few years until I was in a position where I felt like I had to.  I use information from this site extensively, but I have learned how to be careful in choosing which questions to answer, so I don't get bitten much these days.  I still see a hostile attitude toward newcomers all over the place.  I've read enough on here to understand the rationalizations that are used to justify this behavior.  The smugness shown by many of the users with very high scores is a real detriment.  This is not intended to accuse all of the long-time users at all.  I have seen some people with very high scores who are generous with their time and kind with their guidance.  Overall I see a lack of kindness on this site.

**"...don't worry if others suggest changes or edit your question - they’re trying to make your question helpful to as many people as possible."**

Often that is true.  It is also often the case that people suggest these changes to demonstrate their "superior" knowledge.  This should not be the case, but it is.  As long as the description of a problem accurately conveys the elements of the problem it doesn't have to use the same buzzwords and terminology as someone who is an expert in the topic.  I realize the rationalization for these type of changes is that it makes it easier for others to find the answer, and that is true if the others are also experts in the field.  The issue is that the people who will most likely need the answer are not the experts in the field.  I'm not talking about accepting things which do not accurately describe the problem to be solved.  I'm strictly talking about edits which are done purely for terminology reasons, when the existing post accurately conveys the problem to be solved or question to be answered.

Comment: I dispute that people edit only to demonstrate their superior knowledge.  Links, please.

Comment: In your comment you claim that I say "...people edit only to demonstrate..."  I made no such claim.  There is a huge gap between saying "It is often the case that...." and saying that "people edit only to demonstrate"  My claim is that some people show good will in their edits and some do not.


This question asks "We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!"  The votes that I have received for my answer shows how poorly this site accepts constructive criticism.

Comment: When your entire criticism is predicated upon a false premise, and you refuse to show proof, it's not constructive in the least.  You can either prove it and provide evidence as requested, or don't, and accept that people think you're wrong.

Answer (score -14):

Here's another example you might like to add of "being nice": Don't use jargon words like "burninate" and "sock puppet" that might mean something to experienced users of the site but mean nothing to newcomers, and just make them feel excluded from the club.

Comment: Wow, a downvote with no explanation within 2 seconds! That's definitely someone who doesn't want to be nice!

Comment: I downvoted because I disagree.

Comment: Ideally, we can reduce usage of terms with no context *or* make it clearer as to what they mean, but jargon certainly has a place here - and, honestly, those terms are either well-known on the Internet ([sockpuppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet))) or described in detail on Meta ([burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/274942)).

Comment: If the new CoC will have "Do not downvote without leaving a reason", I'm out of Stack Exchange for good, and most likely most other users as well. SE will be really nice, and empty, place.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Same here. But I think OP's point is that the downvote was in 2 seconds. Not uncommon on SE meta sites, but it does suggest (not prove, suggest) that the downvoter barely read the answer before voting.

Comment: Every community has its jargon. Jargon comes into existence because it is needed . Ban the jargon terms, and new terms will take their place.

Comment: I don't think the use of such words is the problem, how we respond when users are confused by those words is what matters. Not *go google for our dictionary* but *It is a common term around here and is used for ..... find more of these common words in our glossary* or a similar worded sentence.

Comment: @S.L.Barth this answer is short enough to be read in 2 seconds. Longer answers are usually just skipped, hence draw much less votes. (up or down)

Comment: Wow, actually someone who shares the sentiment that such kinds of trend words give off a significant in-crowd vibe. Though, I'd agree that this doesn't have anything to do in the CoC. Neither is there much that can be done against such terms substantiating inside a closed community.

Comment: Can anyone imagine anything less welcoming than issuing a question "we'd like your feedback" and then throwing mud at someone who responds by providing it?

Comment: @MichaelKay: Yes. How about banning someone who responds by providing it? More to the point, Meta is about figuring out which arguments and positions are considered best by the community, so downvotes are issued quite freely on posts that folks disagree with (often, but not always, along with commenting with criticisms or upvoting such comments). Never mind the fact that SE-the-company asked the question while SE-the-community is doing almost all of the voting on answers.

Answer (score -19):

It's great you want to be more inclusive and more nice, because, as a relative newbie (who uses this site almost daily for only... 2 years?) hands down it is a very unwelcoming website. And actually, from my perspective, the main problem are the "veterans" with their unhelpful attitude. I sometimes wonder how someone with so much points got them by being so unhelpful... and was the user like that when he just started, or did the user just forgot how it is.

And reading the "answers" here just proves it even more - as these veterans complain that they don't want to be more nice and inclusive.

If anything, IMO, this site suffers from over moderation, and trigger happiness on that vote close flags.

Keep in mind that the world can very much exist without stack overflow. There's not one answer in SO that can't be found with enough research in blogs/books/etc. If you expect a newbie to go over all the website and see what already exists, and what isn't (which sometimes can be - "oh, it was answered on the 13th line in the 3rd answer from the end, and was later developed in the 4th comment") - then you might as well expect the user not to use your site at all.

As agentv mentioned, I too know quite a few (talented and experienced) programmers who are silent readers. In essence, they treat this website just as any other info source on the web, and would not dare asking a question.

I definitely think you/we should try to change that.

Comment: One could argue that the best way to change the culture of an all-volunteer community is to participate and be the role model for others. *Show* these veterans, how much better the site could be, by walking in their shoes and be even better doing so. *Be* that change. Contributing yourself and setting a good example how to do that is more powerful than just criticizing those that already contribute.

Comment: "just" criticizing? Being a human being is much more powerful than just being a contributor in an online community of developers.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. We are all human beings (at least I'd assume so).

Comment: You see SE websites as very unwelcoming because I bet you didn't read the rules how to ask questions in each community and how to answer. Then you wonder that everybody is complaining because you're inventing your own rules and blaming others for not following them.

Comment: No.  [**The mission is to build a library of detailed answers.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312206/307622)  The mission is NOT to build an inclusive community.  An inclusive community is a good thing only to the degree that it contributes to the actual mission of the site.  (I'm not saying we shouldn't be inclusive.  I'm saying *that's not the mission.*)

Comment: I'm surprised you've had so many downvotes for this answer, David. I'm also surprised that some people are being unpleasant on this webpage, and employing their usual weaponized downvoting. But I guess they don't appreciate the irony. +1

Comment: @JohnDuffield thanks. I didn't expect otherwise, but I thought it's important to vocalize what probably a lot of people feel and are afraid to express. Luckily I couldn't care less.

Comment: @Wildcard per the new CoC, the mission is now "to build an inclusive community"

Comment: @user9399 Actually, [that's that specific team's mission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct/312049#comment1020633_312050), not SE's.  That really does need to be clarified, yeah.

Comment: @nvoigt "be the change". The point is that people are being put off by certain behavior and no longer see the point of investing (wasting) their time in the site. I've seen perfectly recoverable and useful questions being closed in matter of hours, without any effort to fix them and in one case with false motives (reason given to close the answer not corresponding to truth, and that prevented further editing). When this is not only allowed but also defended by other high rank users, there is no point in wasting any more time in trying to change the system.

Comment: @SredniVashtar assuming you were right... in what way would you expect this code of conduct to change any of what you experienced?

Comment: @nvoigt I don't think that is fixable by the (current) Coc. I am just pointing out a problem; what others have called elitism (I would call that 'broomstickism') might be caused by the ranking system (I am saying this because I've seen similar dynamics on the Usenet - last century - but they did not fully develop because the 'top posters' had no real 'power' there. Here, instead, it appears that having high rep and being a long-term  user entitles them and a small circle of their peers to own the group, to the point that it is possible to close a question with "whatever" reason, just because.

Comment: Some ideas: if you want this site to host high quality questions and answers you should give enough time for the other users to fix things. This is not a chat, and the fact that you (impersonal you) were not able to see how to fix it, and how this could turn into an interesting question+answer does not mean that the rest of the world is like you.  Moreover: reasons to close a question must be true. If you close a question saying "it is not clear what you are asking" when the question is clearly stated, you are preventing further editing. So, add reasons like "Screw this, I don't like it"...

Comment: ...to make it clear. The rules must be clear and the same for everyone. Being able to invent your rules because you have high rep undermines IMHO the 'democratic' (as in voting) aspect of this site. Seeing that I can spend hours to craft a thoughtful answer only to see a question closed and possibly deleted before even having the time to fix it is enough for me to renounce investing any more time here. I will content myself with leeching, thank you. (There are other things but time, you know...)

Answer (score -37):

#### How will the new Code of Conduct treat insensitive language/microaggressions?

On programming sites I often come across ableist terms or words, used in a derogatory sense (**TW** ), such as "blind", "stupid", "dumb", "autistic", "retarded", and "insane". While they're rarely directed at other users, they may be triggering for disabled and neuroatypical users of the site. Lookist terms like "ugly" are also in common use.

If my reading of the CoC draft is correct, they tick a few boxes:

- Subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language
- Language likely to offend or alienate people based on disability, mental illness, neurodiversity, or physical appearance

Occasionally, I've seen users sexualize things they like by calling them "sexy". Will that be allowed by the CoC? In general, how will we (the community) be expected to handle posts/comments containing all those words?

#### Will the new Code of Conduct apply to code snippets?

Sometimes even code posted on the Stack Exchange network contain offensive or insensitive language. In a way, this topic [has been discussed before on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255188/2301450), but a new/clearer stance will be needed, I think.

As an example, just two weeks ago someone asked for help with their code that printed something depending on the value of the BMI, including

- "you are underweight"
- "you are clinically fat"
- "you are obese, exerise more and eat less"

These (*especially* the harsher last one) go very much against the size acceptance movement and may even be damaging, but back then my flag calling out "fat shaming and anti-fat bias in code" was declined.

Furthermore, even in 2018, I very often see questions about code, supporting just two gender options.

I get that these topics are polarising, but there's no doubt these code snippets are *at least* off-putting and stressful for many marginalized readers, and will most likely be in violation of the *new* CoC, as containing "subtle put-downs or unwelcoming language", and "any language likely to offend or alienate people based on physical appearance or body size" (first example) and "gender identity or expression" (second example).

It gets more complicated with problematic but universally recognized software engineering terms like "sanity check" (ableism) or "master/slave" (may carry racially charged meanings to readers), both of which are likely to alienate some. It's harder to edit someone else's code without changing its meaning, so...

What are our options?

Comment: I've found the concept of "microagressions" to be within the eye of the beholder. "Triggering" tends to be worse, with many people defining it as "I get offended easily". There's no middle-ground for enforcement, either. They have offended me so we must punish them! That's a poor model for serious conversation. If someone is offended the proper course of action is to *express that offense to the speaker*, not mod flags. As with my kids, if the behavior continues, we can consider that harassment (and the policy covers that), but let's not create language police with chips on their shoulder.

Comment: "Furthermore, even in 2018, I very often see questions about code, supporting just two gender options." Keep in mind that you can't win on this one: there are quite a lot of people whose historical, sincerely-held religious beliefs would be offended by *changing* this thing that you were offended by to almost any other option. So, since both "option button: M/F" and "37-entry dropdown" are going to offend *some* groups, we're going to have to either grow up and accept both possibilities without complaint, or get used to constant complaints back and forth, or make sure SE eliminates one side.

Comment: For the question with the BMI counter, what stopped you from editing it to not include those terms? If it's a simple question based on the output of a number, you'd be able to edit that out without ripping out any context. Why flag?

Comment: Further, most of the stuff you mentioned is a two way street. Other people might be sincerely offended by the inclusion of such tone policing or expanded descriptions. The master/slave thing I just dont get personally but if you can edit it without destroying context in a question, nothing is stopping you.

Comment: I encountered a Q not long ago where the OP was designing an application form. It requested gender information, which is quite standard, and someone complained in comments about it being discriminatory. From the name the OP is *not* part of the Western culture and did *not* understand the comment. And if he had he probably would have been very offended. IMO carrying this type of policy to real-world code snippets simply goes *too far*.

Comment: *'my flag calling out "fat shaming and anti-fat bias in code" was declined.'* - rightfully so. If one is clinically obese they should see a doctor and not tumblr, even if they might prefer to be told that it's OK to be obese instead of going on a diet to help you get back to a more healthy lifestyle.

Comment: I fail to understand how "master/slave" is rooted in racism. Many civilizations enslaved people of the same ethnic background as them.
I agree with the other commenters that microagressions are within the eye of the beholder, and you can't expect a website to thrive if you police speech this harshly.