# In relation to your New Code of Conduct meta post

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

In relation to your post on your New Code of Conduct...

[We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct?cb=1&newreg=9502ec78ad644adbba355d4ce66c77d2)

...I just experienced five immediate downvotes on my initial post today by moderators without any chance to correct, update or do anything at all about it before - probably those five - downvoted my reputation for no reason at all!

[How to console output only one dimension in a 2D array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411514/how-to-console-output-only-one-dimension-in-a-2d-array-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment89795518_51411514)

I am sick of this type of behavior. When will someone who is on top of the food chain in SO finally rein these moderators in and give them a warning for these actions? It's just impertinent, having to put up with this time after time after time.

If you really are serious about your New Code of Conduct, then change the attitude of hostility of these people, which they show without hesitation, thought nor restraint in a consistent and constant manner towards people, who just come to SO with the intent to ask questions which generate knowledge as to benefit all.

THIS is what is wrong with SO. Nothing else!

Comment: A common misconception is that downvotes = hostility. When in reality, downvotes = bad question/answer or low quality and in need of improvement. A downvote is like getting an answer wrong on a test. The teacher then circles the answer and deducts points from your grade. It's really nothing more than that. If you find that you get downvoted a lot, that's an indication that you should start improving them. If you start failing test after test in school, it's an indication that you should try to improve.

Comment: "downvoted for no reason at all" - You cannot be sure about that. It might be better to ask how the question can be improved.

Comment: By moderators?  How do you know who voted?

Comment: There were five people who voted to put the question on hold. They were not moderators but had the close vote privilege. And they may well not have downvoted at all.

Comment: @Mysticial Interesting assumption that down-voter is always more right than the actual question writer.Think about that. Yes, I've read some terrible questions but original question was not that bad. Consider how easy it is to downvote something in relation to actually writing a question. Consider how there are more trolls on Internet than people who purposely write bad questions & you would have to come to the conclusion that it does not make any sense that a downvote _most often_ means it's a bad question.The only way that could be true is if SE were 100% benevolent and free of bias.

Comment: @raddevus: "*Interesting assumption that down-voter is always more right than the actual question writer.*" Well, 9 times out of 10, they are. And the more downvotes that get attracted, the more likely it is that they are right. "*Consider how easy it is to downvote something in relation to actually writing a question.*" The primary reason questions receive downvotes is because the asker didn't put in much actual effort. Consider the OP's question; he basically asked how to write a single for loop rather than a nested one.

Comment: @NicolBolas Where's the data for your belief? You'll probably think I am being rude but I'm really attempting to discuss this. How could what you say even be measured? There is a band-wagon effect that can (and often does) occur also. I experienced it today to the extreme.  Check out some of my questions that are extremely thought out and worded specifically and then check out the question that got deleted even though I explained what I was attempting to ask and still they decided to delete the question completely for biased reasons and logic based upon "i am right, because I am right."

Comment: You need to appreciate that nobody's obliged to help you with that problem. People do it as a volunteering activity. The question you asked seems extremely elementary considering your knowledge of 2D arrays, so it's only reasonable that they found your question strange. Remember that they have answered questions well to gain that reputation and prove their awareness of SO and SE, while you have not. That's not saying that you aren't aware, but it's important proof that they probably know what they're doing. Don't get annoyed with them, they're not obliged to help. And be nice, or they won't.

Comment: Writing a question can be quite easy - copy/paste some code, compose a title and add a sentence of explanation and question.  To analyse a question and decide to vote on it is not trivial, and understanding some questions can take a considerable effort.  Your C# question shows code for two loops to index both dimensions of a 2D array.  It's not unresonable to expect a programmer to realize that one row/column can be iterated by eliminating one loop and keeping the index for that dimension constant.

Comment: I mean, if you understand 2D indexing, it's, well, you are asking for a simpler operation.   It's like 'I can plough a whole field just fine, but how can I dig just one furrow 50 metres in?' - you just drive the plough down the field once, staying always 50 metres from the hedge.

Comment: 'I am sick of this type of behavior' oh, believe me, so am I.  This continual slamming of SO curators in this manner is disgraceful.  It's grossly insulting to accuse user-moderators of consistent and constant unrestrained hostility on the grounds that you posted a question that other users decided was not useful/researched:(

Comment: @raddevus: "*Where's the data for your belief?*" 9 times out of 10, people who use the phrase "9 times out of 10" are merely using a phrase that means "the vast majority of the time" rather than using hard numbers. My "data" for this is merely my years spent on this site. "*There is a band-wagon effect that can (and often does) occur also.*" Where's your data for that? Nobody ever thinks they've asked a bad question, so you cannot reasonably evaluate your own questions. Where are you seeing people voting purely due to a bandwagon, rather than because the question merits the voting?

Comment: @NicolBolas SO should issue free mirrors to new accounts so that they can assign blame for downvotes etc. where it usually belongs:(

Comment: @NicolBolas Just as an FYI, my data came from the list of cognitive biases (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases) specifically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwagon_effect. Also, you mentioned 9/10 and I was attempting to explain the 1/10.  There are over 17 million questions on SE and a large number added each day so it makes sense to me that about 1/10 is good but improperly downvoted.  At those rates, 1/10 is a large number though.

Comment: @raddevus in that case, you should have no trouble in linking, say, 10 of the 1.7 million improperly-downvoted questions....

Comment: @raddevus Considering I see no recent downvotes on your account on SO...I'm having trouble seeing your issue.  You ask for data, but provide none of your own.  Where's your data that trolls abound on SO?  Hint: pointing at downvotes isn't evidence, because it's not trolling.  It's engaging in quality curation.

Comment: @raddevus: Saying that bandwagons exist is different from saying that you've been the victim of one.

Comment: I can see that my initial point, written in my original post, has been over and over proven correct in the majority of comments on the very same. The prevailing attitude that can be read from those comments is overly what - is - wrong - with stackoverfow. It's full of navel-gazing divas and princesses that think everyone is there for them, not the other way around. 'And be nice, or they won't'??? If I am helping someone voluntarily, I do so or I don't. Don't want to help? Think it's cumbersome? Leave! Don't complain. All of you have started somewhere and I think that those comments just...

Comment: ...illustrate the juvenile behavior of some people who are socially inept and dysfunctional. Now this is not new amongst the programming community, where you can find all sorts of diagnoses, ranging from ADHD, Autism and to Aspbergers and Anxiety. I don't have an issue with that, but I do have an issue when that lack of social skill is impairing the ability to nonverbally communicate in a forum that was designed to do just - that. I don't think the majority of commenters in this thread has read what was writting in the first link posted by the people who started this community. It was small...

Comment: ...everybody knew each other in the community and helping others was one of their finest skills apart from programming and the likes. If you are here to cater to your own ego, act judgemental and feel elevated due to being able criticizing others who don't have some particular knowledge that you acquired, then just leave SO. I will gladly renounce the help of these type of people and ask it from those who are not only technically but also socially skilled. The greatest challenge in helping someone lies not within the knowledge you got, but in conveying that knowledge so it is understood!

Comment: Looking at these personalities and behavior, SO needs desperately some change in both ticketing system, support features and - most important - a change of attitude by some of the users.  There is only one answer to the comments of the majority of the persons in the above statement and that's... https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: Oh, by the way..., answers can be edited, altered and improved! If someone, who claims to be skilled doesn't understand them, then he might just not be skilled enough to be helping out and ought to refrain from acting on anything at all or - alternatively - ask for clarification. One should be able to think that far for themselves if they claim to be so clever. I for my part don't want to and will not be using flattery in order to win approval from someone in a forum, which was DESIGNED to help other people on a VOLUNTARY basis. I helped others zillions of times and never made a fuss about it!

Comment: @themightyhulk: "*I can see that my initial point, written in my original post, has been over and over proven correct in the majority of comments on the very same.*" Because if people disagree with your beliefs, that must confirm those beliefs. Ignoring what other people say and clinging to your own personal notions is not an attitude that is conducive to learning. "*where you can find all sorts of diagnoses, ranging from ADHD, Autism and to Aspbergers and Anxiety.*" Do you have some kind of problem with neuroatypical people? Because that's against the CoC.

Comment: @themightyhulk: "*communicate in a forum*" Oh, there's your problem: Stack Overflow is *not a forum*. It's a Q&A site. "*If I am helping someone voluntarily, I do so or I don't.*" We're not here to help someone. We're here to build a knowledgebase. Answering bad questions does not build a useful knowledgebase; that's why we close them.

Answer (score 19):

> who just come to SO with the intent to ask questions which generate knowledge as to benefit all.

Our purpose is to generate useful knowledge for all, yes. But consider the quality of your question.

You showed off a 2D array, where you loop over each element of that array with two `for` loops, with each loop accessing a particular dimension of the array. You then asked us to explain how to loop over a single dimension of the array.

... I know that I've been programming for 30+ years, so I'm coming at this with a vast wealth of knowledge and experience at the task. But I genuinely cannot fathom how one can write 2D iteration over a 2D array, but be unable to convert it into 1D iteration. Even if you only got that code through copy-and-pasting from some tutorial, I don't understand how you can be unable to just play around with it and work it out on your own.

Asking on Stack Overflow is not meant to be the first recourse when you encounter a problem. You come here to ask when you have made a good faith effort to resolve that problem on your own. Whether that's looking in a debugger, just playing around with code, doing some Googling on how loops/arrays work, or whatever.

Can you *truthfully* say that you made a good faith effort to solve the problem on your own?

I would say that your question can not "generate knowledge as to benefit all"; it only benefits yourself, the person who is in this particular position. That is, most people who don't know how to iterate over a single dimension of a 2D array probably also don't know how to iterate over *both* dimensions of a 2D array. So your question won't help them.

It only helps yourself.

That, coupled with the fact that you probably could have worked it out for yourself if you took a little time to do so, shows that this is a low-effort question. That makes it worthy of downvoting.

Voting is not about you; it's about your *post*. Good content gets upvotes. Bad content gets downvotes. The vote total is about telling other people "this is good content; check it out" or "this is bad content; don't bother unless you like wasting time". They are a sign of a post's quality, which is of interest to other people.

People aren't downvoting your posts to harm you; they're downvoting them to tell others the quality of the content you provided.

This is not about being welcoming to a person; this is about being welcoming to *bad questions*. The former is fine; the latter is not.

Comment: Note to the person who thought it was a good idea to write a novel in the comments here: it wasn't.

Comment: Did you ever find a strongly downvoted good post?

Comment: @peterh: I don't recall running across one. But even if I had, that wouldn't change anything. One out of tens of thousands is a rounding error.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not even on the metas?

Answer (score 6):

Hi @themightyhulk! I'm sorry you are having a hard time on this site. I understand what you feel, I've been there too but there's things you need to understand.

People aren't downvoting your question because they don't like you or because they aren't nice, they are simply doing it because they think your question is unclear and should be improved. Don't take downvotes as insults, they aren't at all!

Most downvoters will also give you a comment when downvoting your question. Their comments will contain useful tips on how to improve your question! Read them carefully and you find very good information! I know it can be hard to take criticism at times when you may already be desperate to solve your problem. It might be a good idea to take a time to cool down to think rationnally.

No one should feel ashamed of asking questions that gets downvoted. (Everyone are bad askers before being good askers). Asking good questions is a skill that is valuable and not only on SO. Transforming your thoughs into a clear question takes efforts but do it properly and you won't regret it, I promise!

Comment: In this case, since it was close votes, you can change the "most of the time there's a comment" to "there is a description given". But this is a good, positively written answer.

Comment: @Winter Thanks for your constructive answer. I already posted my response to the majority of comments to my initial post under it. So you can read my stance on this there. I appreciate your kind attitude and attempt of explaining your take on this, but I have to disagree with you on that topic. The point here is, that the better part of the SO supporters - if we should call them that - are having a narcissistic attitude and are clearly showing that others should be catering to their needs and wants, rather than acknowledging some facts. For one, the question was answered and the problem thus..

Comment: ...solved. This is how things whould be working. For the other, I got a post about Big Data, which I clearly remember being downvoted for the same reasons and attitude. Throughout time, said post has been repeatedly upvoted and garnered thousands of views. By users - just - like - me - who found it absolutely useful. This is not about being 'not able to take some criticism by me - the user who needs help. The issue of not being able to take criticism lies with the people, exhibiting the toxic, self-absorbed behavior! People who started out like anybody else, knowing nothin! The grotesque...

Comment: ...part about this all is, that one can draw a direct line between the SO post on what is discussed as the New Code of Conduct by the individuals who started this community and to the above comments. The ones who provide the best support and answers are the ones that know this and are acting to be kind, helpful and supportive in a swift, uncomplicated and effective manner. The ones that need their egos polished are the ones that you hear immediate and most complains about. This is wrong, that is poor, you didn't try, you did this and that and on and on and on it goes. People with poor social..

Comment: ...skills, but possibly good programming skills. I for my part would rather be without their help and accept help from the minority on SO which do help. In my older posts there are numerous commenters who, without criticism, narcissism or hostility are helping straight away, throwing in interesting new angles, thoughts and ideas which usually end up, providing great help. Unfortunately, they are in the minority as mentioned before and this is what SO's reputation suffers from in the latest years. I am not alone in my criticism and sick of this behavior. Just to give you solid prove that...

Comment: ...other are too here goes... https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d  I have helped numerous people throughout time with IT related issues as well as programming and I never - ever - have been acting this infantile as what can be seen from the above posts. Just look at the comments and the attitude. 'He copied this', 'he didn't make an effort', he this, he that etc. etc. etc. It's head-spinning to say it nicely. Egos, as big as the Mt. Everest. Also, downvotes are not always aimed at 'improving the quality of the question' as some here claim. Downvotes are often a...

Comment: ...way of personally diminishing the rep of a user. There are numerous stories on this topic you can google saying, that many present supporters and moderators are trying to accumulate as much reputation as possible in order to be using their accounts as references when searching for better jobs. At the same time, they're downvoting others in order to protect their reputation so their position can't be touched nor threatened by other users. Downvotes therefore mean, my reputation and possibilities to comment, upvote and participate on an equal level are constantly sabotaged. So it means a lot!